# What's too broad about "all the possible operations that could cause a NaN"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

[What are all the possible calculations that could cause a NaN in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506281/what-are-all-the-possible-calculations-that-could-cause-a-nan-in-python)

The original version of this question, reproduced below, is asking what possible ways there are to get a NaN in Python.  The current version asks the same about NumPy and SciPy.  It was closed as too broad, then it got reopened, and now people are trying to close it as too broad again.

This question looks to me to be clear, narrow, and useful.  Is this simply a case of people casting close votes on a subject they aren't sufficiently familiar with?

Original question:

> Okay I've been searching around and there appear to be scattered
>   discussions about NaNs in different programming languages, including
>   some specific cases, but not exhaustive or clear.
>
> I have one simple question:
>
> What are all the different operations that would cause a NaN, in
>   python?

Current question:

> Okay I've been searching around and there appear to be scattered
>   discussions about NaNs in different programming languages, including
>   some specific cases, but not exhaustive or clear.
>
> I have one simple question:
>
> What are the most common operations that would cause a NaN, in python,
>   which originate while working with numpy/scipy?

Comment: It's a list question.  SO isn't designed to support list questions.

Comment: @Servy: Huh?  What's a "list question"?  You get a NaN when you do one of a very few things that don't make sense in floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: And the question is asking for a list of those things.  When you're asking for a list of things as an answer, that's a list question.

Comment: @Servy: OK.  Since when have they been off-topic?  Do lists of one thing still count as lists?

Comment: Longer than I've been around, so for quite a long time.

Comment: @Servy: Reference?

Comment: @Servy: It does not appear to be a "list question" according to Shog9's response at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question .

Comment: I think it's a legit question. (before and after edit) If it were put better, it would help future readers decently, and plus, it doesn't attract low-quality answers.

Comment: So nobody would ever disagree on what operations are "common"?  It's an entirely objective evaluation of every single item?

Comment: @Unihedron There's plenty of useful information that simply isn't well suited to the format of SO.  Just because some information is useful doesn't mean it has to be able to be an SO question.

Comment: @Servy: I don't see what's unsuitable about this question, and you calling it a "list question" hasn't helped one bit.  It's not a "list question" according to any definition of "list question" I can google.  There are five operations you can do to floating-point numbers, so whether square root is "common" or not is not a fundamental part of the question.

Comment: @Servy And how is this question asking for useful information that isn't well-suited as a SO question? It doesn't match the Too Broad qualification: "There are either __too many possible answers__" (not true as there are a finite and documented operations)", or __good answers would be too long for this format__." (not true as the question requests the information with the specification "working with `numpy/scipy`") The question doesn't have to "add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." either.

Comment: @Unihedron Before the edits it *absolutely* was.  When looking at the set of "all python code" then any custom function can potentially return NAN, for whatever reasons the implementer of that method feels it should (whether sensible or not).  It is an infinite set of always increasing items.  Limiting it's scope to "common" functions, after the edit, does decrease the set of items, but also adds in a strong subjective factor.  What's "common" to one person is not common to someone else.  Limiting the scope to just a specific set of libraries (the edit) also does help, but only to a point.

Comment: @Servy: There's nothing "strong" or "subjective" about whether a floating-point operation returns NaN.  You appear either not to know what floating-point numbers are or you're deliberately misinterpreting the question (in particular, the word "operation") in order to cast it as "too broad."  Also, last I checked, 5 is not infinite...

Comment: @tmyklebu I never said there was anything subjective about whether or not an operation returns NaN.  I said it was subjective wither or not the function is "common" or "uncommon".  Oh, and just because you only listed 5 operations doesn't mean the set of valid operations isn't infinite, it only means that you haven't listed anywhere near the full set of operations that can return NaN.  You appear to either not know what floating point numbers are or you're deliberately misinterpreting my comments in order to cast the question as not "too broad".

Comment: @Servy: It's also quite irrelevant...

Comment: @tmyklebu Except that it's not.

Comment: @Servy: Again, there are five "operations" on floating-point numbers.  Which of the five are are common and which aren't has very little to do with the question.

Comment: @tmyklebu But there are not just five operations.  There are an infinite number of possible operations.  You've listed five of them.  The question also specifically asks for the "common" operations, so that *made* it relevant.

Comment: @Servy: Care to describe a sixth operation and point me to where in the standard it's defined?

Comment: @tmyklebu Computing the exponent of a value, Sin, Cos, Tan, negation, just to name a few off of the top of my head.  I'd expect that the vast majority of all operations you could perform on a floating point value could return NaN (certainly just about any sensible implementatino of any operation should have that capacity, although some unsensible implementations or unusual operations won't), including whatever operations you write yourself, which is of course what makes the set infinite.

Comment: @Servy: Exponential, sine, cosine, and tangent are transcendental functions.  They are not commonly called "operations" by any person I've talked to or paper I've read.  The IEEE standard does not define them or what characteristics their implementations should possess; indeed, it uses the term "arithmetic operation" for the few arithmetic operations it does define.

Comment: @Servy: Further, *even if* you were advancing a sane argument, I don't think we should close this question simply because the asker didn't know to say "floating-point operation defined by the IEEE 754 standard" or whatever.  If he knew how to say precisely what he meant, he'd know where (the IEEE 754 standard) to look for the answer.

Comment: Given that your answer punts on the idea of providing a full list in _two_ different places, it's hard to see how you don't see how other people could think this is too broad.

Comment: @tmyklebu Then you should edit the question accordingly, if you feel confident that that is what the OP is interested in.  That *does* make the set finite and objective, unlike the question that was actually asked, which is neither.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: My answer answers the question as asked (gives the "full list"), then it gives guidance on related situations, then it gives a piece of debugging advice.  Perhaps it strays away from the question at points, but I do not see where it "punts" on anything.

Comment: @Servy: Why?  It's perfectly fine as-is.  Littering the question with technica would seem to make it *less* useful, rather than more useful, to future visitors.

Comment: "See the man page for atan2 and log, for instance" and "A complete discussion of how you can get screwed by numerical linear algebra is too long to belong in an answer." Having said this, however, I should also say that, in my estimation, this is a nice Q&A pair that we should be happy to have. But I definitely understand why others' opinions differ.

Comment: @tmyklebu If you limit the scope of the question to *just* IEEE defined operations then the question has a small finite set of operations to evaluate and answer on.  Without it it has an infinite set of items and your answer is radically incomplete.  If you think limiting the scope of the question to just IEEE operations is limiting it's usefulness then that's admitting that the current scope of the question is *not* just to IEEE operations, that it is asking about the infinite set of all possible floating point operations, and that your answer is *very* incomplete.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Doesn't look like punting on the question to me.  You can certainly make a case that that stuff is irrelevant to the question as asked; I included it because, looking at OP's question history, it seemed like something he'd want to know.

Comment: @Servy: Forcing future visitors to know what an "arithmetic operation as defined by IEEE 754" is before comprehending the question would certainly reduce the question's usefulness.  And again, a set of size 5 is not infinite.

Comment: It's punting on the idea of providing the _exhaustive_ list that the OP is supposedly asking for: "These five things, plus -- potentially -- a bunch of other things in this category (you'll have to look those up for yourself)."

Comment: @tmyklebu Then write the question so that they don't need to understand that term before comprehending the question.  That's easy enough to do.  And again, when you aren't binding the set of items to just those defined by IEEE the set *is* infinite, and the question currently does not do this.  Currently you're pretending that the question is a dramatically different question than it currently reads, and you're trying to answer that imagined question, rather than what is there.

Comment: It's a list question, because it asks for a "list of things". The problem is that, while the list in this question may be short, the list asked for in the next question probably won't be, and it would need to be closed. It's difficult to explain why the referenced question is acceptable, while "What are the things that can cause a page not to load properly in Firefox?" is not to a new user. The fact the list may be short doesn't make it a non--list question; it's just a **short** list question.

Comment: @KenWhite: It doesn't fit any definition of "list question" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question, so I'm not sure why you'd repeat that.

Comment: Any "how do I" question is, based on what I read from this discussion, too broad in the world of programming, because there are a potentially infinite number of ways to do just about *anything*. Perhaps we should just suck it up and allow SO to make its transition from a knowledgebase into a debugging site. That way nobody will have to worry about broadness of anything anymore.

Comment: @BoltClock: I have to imagine that there's a better solution to blind rule-following that doesn't throw the baby out with the bathwater.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I disagree that the question is Too Broad **`(post-edit)`**. I think it's a legit question; If it were put better, it would help future readers decently.

The Too Broad qualification is:

> "There are either **too many possible answers**, or **good answers would be too long for this format**."

- The question doesn't have too many possible answers as there are a finite and documented amount of operations, and the scope and expression is clear -

  > calculations that could cause a NaN
- The question doesn't require an answer too long to answer either, as the question requests the information with the specification "working with `numpy/scipy`".
- The question doesn't have to `"add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."` either.

Also, low-quality questions (that one should rush to close) tend to attract low quality answers. This doesn't.

While it *may* be subjective, it does not **generate discussion, and opinion-based posts** as the qualification of a question that is **primarily opinion-based**.

I disagree that the post is Too Broad, less to deserve being closed for the second time **`(post-edit)`**.

Comment: At the risk of offending those who follow the rules to the word, I agree with this. Even if it *is* asking for a list, I see no harm if the list is short. There's only a few ways you can produce a NaN.

Comment: @Mysticial: Is there even a rule against this question?  All I've been able to get out of Servy is basically "I don't like questions that I don't understand."

Comment: @tmyklebu [Even then they're using the wrong close reason...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UzMYD.png)

Comment: @tmyklebu Welcome to meta.SO. The mecca of pointless bickering over 1st world problems.

Comment: @Mysticial: I gather I shouldn't actually be trying to follow seemingly-insane advice dispensed here?

Comment: "finite and documented amount of operations" - there's a finite, small, and documented number of *operators*, but *operations*? There is a crazy number of functions and classes and weird interactions that might produce NaNs, and more are invented constantly.

Comment: @user2357112: I debunked that already.  Go read the spec.

Comment: @tmyklebu: You have an extremely restricted interpretation of "operation" that the actual question does not support.

Comment: @user2357112: I debunked that already.  Go read the spec.  The spec is the IEEE 754 standard.  Look how it uses the word "operation."

Comment: @user2357112: And, even if the question were "too broad" by the book, I can't support closing questions like this.  It's an "if you knew how to phrase your question precisely, then you'd know where to look for the answer" question.  Closing these for reasons other than "duplicate" does nobody any favours.

Comment: @tmyklebu: What makes you think the questioner is referring to the IEEE 754 standard's use of the term "operation"? It's a NumPy/SciPy question; why not use the term as the NumPy and SciPy docs do? You will find that that documentation uses the term in a much broader way than what you have in mind.

Comment: @user2357112: Probably because the question is about machine arithmetic.  In any case, that's the first interpretation I can see that doesn't render the question universally useless.

Comment: @tmyklebu: What gave you the idea the question was about machine arithmetic? There is not a single reference to machine arithmetic in the title, body, or tags, in any of the question's four revisions. Somehow, you've gotten the idea that this question is something it's not. It's making you miss things like the exponentiation operator (`**`), which is a common operation that produces NaNs, because you're thinking in a model where that's not an operator.

Comment: @user2357112: How else do you get a NaN without explicitly asking for one?  Python likes turning invalid operations into Python exceptions (in a way not entirely consistent with IEEE 754).  The poster modified his question to ask about NumPy instead of about straight Python in an apparent effort to "clarify" or "narrow" something I still don't see.

Comment: @tmyklebu: How else? Well, by using NumPy. I don't know why you'd look at a Python question, think "Python likes to turn NaNs into exceptions", and jump to the conclusion "The questioner must be asking about machine-level floating-point operations" rather than "The questioner is using libraries that don't do that with NaNs".

Comment: @user2357112: I jumped to the conclusion "The questioner wants to know why NaNs sometimes crop up when he uses NumPy to do tons of machine arithmetic."  This still appears reasonable to me.  (From all this discussion, I gather that the question can be interpreted in a "too broad" way.  I still don't feel it's reasonable to do so, however, and I'm rather at a loss as to how to change the question's wording so that it's still useful to the same audience and is harder to misinterpret.)

Comment: @tmyklebu "[...] when he uses NumPy _to do tons of machine arithmetic_" is an unjustified assumption on your part. I'd even guess it's a false assumption; read the comment by flebool and OPs response: "causes of NAN [...] that _do not originate from other libraries_ [than numpy/scipy]" - which I would interpret as OP wanting to know all numpy operations _and library functions_ which could ever return a NAN; I think you agree _that_ question is too broad. FWIW, I'd close the question as _unclear_ until OP clarifies if he wants to know about IEEE754 operations, or about all of python and numpy.

Comment: @tmyklebu and the comment that flebool just left in reply to you on the original question pretty much confirms my view: "Many libraries return (or can return) nan under certain circumstances, defined by the library, instead of returning an exception for example. They are a finite but very large number of cases.". Do you still think anybody who might find this question somewhat broad doesn't know what floating-point numbers are or deliberately misinterprets the question?

Answer (score 16):

My problem with questions like this is not that they are too broad, but that they are already completely answered by the relevant specifications, in this case IEEE754.

I don't want SO to become a repository of transcriptions of those standards, or, worse, incorrect renditions of what they say, but both are inevitable if questions like this are permitted. The goal of SO is to become the first place you should look for answers to on-topic questions. As the first place you should look in such cases is certainly the relevant specification, that makes the question off-topic by definition.

Comment: why don't point to the specification as an answer ? I'm really asking

Comment: @Bart I agree, that's exactly what should be done, as opposed to posting extracts, even verbatim, and certainly as opposed to posting mangled paraphrases.

Comment: This is a good point, and I almost agree with it.  The gap I see is that (0) specs can be expensive, (1) people don't always know which specs are relevant and which aren't (the use of NumPy here means you're getting native arithmetic, not Python arithmetic), and (2) specs aren't always easy to interpret.  The IEEE spec is reasonably clear---section 7 of the IEEE spec talks about exceptions and how they're handled---and I could have done better to either transcribe the relevant part more accurately or give a pointer to the spec itself.

Comment: @Bart: Because I didn't think of that.  (Why didn't I think of that?  Because I'm apparently daft.)

Comment: Your point seems to be, if there is **anything anywhere** that would answer the question, it should be off-topic. I think otherwise, the StackOverflow should be the first place to look for an answer, with exception to language basics and API specifications.

Comment: Aren't most (or at least many) questions on SO solvable with the help of the specification? I've seen a ton of questions a la "Why does operation `X(YZ)` not work", while reading the documentation reveals that the required parameter would have been `ΨΩ`. Edit: I agree with @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt

Comment: @Theolodis: Yes, but whether it's reasonable to expect the asker to understand the specification varies with the specification.  IEEE 754 is pretty simple---I probably could have answered with a link and a few pointers about interpretation.  C++, for example, is not simple---have a look at the language-lawyer tag.

Comment: @tmyklebu I do not know the `IEEE 754` (c++ programmer), and I am sure not many people actually do. But that makes an answer on SO, with a link to the specification!!!!, even more useful ;)

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt That is a complete and utter misrepresentation of what I said, for which there is absolutely no excuse. My point is that when a normative reference or specification is applicable (as per your own final sentence, which isn't too different from what I wrote), it is otiose to quote it, and even worse to paraphrase it.

Comment: @EJP: I dunno about "otiose"; as I said, some specs cost money, others are hard to follow, and it may not be obvious which specs are applicable in the first place.

Comment: @tmyklebu Agreed but we are discussing 'questions like this', not abstruse things buried deep in specifications that are only comprehensible to implementors.

Comment: @EJP: Sure.  But that means the rule should be "if there's a spec, provide an interpretation and for the love of god also a reference" or thereabouts, rather than "if there's a spec, don't repeat it."  My initial failure to do so was an oversight on my part.

Comment: I understand that not all users are willing to take the time to explain a spec in plain English in their own words, but in general I disagree that everyone posting on SO should have to study the spec for everything before asking; that seems like overkill especially since some of these specs are behind a paywall, and/or bloated with outdated/esoteric information, "please don't sue me if it doesn't work" legalese, or terminology that only a compiler writer/hardware designer would know or need to know about.

Answer (score 12):

The original question was (and the title still is) too broad.  It's like asking for a complete list of functions that can raise `ValueError`.

The question limited to NumPy / SciPy may be too broad, but is more likely to get good answers, even if the list is never comprehensive.

Answer (score 8):

I don't find this question "clear": it asks about "common operations in Python" - no one knows what that is, and even if you claim that you do - you don't, unless you show me some convincing statistical data from a significantly large number of Python programs written.

I don't find this question "narrow": as the number combinations that leads to this outcome is infinitely larger then the list in the answer. Even if the answer is good and narrow, doesn't mean the question is. The answer deals with "operation" in IEEE's meaning - not referring to what an "operation" is in Python. Here is an example of a [*Python operation*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) not listed in your answer:

```python
class X:
    def __add__(self, other):
        return 1/0

print X() + 1  # X() + 1 is an operation
```

I don't find this question "useful": why would someone need a list like this? Don't they teach people in the kindergarten not to divide by `0`? Or isn't it obvious that something's wrong with your code when it tries to come up with an answer to "how much is it `inf - inf`"? Anyway, even if someone will not understand why it's wrong, they can post their code and ask what's wrong with it - that would be narrow.

The conclusion is that IMHO this should be indeed closed as *too broad*, or migrated to Programmers. The latter seems more appropriate because the answer is indeed very nice.

Another possibility is to ask a different, better and more precise question, and self-answer it.

Comment: What's wrong with dividing by zero?

Comment: And your conclusion is?...

Comment: Separately, your "not clear" complaint is a red herring, your "not narrow" complaint has already been debunked, and the question's useful because it pays to understand the behaviour of the things you're working with.

Comment: @tmyklebu 1) It's a direct response to your diagnosis, so if this is a red herring then so your "the question is clear" is.  2) No it wasn't. The question is about Python, in which an operation is something very different than IEEE's operation. 3) It doesn't help to understand "things you're working with" because there is no thing someone was working with in the question. Your (albeit very nice) answer won't stop people from posting a *particular issue* that results in such errors, even if they will read it.

Comment: ... and that's because the problem mostly is not that people don't know that you shouldn't divide by zero (except you, apparently), but they often don't know how come during execution of their code it comes to the point when division by `0` occurs.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Nothing will stop people from posting about a particular issue in which a NaN arises, nor should it.  "Scientific" code is usually written with the "useful tool that usually works" goal in mind rather than the "bulletproof library that satisfies all of your naive wishes" goal.  This is because the "bulletproof" variants wind up being unusably slow, often requiring arithmetic on huge numbers.  By its very nature, then, this stuff is considerably less composable than "integer" code.  What follows is a need to understand the implementation at at least some level.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Perhaps "operation" means something different in Python.  I don't know---I'm not much of a Python programmer.  If so, the correct course of action is to correct the poster's clumsy wording rather than close the question.

Comment: @tmyklebu If you *are really sure* what did the OP mean. That would however be a gray area edit. After all, the Python tag most probably isn't there by accident. This suggests again that you really wanted to answer a question *you* had in mind, and just found something closest to it. Perhaps consider asking a better question yourself, and self-answering it? That would be the cleanest solution according to SO policy IMHO.

Answer (score -4):

The question, as originally asked, was absolutely too broad: the number of Python "calculations" that can produce a `NaN` is essentially unbounded, limited only by the combined creativity of the Python programming community.  Replacing "all the possible" with "the most common" just makes it subjective, too; arguably, it's *still* too broad, as there's a limitless number of possible answers depending on each answerer's definition of "most common".

That said, the question has [a nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25512004), which I'd hate to see lost.  So what we *should* do is **figure out what question the answer actually answers, and then edit the question to actually ask it.**

The trick here, I believe, is to be specific.  The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) suggests that a good SO question should be about **"a specific programming problem"**.  While the original question was written in the form of a (doomed) literature search looking for an exhaustive list of possible sources of `NaN`s in Python, the specific programming problem behind it, which the answer correctly picks out, seems to be something like:

> ## Where do NaNs come from?
>
> I wrote some Python code (using numpy / scipy) to calculate a numerical value, but it returned `NaN` instead.  It seems that any further calculations I do with this `NaN` value also return `NaN`, but I'm sure that my original inputs didn't have any `NaN` values in them.
>
> What are these `NaN` values, what kinds of operations produce them, and how can I find their source and fix it?

(This is just a quick draft; feel free to suggest improvements.)

IMO, rephrased like that, this is a valid and even a good question for SO: not so broad that it would be unanswerable, nor so narrow that it wouldn't be of use to other people.  True, the lack of program code means we can't debug it ourselves and find the specific source of the OP's `NaN`, but, as the existing answer demonstrates, that doesn't necessarily preclude us from providing a general answer that describes the typical sources of `NaN`s and how to locate them.

Indeed, it could be argued that, for future visitors finding this question and answer on Google, such a general answer can actually be *more* useful than one that focuses on finding and fixing a particular bug in a particular piece of code.

Anyway, unless someone beats me to it (or unless this answer gets downvoted to oblivion), I'm going to edit the question later today to say something like my suggested wording above.

Comment: I think your proposed rewrite makes it even broader (asking four related but separately answerable questions). "How do I debug" questions are generally not on-topic, and just saying "I wrote some code" is not preferred - we like minimal examples that reproduce the issue.

Comment: You have my blessing, for whatever it's worth, to edit the question.  But I still don't see why people are making a fuss over the wording here and I'm perfectly happy to let the question fade into oblivion if the community prefers that.