# Why is this question about a clever Ruby on Rails syntax too broad?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions, specific-question, needs-more-focus

This question is on hold for being too broad: [How does method chaining work in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25981099/1454117).

Frankly, I think this is one of the better questions I've seen lately. The question is concise and addresses a syntax that is often surprising or confusing to new Ruby on Rails developers. It's also easy for experts to walk through the different calls and explain what's happening (as exhibited by the answers already posted).

Can someone help me understand what is inappropriate or too broad about this question?

Comment: TL;DR; Maybe it's too clever? ;-) ...

Comment: Its appears to be a classic case of "I know more than you", [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users). This really irritates me: *"put on hold as too broad"*. I doubt its too broad since its a one-liner. It should say the folks casting the close vote were too lazy.

Comment: I cast the final reopen vote.  But it's already been asked and answered, so... nothing more to see here.

Comment: It's on hold because 5 people (most of whom are active in ruby) voted to close it. I think the issue is that the OP doesn't explain what part they are having trouble with or the background information they already know. "how does this code work" could be very broad if you need to explain everything.

Comment: The question could have benefited from someone cleaning it up a bit... it's not like there was that much to clean up.  I edited the title and the body.

Comment: *...nothing more to see here..."* - well, the fellow is still suffering the effects (as will future visitors) - the question still has a negative total. I'd love to know if its a case of "hunting in packs" due to [tag:cv-pls]. And good job on the edits. I was wondering how much ESL affected the question.

Comment: @jww: I wouldn't feel that sorry for the OP.  He earned a net 18 rep from that question, and is currently at zero score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was closed because the original question as posed suffered from a few problems. Here's the original question for context:

> #### can't understand this ruby code
>
> maybe it's very basic question , but i'm a C# developer , new to ruby on rails 
>   I can't understand how this code work. Can anyone give me some explanation.
>
> ```
> <%= 1.hour.from_now.localtime %>
> ```

1. It's a question that does not have any searchable text in it, at all. If someone googles 'Can't understand this ruby code', maybe they'll find this post. Otherwise it has no value for anyone who may have this same problem.  So the title has a lack of clarity.
2. The question also suffers from the same problem as the title. You could remove everything but the last sentence and be left with the same question. If anyone searches for "new to ruby on rails and I can't understand how this code work [sic]", I'd be very surprised.
3. The OP couldn't be bothered to use any sort of capitalization or punctuation in the proper places.

So it was closed. That part's right.

It was closed as "too broad". That's because some people have taken [very specific advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226535/place-a-question-in-temporary-limbo/226543#226543) and tried to apply it to everything.  That part is wrong. It should not have been closed for that reason.

It's not too broad, as an answer could be a few sentences.

What this question really lacks is usability: But that could be fixed through editing; and closure helps the OP understand what they need to do to get their question re-opened. In this case, the community failed the OP by closing it for the wrong reason.

Comment: "the community failed the OP".  Attitudes like these seriously poison the well, it is unbecoming of a moderator.

Comment: @HansPassant We owe it to newcomers to our community to treat them with the same consideration we'd want to be treated with. I can't imagine anyone who would be ok with being told they were wrong, but not told why, or how to fix it.  Maybe just as bad (if not worse) is to purposefully obfuscate the reason for the closure because you (the closers) have issues with the question but can't be bothered to articulate it accurately.  If that's not failing the OP; I don't know what is.

Comment: We owe it to the members of our community to treat them with the same consideration we'd want to be treated with.  I can't imagine why a moderator would accost them of failing to service visitors when there is so much daily evidence of the opposite.  This site was built by the tireless effort of these members and is an unparalleled resource to programmers throughout the world.  To suggest, yet again, that they are failing at this is insulting, unconstructive and trivially proven wrong every day.

Comment: "It's not too broad, as an answer could be a few sentences." – I disagree. I can't see how this can be answered sensibly with anything less than a complete Ruby tutorial, with some ERb and ActiveSupport thrown in, plus maybe even a tutorial on timezones. What is he asking about? The syntax for calling a method in Ruby (`foo.bar`)? What a method is? What an object is? Fundamentals of OOP? The ERb template syntax (`<%= some_expression %>`)? How you can make a method that returns something that you can then again call a method on ("Fluent Interface")? The concept of timezones and local time?

Comment: @JörgWMittag The top rated answer on that questiondisagrees with you.  "How does this code work" `<code>`. If the OP were asking any of those things you mention, he would have asked that.

Comment: The question should be closed because it has poor grammar?! What the fsck? What's the close reason for that, exactly? What's the close reason for "not googleable"?

Comment: @JoshCaswell There are two: Unclear what you're asking, and "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. **Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers**. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example." Poor grammar or spelling on its own is not always an indicator of a question's clarity; but in the venn diagram of question closures; the hardest ones to understand are ones with bad grammar.

Comment: This post does not say "poor grammar might make a question unclear enough to warrant closure". It says: "It was closed because the original question as posed suffered from a few problems. ... 3. 
The OP couldn't be bothered to use any sort of capitalization or punctuation in the proper places. So it was closed. That part's right." It's pretty hard to square this with your railing against improper use of Too Broad over at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271864/

Comment: @JoshCaswell The comments aren't a place to get into a protracted discussion about this; if you'd like to ask a meta question about how grammar and spelling play into closing, go ahead and I'll answer it.  I don't want to assume you're just cherry picking part of my statement without taking it in its whole form; but the nature of comments doesn't' help in that regard.

Comment: Comments are for discussing problems with answers. I'm discussing your answer. Your first comment to me here, and another post of yours, seem to indicate that this answer either doesn't say what you mean it to or what you think it does, or that you have a very inconsistent view of closure reasons. _Every one of the three_ reasons that  you've given in this answer _is not a sufficient reason for closure_; I just picked the most egregious as a starting point. I would suggest that you edit this answer if you believe I'm misreading or mischaracterizing it, because I'm probably not the only one.