# Are "format my code" questions welcome?

Tags: discussion

Are questions like:

1. Format my code
2. Shorten my code
3. Write better code
4. Convert my code from one language to another (mostly a part of it)

welcome on the Stack Overflow community?

Comment: No. No. [Not here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). **No.**

Comment: Stack Exchange would probably have a place for some of these but Stack **Overflow**...no I don't think so.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi hehehehe I understand understand understand understand

Comment: Some posters want us to compile, link, test debug and verify their code too.  AFAIK, none of them has ever asked us to deliver it and take payment for it.

Comment: That's really sad. You should have explicitly asked for some donation in Bitcoin(easy way)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. Stack Overflow is supposed to be a repository of programming knowledge. Questions like these would only ever be useful to the one person who asked them. Since they'd never have any future value to anyone else, they'd be off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It is conceivably possible for them to be useful, but [the criteria is pretty strict](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271894/why-is-this-question-about-a-clever-ruby-on-rails-syntax-too-broad), so for most people these questions are just off topic.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Yeah, it's true that you might be able to squeeze a few useful posts out of this genre, but when compared to the deluge of useless posts allowing them would open us up to, I think we'd be in [infinite monkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) territory.