# What to do when moderators don't care about rude users?

Tags: support, moderators, offensive

For quite a while there has been a user who is frequently making up their own rude, non-constructive close vote reasons. Examples:

- "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because trash code"
- "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because malicious question."
- "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because priority close."
- "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a works request"
- "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's extra-urgent that this question be closed."
- "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because exploit crap, and I'm sick and tired of pandering to those that seek to waste my time and money."

Apart from close votes like these, the user is almost always rude and aggressive, always seeking conflict in comments instead of using conventional moderator means or just ignoring the question.

At a minimum, I would think they should have close vote privileges revoked. But since such behavior does not belong on this site, they should probably be banned as well.

I can't believe behavior like this is acceptable, so now I wonder what I should do?

I have flagged them for diamond mod attention *twice*, but nothing happens. Since that is clearly not the solution, should I go on a "offensive flag crusade" of my own against every single rude comment they have made? I'll run out of flags quickly...

Comment: *"but nothing happens"* I doubt the moderator is going to notify you of an action taken against another user, so you'll rarely see an action actually take place, other than something being edited/removed, but we the community can do that.

Comment: A number of the examples you posted are _bad close reasons_ but not exactly rude. I see three that I would actually count as rude  (one of those I'm borderline on, actually), and the rest are just really crappy close reasons.

Comment: And as Kevin B points out, you're not likely to see that something _has_ actually been done. Do you have a way to know for sure that the mods haven't sent a warning or two to the user? As I understand it, mods prefer to try to correct the behavior before straight out suspending a user. It could be that either the user has been talked to and hasn't done this since, or that the mods feel they have a few more options before a suspension is issued.

Comment: Did you flag the comment or did you find one of the user's posts and use a custom "Other" flag explaining what's wrong and what a moderator needs to do?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271863/misuse-of-off-topic-closure-reason

Comment: *"I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because exploit crap, and I'm sick and tired of pandering to those that seek to waste my time and money"* - I'm curious to see what kind of question can warrant this pending rage quit.

Comment: @KevinB No of course they won't, but his behavior has not changed either, thus whatever measures they took/did not take had no effect.

Comment: @Gimby I'd wager the comment is gone, but this is still indexed for that search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644572/buffer-vulnerability-problems-generate-shell/33646544

Comment: @bluefeet I used the custom flag reason on their rude comments.

Comment: How does one waste money in SO?

Comment: If a close reason like "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a works request" is beyond the pale then punch my ticket, I'm outta here.

Comment: @Will The key here is to not point fingers at the particular user and hang their profile out on meta, if you couldn't read that between the lines...

Comment: Did you explain in your custom flag that this is on-going behavior and link to examples? Or did you just say that this user is rude and aggressive or something along those lines?

Comment: I'm with Will here "this is a work request" is a valid reason (and not at all rude) to close... He could've been more diplomatic about it, but I don't see it as offensive in itself. As part of his pattern, maybe

Comment: @Kendra At both custom flags I pointed towards his comment history, which contains a lot of worse things than listed here, under the assumption that the moderator would do as much as standard procedure.

Comment: @Lundin Any actions by a mod to the user would be private, so you can't assume a moderator did nothing in regards to the flags. It's entirely possible that the user was contacted by a moderator when you raised a flag.

Comment: @bluefeet Yet they haven't changed their behavior. Well anyway, in case you are interested I could contact you somehow and you can have a look at the user's comment history. Shouldn't take more than 5 minutes to determine if my concerns are valid or not.

Comment: @Lundin I can see your flag history and the comments in question. It's been handled, no need to go any further with this.

Comment: @bluefeet Alright, in that case we can close this support request. For future reference, is it more helpful to provide several direct links to particularly comments? I believe the custom flag "edit box" has a limited amount of characters.

Comment: @Lundin In the future use a custom "other" moderator flag and add an explanation of what the user is doing and a link to one of their comments. That should be enough to get the attention of a mod.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This is a known issue...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271863/misuse-of-off-topic-closure-reason)

If you've spotted a particularly rude custom close vote, or notice a user who has a habit of leaving them, flag it with a mod flag (like you did).

Be sure to be very specific in the flag.

- If you see a pattern, offer a few links to support it.
- Also mention why you find it offensive or inappropriate.

Then be patient. It may take a few days for your flags to process.

---

**Don't be afraid to raise another flag if you see a pattern continue after you've flagged it in the past.**

Mods have a lot of issues to handle, and a lot of things to keep an eye on...
They may have just issued a warning the first time and alerting them to a repeat offender is often appreciated.

Comment: This is all sensible things but essentially what I already did. In both cases my flag was listed as "helpful" so they have been processed... somehow.

Comment: @Lundin Then all you can do past that is have faith that the moderators are taking action (most actions they'll take will be things you can't see or just won't notice) and continue flagging as things come up or get worse. If the user continues to refuse to correct they're behavior, it'll lead to a suspension. (This is assuming that you're correct about how bad their content is. I'm taking your word for that.)