# What can we put in a question template to help people ask better questions?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

**Update**: Our v1 experiment is done. We used a template loosely based on [enderland's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357956/1438) for this experiment. See [this post for an overview of the results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363051/ask-a-question-template-v1-experiment-results).

---

Based on [your feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354125/help-set-qa-teamdag-product-development-priorities) the DAG team is [working on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301449/teamdag-project-updates/301450#301450) several projects related to question quality. On the low-hanging-fruit side, we’re going to [A/B test](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/10/17/power-calculations-p-values-ab-testing-stack-overflow/) some question templates. (As a bonus, we're finally getting around to addressing [a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231827/revisiting-question-templates) we've been hoping to work on for several years.)

Once we have some template variations, we’ll show them to different groups of users who have asked fewer than some number of questions and have less than some reputation. Then we’ll compare the quality of  result and see if templates help improve questions or not.<sup>*</sup>  The primary goal here is to validate the concept of giving new users a question template. Among the secondary goals is finding what sort of template (if any) works best.

That’s where you can help. **What sort of guidance do you think would most help new askers provide the information needed to get useful answers?** An obvious item that came up over and over again in the [mentoring experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up) is the importance of an MVCE. We can also demonstrate code block formatting, which would help *many* askers. But are there other, perhaps less obvious, hints we could include in a template?

---

Please note we are *also* investigating some sort of “ask your question” wizard-type feature. Templates may very well be incorporated in that eventually. We’re very much in the proof of concept stage. Exact template wording will be much less helpful than principles.

For the moment, we're focusing on Stack Overflow because it gets so many questions from new users that it'll be quicker to get statistically meaningful results. Once we have results, we should be able to transfer that knowledge to other sites on the network. For now, let's focus on guidance specific to asking code questions.

---

Footnote:

* We're working with our data analysis team to determine what metric to use. The details are coming soon, but we'll be looking at whether the question has:

- a positive, negative or zero score
- been answered
- been closed (possibly excluding duplicates)
- been deleted (possibly excluding self-deletions)

We are aiming for a (mostly accurate) way to grade each and every question submitted based on the community's feedback.

Comment: Highly related - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278444/193412 - this covers most problem cases for questions which are actually good fits for SO.

Comment: @KevinB: The Stack Apps template is a bit of a red herring, so I cut it out of the question. The main reason I linked to it is we recently (re-)discovered we had that feature over there. So there's no reason not to try templates here. That said, I'm not sure if our developers will reuse that code or if we'll need to do something a bit different. (I also found the setting and, yes, you do need an account to ask on Stack Apps just like you do on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: @enderland: Oh. Thank you! We'll definitely take those ideas into consideration. (Not sure why my searching missed that. Maybe I was too focused on the word "template"?)

Comment: I think instead of a template i'd rather see guidance there. For example, some info from here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask or maybe a list of things to *NOT* ask about. Maybe also some just in time hints when users type in common words that derail questions, such as "best practice"

Comment: @KevinB: That's an interesting idea to test. Maybe the reader's digest version or just a link they have to remove in order to post. (I think we can safely blacklist the template text to make sure people remove it before posting.)

Comment: Also see: [Let's improve Stack Overflow's "Ask a question" page!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326868)

Comment: MCVE is not the only problem. There is also number of blatantly off topic questions asking for libraries, code writing requests, too broad how to questions without research effort, opinion based questions, hardware and software related issues that don't belong on SO. IMO there should be some sort of wizard guide that would also include all above bad options and if person selects wrong one it would get the message that is not appropriate question. Only after they pass that first step, there could be some MCVE template to help them polish the question.

Comment: A related question, but do you consider a user with 1 rep and no questions to be different than someone who either has *some* rep or a single post? Do these types of user behave any differently? One would hope the user who has actively contributed to the site would have learned something?

Comment: Funny you should post this. I placed [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351751/meet-team-dag-developer-affinity-growth#comment522794_351751) and [this addendum...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351751/meet-team-dag-developer-affinity-growth#comment523370_351751) in [Meet Team DAG! (Developer Affinity & Growth)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351751/1415724) in regards to how the "How to Ask" box should be modified; just a few upvotes but no response.

Comment: Personally, the "front end" is probably (just) as important as what happens in the "back end". What users see in front of them, shows a better picture on how to "play their part" and what their role is when "playing ball" in the ballpark arena, as it were. The less they know, more the questions keep rolling in (like oranges) without a clear explanation of what the problem is, and/or where their code is and/or their attempt at first solving this themselves. We need to focus on what they should do, rather than having us constantly telling them/posting links in the help section etc.

Comment: When thinking about *templates*, please be careful that the template should *not* be a prefilled part of the text you enter. I agree with Kevin B, that it should be a guidance instead of a strict template. I have seen far too many GitHub issues or other issue tracker entries where users have *literally* filled out the template, keeping all the terrible surrounding template structure. That’s really *not* improving question quality *at all*.

Comment: I really think a wizard approach that can be disabled at a certain rep threshold is answer to this problem. Take a look at Chris Baker's mockups: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253317/998328

Comment: @CodyGray Random and arbitrary deletion of answers seems heavy-handed in the extreme. At a minimum, you need to give a better rationale for having done this. There was no humor in my answer, and it's hard to make the case that it amounts to "GTFO". I supposed one could make the case that my answer was not an answer to how to build a template. On the other hand, it is a perfectly reason template feature to have "exit lanes" where the poster is gently guided away from posting at all.

Comment: Has anyone suggested using machine learning on past bad questions to identify when new bad questions roll in? No one wants bad questions on SO, but the ones that have been asked so far are a trove of wealth for finding like items.  If we train for known *types* of bad questions, the OP could get real-time feedback on what they're doing wrong as they're crafting their crummy question. Static guidance may help all types of bad-question-askers equally poorly by trying a 1-size-fits-all approach.

Comment: @jinglesthula: We did something like that [a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/08/21/stack-exchange-machine-learning-contest/). It might be worth trying again, but that's outside the scope of the template project.

Comment: Why not *also* (finally) raise the bar and prevent anyone from asking unless they have read [ask] and taken the [tour]?  If you dont require user8675309 to read the guidelines and learn how the site works, you ought not be shocked (SHOCKED, I tell you) when they post sewage.  If they are not willing the expend that much effort, how much do you expect them to spend on their post?

Comment: @Plutonix: It's such a good idea, we built [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) that users with less than 10 reputation have been forced to view since [June of 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9710/1438). So we're trying something else this time.

Comment: And please add a hint to stay put the first minutes to answer comments asking for clarification. This is IMO the main reason why questions get closed when they dont answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156761

Comment: I agree with poke, you don't want the template questions to be a part of the text field. SO questions would become very verbose, people would answer parts of the question that are irrelevant to them, etc. So maybe something more like an interactive guidance as people are writing questions. For newer users you could require them to hit a button to confirm "Yes I've provided system details if it is relevant", "Yes, I added code if it is relevant" etc

Comment: My advise would be to keep it short and simple. Get their attention with something that say *"STOP! We have rules. Read them before posting if you want an answer"*. From there, it should take you to some short bullets, with links for more expanded details if necessary. I feel sure I've written an answer about this somewhere at some point in time, but I can't recall where.... edit: [found it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327028/302677)

Comment: @Rachel: Yes, you wrote [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327028/1438) to a related question. I think short really is the key. Really helpful insight.

Comment: @JonEricson Yes, I find new users who write bad questions often don't want to invest significant time to learn how to post something on a "new" site to them, so short is key for getting important info to them. Either that, or they're often not native english speakers, so walls of text often lose them too.

Comment: Maybe they could be **motivated** to produce better questions by giving them some indicator of likelihood of getting an answer - like a *"Password Strength Indicator"*. The likelihood of getting an answer might increase with more references to places they had looked and more code blocks and more tags.

Comment: I guess the main problem with this kind of template is that it assumes that most newcomers who ask a question  have essentially a good question to ask,  and all they need is help in making their question complete and clear. But my perception (perhaps incorrect) is that is not the case. Most newcomers post essentially unsalvageable questions. If the template or wizard can't steer the OP into deciding NOT to post yet another debug-me NullPointerException question, I can't see this making things much better.

Comment: @Raedwald, FYI there's [a deleted answer here that makes that point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357965/).

Comment: If you do go with a template or wizard, you may want to consult with some of the data analysts that write the SO blogs. They may have suggestions for meaningful fields that will help them extract trends from question text, or allow the backend to find suggested similar questions based on multiple fields (right now when you ask a question, I believe it only suggests based on the title text).

Comment: Why was this question posted when meta is already FULL of topics that  already address the issue of new users and question quality?  Templates in particular have also already been discussed with little success (low votes) from what I perceive.  It does not speak well to the entire purpose of Stack Exchange question archives when the dev team itself must revert to rehashing the same topics over again.  There are already many gold nuggets of great suggestions that have been posted for many years, especially regarding new users and question quality.

Comment: I’m most active in the ‘relational database’ sections, and as a supplement to the comments from all the ‘coders’ I’d like to add that including example code only helps you understand the question in 50% of the cases. In all the other cases the question was mainly posted because the userxxxx didn’t have the faintest idea what the desired output is, let alone having read the syntax manual. Therefore: a default template should probably be different based on which [categories] have been chosen, and for database questions it is a MUST with example input and output data (which is hard to enter btw)

Comment: @CPerkins: We have been reading those old meta questions too. This is a very specific question about what we should include in templates that we are planning to test soon. I've got several distinct general templates suggested below (plus the empty control) that I'll be presenting to the DAG team next week. Most of the ideas weren't new by any means. I'd love to have more, but most of the 26 answers (some deleted) ignored or misunderstood the question. In any case, we might find that templates don't work. We'll just move onto some of the other ideas suggested over the years.

Comment: @RToyota: Yes, we are working with them. In particular, we asked for a study about how long it takes for a question to "stabilize" in terms of score. The answer ~3 days. We'll be consulting with them more as we test more ideas.

Comment: In 99% of all bad questions a simple [mcve] would have been enough, but nobody reads that.

Comment: rather than a template, I would suggest an AI system possibly using a Deep Learning trained assistant.  SO has a large labelled data set that could be used to make helpful suggestions, like "This question may need a MCVE", or "these may be duplicate questions" or "you should probably use these tags" or "you probably should not have these tags" or ... whatever the list of top defects in new questions are, you could probably train a DL AI assistant to make helpful suggestions concerning those.  You already have a huge, labelled data set.

Comment: Instead of spending time on improving the Ask a Question page we should prevent a user gets into that mindset in the first place: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261343/give-greater-dominance-placement-to-searching-rather-than-asking-for-new-low-rep (though that proposal is badly out of date)

Comment: One question attempts to solve ONE problem - and often simply getting good definition of the problem will lead to a quality answer - then you get to the "and also..." portions of questions.  Now how do we differentiate that "problem" from a "How do I..." question which is many times previously answered or perhaps insufficiently so to lead to enlightenment on the "How to" that is desired.

Comment: @DavidMulder: Our current plans don't preclude doing more later. In fact, we're trying to do [more iteration and less incremental building](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/tearing-down-the-structure-of-documentation). The great thing about dead-simple templates is they are going to be quick and easy to test. Then we can use that knowledge to find the most effective places for us to focus on next.

Comment: I think a template is a great idea.  Of course it won't prevent all bad questions; nothing will.  Don't let a focus on perfection block all progress.  If a template can make even a small improvement, why not do it, learn from it, keep going..... and maybe it might even be a big change.

Comment: It sounds like there's some disagreement on what a "template" is for the purpose of this discussion.  Could some example images be added to this question post to clarify?  Perhaps use a goofy, non-software topic to avoid focusing on it's contents.

Comment: Atlast........... I have been advocating this issue with the new users from Day 1.... Looking for productive amendments ahead.

Comment: Here is another suggestion. In the "Ask a Question" / "How to Ask" box, to contain **Please take the time to read....** in big enough/bold type. That should be clear for them to take the time to read what they should be doing.

Comment: @MikeM: Yeah. . . I had a live example from [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=library) that seemed to confuse folks. I should have used a non-software template as you suggested. At this point, I got the feedback I need to run the first test. I'll be back for more once we have some initial results to share.

Comment: At the very least, ask for the log file or console output.

Comment: Reject any question with an image or a link to an image that does not contain code or sample data in a code block within the question. Too many low-reppers think we have nothing better to do with our time than retype sample data and/or code from an image.

Comment: I'm not sure but I've seen questions marked as duplicate that does not deserve it. In many cases lot of people does not understand a given concept, and try to get it by using their own practical example added to a new question. That let them get a correct answer for their example and compare that with [possible duplicated question] answers, and learn in the process.

Comment: Is templating really the answer?  Why not segment SO into SO new, SO pro.  First time questioners are routed to the new queue, anyone with the spirit to help inexperienced people can hang out on SO new and help people get started.  Once a mediocre level of rep has been earned, then the questions are routed to SO pro.  Busy professionals that want meaty questions can hang out on SO pro.  Or, not even notice, unless they click a preference for "Allow view of rep < threshold".  Experts that are helping new users can force elevate good questions into SO pro space and guide the rest to better.

Comment: Since there are so many questions on meta about this, and so many good ideas have come up, perhaps it would be useful to look at the most upvoted answers across the board, and boil them down to a set of features or principles, and create a survey where meta users can rank them in order of perceived importance.  I think that would give us a good starting point.  If we keep talking pros and cons until we have the perfect design, we will be here until the Sun explodes.

Comment: @SamHazleton: I've already written up a test plan that I hope will be executed in November. (How is October already nearly done?) Most likely, I'll be coming back with the copy we are trying and then the results in a few weeks. In the meantime, we're also working on a few other ideas that are in the early mockup stage. I hope to show those off later this week. We are not going to let the perfect be the enemy of the good here.

Comment: @BrianTiffin: We don't know if templates are the answer. My best guess is they will be one more step in the right direction or not helpful at all. We have already tried something like what you are describing: [the triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage).

Comment: @MiguelLattuada: We've done some things to encourage [askers to mark their own questions as duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/1438). Duplicates are, of course, a huge problem. There's some work on the horizon that looks promising, but many questions are incorrectly marked as duplicate and many more are not closed, but should be.

Comment: @JonEricson great to hear, thanks.

Comment: I have no data to support this but my guess is that the vast majority of new questions have already been asked (and many answered). Perhaps one approach is to guide the asker towards existing questions that likely answer their question? Someone will/can probably pull some data that states that X% (some fairly low #) of questions are dups but I think we all know that many (aka lots) of questions are never properly duped and instead are answered again.

Comment: @Plutonix It's well known that people don't read walls of text, especially when they are forced to view the page with it, especially when they are in a hurry and want to do something else.

Comment: There are 3 reasons someone doesnt do something: they Cant (lack the tools, access, time, training...), they Wont or they Didnt Know They Were Supposed to.  Its been a while, but I know the new user stuff has a check for the Tour but I dont think it also mentions How To Ask.  if it doesnt, the new user process is partly to blame.

Comment: Whatever this ends up becoming to be, I hope you share your A/B testing results. The knowledge on this gathered on a big platform such as SO might be quite useful to numerous OSS projects.

Comment: Instead of a template, how about a separate stack exchange for dev newbies? There are a bazillion tutorial sites out there, but SO still seems to be the place newly learning devs want to come to ask their questions. Those and language issues are the majority of problems I see, and no template is going to solve either of those.

Comment: I still think that [having probation period before a question by a newish user can be answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252769/probationary-period-for-questions-to-be-answered-to-encourage-better-questions-w) will fundamentally change the behavior of and the dynamics of the gamification system ( which is broken now ). It will force them to think about what they are posting and it will discourage rep whores ( mostly high rep users already ) from answering duplicates.

Comment: Whatever you do, please don't add instructions to the default text field value like some people do for Github issues. It's so annoying.

Comment: PLEASE provide a question template that all users with less than a certain rep (dealers choice) are required to use and which has code block formatted required areas for 1) Sample Input, 2) Expected Output, and 3) What you've tried so far. 90+% of newbie questions have to immediately be replied to with  "please post sample input, expected output, and what you've tried so far" comment before we can do anything with it.

Comment: I know Jeff is no longer with Stack Exchange, but he posted an extremely relevant article on his blog a few years ago - [The "Just In Time" Theory of User Behavior](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-just-in-time-theory/).

Comment: @alexw: We pay attention to Jeff's articles because his influence is a big part of the reason we've had so much success in the past. Templates are another attempt at JIT help new askers. Thanks for the reminder of that post; it's been in the background of our thinking.

Comment: @JonEricson on GitHub, people have admitted to ignoring issue tracker templates because they [just assume they are boilerplate](https://twitter.com/userfrosting/status/923974406346563585), and that therefore there is no reason to bother reading them.  It's a difficult problem, and humans seem to have an innate ability to ignore TOS, boilerplate, and anything else that doesn't speak to them specifically as individuals.  If only there were a way to force people to actively engage with the content before they can post!

Comment: One of the things I've seen frequently lately is people asking about "the best way" to do something, rather than how to solve their particular problem.  This seems like potentially a low hanging fruit phrase that the site could catch.

Comment: I would suggest to detect some words from the posts like not working, crash etc. and in those scenarios don't let user post the question until it contain some code.

Comment: Should this mechanism be applicable to all sites in the SE network, or just SO?

Comment: @CaiusJard: For the moment, we are testing on SO since it's the quickest way to [A/B test the results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests). If the results look promising, there's no reason not to test the idea on other sites next.

Comment: How about a blanket ban on any questions that contain the word "best" ? :)

Comment: In terms of metrics you might want to consider "been edited" by someone else and "tags modified" by someone else. (Askers improving their own questions is good.)  The metrics you have listed really don't get at the concept of creating "good" questions, they get at the  concept of creating "not terrible" questions.

Comment: We can use Jon Skeet's question checklist as a guide I think: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: A good template should structure a question and, therefore, consist of a row of tags and two rows of checkboxes at the top, another row of checkboxes at the bottom and partitioned space in the middle:- "Describe your problem", "What is your question?", "Add your code". The checkboxes at the top should include such statements as "I want help writing code", "I can't find the solution" and other expressions of what people want. The checkboxes at the bottom should have items like "This is my first post", "I am an amateur/student" and perhaps "I am posting this question on several forums".

Answer (score 677):

How about a grab from the good old Microsoft bucket?

Click in the text field to activate the assistant.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.wmd-input').one('focus',function() {
    clippy.load('Clippy', function (agent) {
      var animations = agent.animations();
      $('.js-states').text(animations.join(' '));
      agent.show();
      agent.moveTo(400, 75);
      agent.speak('Hello, I see you\'re trying to ask a question. My name is Clippy and I\'d be happy to help.');
      agent.speak("Please provide a clear description of the problem you're encountering");
      agent._addToQueue(function(complete) {
          $('.wmd-input').val("I'm trying to see if `y` equals 10 but it gives an error");
          complete();
      });
      agent.moveTo(450, 105);
      agent.gestureAt(-100,50);
      agent.speak('If your code does not work, please include the exact error message you\'re getting.');
      
      agent._addToQueue(function(complete) {
          $('.wmd-input').val("I'm trying to see if `y` equals 10 but it gives an error\n\nMain.java:13: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean");
          
          complete();
      });
      agent.moveTo(505, 145);
      agent.gestureAt(-100,50);
      agent._addToQueue(function(complete) {
          $('.wmd-input').val("I'm trying to see if `y` equals 10 but it gives an error\n\nMain.java:13: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean\n\n public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception\n {\n     int y = 5;\n     if(y = 10) {\n     }\n \n     }");
          complete();
      });
      agent.speak('Also, when you include code, don\'t forget to add four spaces before each line so it will be formatted as code.');
      
      agent.moveTo(25, 200);
      agent.gestureAt(-100,50);
      
      agent.moveTo(385, 165);
      agent.speak('You can also select your code and then hit the "format as code" button');
      agent.moveTo(185, 115);
      agent.gestureAt(0,-50);
      
      agent.speak("A thanks (\"thank you\") is not necessary to end your post with.");
      agent.moveTo(630, 200);
      agent.speak("So, now you can start on your own question. For that we have a couple of questions to you that you can fill out");
      agent._addToQueue(function(complete) {
           $('.wmd-input').val("# What are you trying to achieve?");
          complete();
      });
      agent.moveTo(250, 110);
      agent.gestureAt(-100, 50);
      agent.speak("Please describe in short what you are trying to achieve");
      agent._addToQueue(function(complete) {
           $('.wmd-input').val("# What are you trying to achieve?\n\n# What is the problem you're facing?");
          complete();
      });
      agent.moveTo(275, 145);
      agent.gestureAt(-100, 50);
      agent.speak("Please describe the error you're getting, and/or post the error message you're getting");
      agent._addToQueue(function(complete) {
           $('.wmd-input').val("# What are you trying to achieve?\n\n# What is the problem you're facing?\n\n# Show the code causing the problem");
          complete();
      });
      agent.moveTo(275, 185);
      agent.gestureAt(-100, 50);
      agent.speak("Please post the code that causes your problem. Try to post it without clutter or unrelated code.");
      
      agent.speak("People who answer should be able to use your code to reproduce the error. Please lookup MCVE in the Stack Overflow help.");
      agent.moveTo(630, 200);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.post-editor {
   max-width:570px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.rawgit.com/smore-inc/clippy.js/master/build/clippy.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Shared/stacks.css?v=5bf1951d43be">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Sites/stackoverflowmeta/primary.css?v=62e4fabfbdec">
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/smore-inc/clippy.js/master/build/clippy.min.js'></script>
Click in the text field to activate assistant.
<div id="post-editor" class="post-editor js-post-editor">
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <div class="wmd-container">
            <div id="wmd-button-bar" class="wmd-button-bar"><ul id="wmd-button-row" class="wmd-button-row"><li class="wmd-button" id="wmd-bold-button" title="Strong <strong> Ctrl+B" style="left: 0px;"><span style="background-position: 0px 0px;"></span></li><li class="wmd-button" id="wmd-italic-button" title="Emphasis <em> Ctrl+I" style="left: 25px;"><span style="background-position: -20px 0px;"></span></li><li class="wmd-spacer wmd-spacer1" id="wmd-spacer1"></li><li class="wmd-button" id="wmd-link-button" title="Hyperlink <a> Ctrl+L" style="left: 75px;"><span style="background-position: -40px 0px;"></span></li><li class="wmd-button" id="wmd-quote-button" title="Blockquote <blockquote> Ctrl+Q" style="left: 100px;"><span style="background-position: -60px 0px;"></span></li><li class="wmd-button" id="wmd-code-button" title="Code Sample <pre><code> Ctrl+K" style="left: 125px;"><span style="background-position: -80px 0px;"></span></li><li class="wmd-button" id="wmd-image-button" title="Image <img> Ctrl+G" style="left: 150px;"><span style="background-position: -100px 0px;"></span></li><li class="wmd-button wmd-snippet-button" style="left:175px" id="wmd-snippet-button" title="JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet Ctrl-M"><span style="background-image: url(&quot;/content/Shared/balsamiq/wmd-mockup-button.png&quot;);"></span></li><li class="wmd-spacer wmd-spacer2" id="wmd-spacer2" style="left: 220px;"></li><li class="wmd-button" id="wmd-olist-button" title="Numbered List <ol> Ctrl+O" style="left: 225px;"><span style="background-position: -120px 0px;"></span></li><li class="wmd-button" id="wmd-ulist-button" title="Bulleted List <ul> Ctrl+U" style="left: 250px;"><span style="background-position: -140px 0px;"></span></li><li class="wmd-button" id="wmd-heading-button" title="Heading <h1>/<h2> Ctrl+H" style="left: 275px;"><span style="background-position: -160px 0px;"></span></li><li class="wmd-button" id="wmd-hr-button" title="Horizontal Rule <hr> Ctrl+R" style="left: 300px;"><span style="background-position: -180px 0px;"></span></li><li class="wmd-spacer wmd-spacer3" id="wmd-spacer3" style="left: 346px;"></li><li class="wmd-button" id="wmd-undo-button" title="Undo - Ctrl+Z" style="left: 350px;"><span style="background-position: -200px -20px;"></span></li><li class="wmd-button" id="wmd-redo-button" title="Redo - Ctrl+Y" style="left: 375px;"><span style="background-position: -220px -20px;"></span></li><li class="wmd-button wmd-help-button" id="wmd-help-button" title="Markdown Editing Help" style="right: 0px;"><span style="background-position: -240px 0px;"></span></li></ul></div>
            <textarea id="wmd-input" class="wmd-input processed" name="post-text" cols="92" rows="15" tabindex="101" data-min-length=""></textarea>
        <div class="grippie" style="margin-right: 0px;"></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fl" style="margin-top: 8px; height:24px;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="draft-saved" class="draft-saved community-option fl" style="margin-top: 8px; height:24px; display:none;">draft saved</div>
    <div id="draft-discarded" class="draft-discarded community-option fl" style="margin-top: 8px; height:24px; display:none;">draft discarded</div>
    <div class="community-option g-row ai-center f-checkbox">
        <div class="g-col -input">
            <input id="communitymode" name="communitymode" type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <div class="g-col">
            <label for="communitymode" class="f-label _small" title="Marking an answer community wiki encourages others to edit it by lowering the reputation barrier required to edit. However, you will not gain any upvote reputation from it. This cannot be undone.">community wiki</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome. (Shame the snippet output is so small)

Comment: yea, you can still click full screen though.

Comment: "don't forget to add four spaces before each line" - sounds like an exquisite torture. I'd recommend replacing that hint with something like "click on the 'format code' button" or adding `<pre><code>`.

Comment: it's clippy, isn't that all about torture? Also, feel free to code in example help things you feel like could be added ;-)

Comment: It must respond to voice though so you can ask it questions without having to do something as outdated as typing. How long to develop that?

Comment: depends, will involve a html5 voice autorisation popup/bar that the page requests authorisation for voice recognition etc.. https://shapeshed.com/html5-speech-recognition-api/

Comment: @Tschallacka the only answer I accept is "6-8 weeks".

Comment: so you mean never right? @Gimby

Comment: The answer is cool, the idea is terrible. Please don't do that, there is a reason Microsoft removed it(it sucked). Unless this was obvious joke to everybody then please ignore my comment.

Comment: I just take every oppurtunity i get to showcase clippy ;-)

Comment: L E T  C L I P P Y  D I E

Comment: I think this qualifies for the `rude or abusive` flag: A reasonable person would find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse.

Comment: I am torn. I can't in good conscience upvote clippy, but at the same time, this is awesome. :/

Comment: Does SO just have all the clippy animations stored on its server?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro google clippy.js

Comment: At least use [Scribble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qR6IJQcDFok).

Comment: That's **_a w e s o m e_**

Comment: Did you know that clippy is the most hated virtual assistant ever made?

Comment: Yes i do. I grew up with 3.q, then 95, then 98. I had memorised how to disable after reinstalling windows for umpteenth time

Comment: Would you mind formatting clippy's dialog as a template so that it's easier to see how your answer addresses the question?

Comment: Sure. Already had ideas to that extent

Comment: I am reluctantly upvoting this.

Comment: @JonEricson I added a "template" ish style.

Comment: @Tschallacka I believe (correct me if I'm wrong, @JonEricson), Jon was asking to include the dialog/prompts in your post directly, so that it's easier for viewers to read without having to actually run the script

Comment: That awkward moment when you try to shoot Clippy, but all the bullets pass through...

Comment: Obviously, Clippy has to be replaced with a unicorn. Other than that, Clippy was hated because it popped up when you didn't want it/need it. "Hi, it looks like you are writing a letter!" No I'm not, GTFO and let me work! Coding it so that it only pops up when actually needed is quite a challenge, one that Microsoft failed.

Comment: Maybe pop in one of those AI systems, train it on bad beginners questions and let it give the best help?

Comment: Design a new mascot! Seriously though, I agree with @Lundin, Clippy is obtrusive. Maybe a horizontal bar with useful text tips would be better. They can pop up at the right moment, while still giving the asker focus on writing his question

Comment: Hahahahah, this is absolutly brilliant and made me laugh a lot. Clippy!!! Hahaha well done!

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooo

Comment: I actually like the idea of an assistant for those with less than x number of questions asked/answered. Then it would be optional. And stack should make their own. I personally like the idea of a cartoon speech bubble.

Comment: When you support voice control don't forget to lecture people on manners when they suggest violent death or contortionist autoerotica..

Comment: hah, hah  :-D    I'm guessing this is not the idea of "template" really on offer, though.

Comment: Make this man moderator already. Bravo what an answer

Comment: Added a bit more templating.

Comment: This is way better than telling the user to go through 'How to ask' page...

Comment: @Tomm Are you crazy to suggest that?! He'll insert Clippy into the flagging interface!

Comment: @ivan_pozdeez "hello, I see you're trying to flag a question. Would you like help with that?"

Comment: @yeputons don't ever use `<pre>`, it won't do any syntax highlighting. Ctrl+K works better

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc When combined with `<code>` on StackOverflow, it does.

Comment: You officially won internet.

Comment: Why all the negative attitude guys?? Look at him... He's cute! God I wish they've made them in furries

Comment: @NicolasMiari That which is dead cannot die...

Comment: except this does nothing that `wait(60000);` could not accomplish equally well for the targeted user group

Comment: How did I miss this one. So good. I was on the Office team when the ideas for  Clippy were incubated. Did you know that Melinda Gates ran the team that originally came up with the idea for the anthropomorphized, "helpful" creatures. See [Microsoft Bob](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-only-truly-failed-project/)

Comment: @JoeFriend it looks cool actually https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5teG6ou8mWU shame it flopped.

Comment: Haha ! Clippy is draggable ! Awesome :-D

Comment: +2 for the idea, -1 for Clippy. :o) Get rid of the avatar, rotate the speech bubbles 90º, and have the bubble point at the template segment. Make the thing user called not mandatory (with a [?] or some such on the toolbar.)

Comment: I think that stack overflow should have its own version of Clippy, perhaps a variant on the main logo? It should also be a profile setting (unlocked after a certain amount of reputation, to prevent people disabling it right away), in case it gets too annoying.

Comment: actually Microsoft seems to be figuring some "Virtual Agent" popup at the bottom-right of their support pages lately

Comment: @Skipper great, I can't unread that one.

Comment: So conflicted.  On the one hand, I _love_ how interactive this is; on the other, it seems like this should have a rude/abusive flag for including that paperclip... bah, +1.

Comment: I was more a Microsoft Minki guy... Anyway. So cute!

Comment: I think this is good for those people who are explicitly new to SO, they will be taught how to properly ask questions rather than some guys who would just slapped them with "have your tried reading the how to post FAQS"

Answer (score 168):

edit - other suggestions here are better.

---

Here's the deal.

Most people asking bad questions won't grok the idea of MVCE and understand that enough. Because getting there requires a lot more understanding than they have.

So you have to spoon feed it.

Most programming questions on SO would be 100x better if the OP included:

1. What are you trying to do?
2. What is your code that currently tries to do that?
3. What do you expect the result to be?
4. What is the actual result?

There are issues with conceptual questions not fitting that framework (sort of, I'd argue conceptual questions are a different category and small enough that it's not an issue as most first time question askers don't ask them anyways). But nearly all programming questions that answer those four questions correctly will be answerable or duplicatedable (tm).

Also, "how do I do X?" types of questions are *slightly* hit by this. But I don't really have a problem expecting people to at least *try*.

My assumption is this template will be prepopulated text into the question box like:

[image: question template]

Metrics from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278444/193412) would still work fine.

Comment: It's worth noting that a full MVCE would be an absolutely _great_ outcome. But I don't think anyone who reads the wasteland of the questions that need improvement would expect that people could go from "gimme teh codez pls" to a valid MVCE..

Comment: I like your questions! (But not the suggestion of "marking" some posters for downvotes without much review).  What do you think about, "What, if anything have you already tried that hasn't worked?"

Comment: Those are, for what it's worth, the 4 items I was thinking about when I imagined a template. If someone includes them, it's usually possible for someone else to edit out other cruft (greetings, rants, unrelated symptoms, etc.). But without them, the question will be very hard to answer.

Comment: @Jaydles I expect a lot of people answeirng "I haven't tried anything so I'll leave this section blank." I want SO to help develop people to be better software engineers. Requiring a slight bit of effort on the part of people asking questions is a small gesture but goes a long way towards that goal imo..

Comment: I assume the problem with the reworded version is that it leaves an opening for the user to just skip it rather than providing what they tried. but that opening is always there anyway.

Comment: Just to be clear, when we are A/B testing, you won't know which users got which template. Plus, there will be a control group who gets the same empty box as always. I expect folks will continue to vote as they always do: on the content of the question and not the identity/background of the asker.

Comment: You had me up until your commentary starting with 'For what it's worth I would also like..." this is a going to be a test initially, some people will get the template, others won't. Voting should still be done based on the question not whether or not they followed a template.

Comment: @bluefeet my assumption was this would be prepulated into the question box. Is that not the case?

Comment: That paragraph is hard to parse. Are you talking about the folks who'll ignore the template completely and post a question with the template text still in place (not filled in / replaced)? Because yeah, that'll probably happen to some extent, and probably get the same treatment as the folks who copy-paste the sidebar text into their questions to get past the length restrictions. Not worth worrying about 'em.

Comment: @enderland I'm not really involved with how this is going to be implemented, but your commentary at the end is taking away from the suggested questions that you have proposed. What I'm pointing out in my initial comment is that it's an A/B test meaning some people will see the template others won't, so saying you should vote on whether or they followed a template isn't correct because not everyone will see it. I personally would remove the commentary about voting/helping the OP and make this about your proposed template.

Comment: @Shog9 I clarified. Yes, that's what I was anticipating and directing that paragraph towards.

Comment: @JonEricson if it's prepulated markdown placeholders it would be pretty obvious who got it if they didn't edit it out of their question.

Comment: @enderland: I don't see any reason to be _extra_ critical of people who don't follow the template. If anything, that's a sign that the template isn't working. Let's focus on fixing the system, shall we?

Comment: @JonEricson I think this is where our goals may be different. I want to optimize the SO experience for everyone, primarily question answerers and secondarily question askers. I want something to make it so people who blatantly ignore the "asking a question" requirements not waste the time of people who spend their time trying to help people. If someone literally cannot follow a template such as either the image or the (4) points the level of effort I want people to expend to help them to be as close to zero as possible.

Comment: I think our goals are the same. But imagine an intersection where people keep getting into accidents. The city might come along and put up a warning sign and say that further accidents are not the city's problem. (This is the position I think you are taking.) On the other hand, the city could dig a bit deeper and look for other underlying problems and solutions. (This is my position.) If a template solves the problem, great! But my guess is that it's just one small part of a bigger solution.

Comment: Another option here would be to just blacklist portions of the template such that the question could not be posted with it in place. But... This feels like solving the wrong problem up-front; if that ends up being commonplace, templates are probably the wrong solution here.

Comment: @JonEricson I see your analogy this way - The city put up a STOP sign(template) if people are not going to follow the rules and ignore it cops should fine them(users should downvote and don't answer) doesn't mean that the city can't improve the intersection(improve the system). P.S. Don't know what the results will be but it's great you're testing this people have been requesting changes for years and I was sure it will never happen.

Comment: @JonEricson that's a bad analogy. A better one would be your city has a driving test that requires applicants to fill out an application. Some applicants do not fill out the application and are consequentially penalized (questions downvote/closed) and those that do receive drivers licenses and can drive. Asking a question on SO and receiving an answer are not a _right_ to OPs.

Comment: @Oleg: Maybe less like a stop sign and more like a [dangerous bend sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbaki_dangerous_bend_symbol). The cops continue to enforce the existing rules as always. The city could remove, change or augment the sign without any change to enforcement. (Except, of course, one would want to have fewer tickets and whatnot with the sign than without.) We've tried the "punish lazy askers" thing for _years_ and long past time we try something else.

Comment: @JonEricson Ignoring a warning sign can cause a fine for careless driving so the rules somewhat change... I think most people would rather want to concentrate on having fewer accidents then fewer fines. It's something else but it's also a new way of identifying extremely lazy askers. If they can be identified this way I see no reason not to punish them.

Comment: @JonEricson "We've tried the "punish lazy askers" thing for years" -- the thing is, it's never been clear when people are actually making a legitimate effort vs dumping text. Any templating you do will by implication clarify this. Regardless I removed that chunk from the answer as it's not directly relevant to the actual AB study.

Comment: _"We've tried the 'punish lazy askers' thing for *years*..."_ Sort of. What we've done is like "punishing" coyotes by not letting them into the house to sit down at the dinner table. But they don't give two toots about that. They just want a sheep to eat. And we don't do a whole lot to prevent them from getting their sheep, or to keep them out of the paddock _in the first place_ until we know that they're here to farm, not steal.

Comment: @JoshCaswell that's unfair to the coyotes.  They never communicate any lies such as 'I searched all the other farms and could not find any sheep at all'.

Comment: I just looked over my top 10 questions by score, and then over the top 10 questions by score on all of Stack Overflow. Not one of them fits the format of this template or could reasonably be contorted to fit into it. I completely oppose presenting users with this template; it's incorrect for all non-debugging questions, but *most debugging questions are crap* and this template does nothing to combat the two of the most common ways that they're crap - the code provided being incomplete or too long. We should not be optimising for slightly-less-abrasive sand at the cost of excluding all pearls.

Comment: @MarkAmery I long for the dream where only good questions are accepted on Stack Overflow and to be honest, most debugging types of questions are crap. But Stack Overflow as a company has consistently been pushing the "quantity > quality" approach for _years_ now so I'm hoping to make do with what options are available :(

Comment: I wouldn't put the code at the very top. Defeats the purpose of summaries/previews in questions page. Start with a short description of the problem instead. Also consider changing the title watermark text to "what would be a good search phrase to find a solution to your problem?"

Comment: @JoshCaswell: My objection to this line of reasoning is that the template idea is intended to help users who don't know how to ask produce marginally more useful questions. And the tone here is "Thanks for the bludgeon!" It's almost as if nobody remembers we have downvotes, community-powered deletion, automated deletion, question bans, answer bans, rate limits, suspensions, blacklists, quality filters, interstitial pages, required signups to ask, flags, low-quality review, etc and so on. Negative reinforcement is valuable, but suffers from diminishing returns.

Comment: Yes, I see what you're getting at there, @JonEricson. My point was just about the form of the reinforcement. I'm glad the template is being tried, and I hope it leads to further improvements beyond, so I will say no more on this.

Comment: ...did you purposely pick *won't grok* as the most obscure synonym you could find for *hard to understand*?

Comment: @TinyGiant I just found it amusing that I had to lookup the definition for grok, a word which means "to understand intuitively".

Comment: -1 Like your previous template, this suggestion *still* makes new users think SO is a "fix my code" service. It's not. It's a "teach me things so I can fix my own code" service.

Comment: The stop sign only works because people are aware of the penalties incurred by disregarding it. Maybe making the penalties clearer will make new users think twice before posting a lazy question.

Comment: “What is the actual result?” Including error messages for goodness sake, they are a result!

Comment: "Most people asking bad questions won't grok the idea of MVCE" - agree; "So you have to spoon feed it" - heavily disagree. In most cases, no amount of work will ever turn their crap questions into good questions, as the question usually amounts to "help, I have no idea what I'm doing" and is just the trilionth iteration of a beginner syntax or sematic error. The best outcome would be if the user, by virtue of the question template, either solves their problem by themselves (e.g. due to being prompted to do more research) or realizes it is a bad fit for SO and abandons it completely.

Comment: Maybe it's just my taste for minimalism, but I really like to begin with a blank clean textarea before beginning to write anything. I really dislike such long-text placeholders. (Personal feeling).

Comment: Love it, simple and we don't have people asking to [kill clippy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions?cb=1#comment524056_358027)

Comment: instead of "answer here" I would suggest to put "explain here". Answer for some ppeople could suggest that, the "Answer" should be put into that field.

Comment: This is the most annoying solution ever. I can't stand this on github issues.

Comment: @xendi I recently added this to a fairly popular repo. The quality of issues we've received has gone up drastically since then....

Comment: @jpmc26... respectfully disagree for two reasons. 1) There are many times where people do fix someone else's code and both the asker and answerers have no issue with this. In fact, this is sometimes the exact piece of learning that needs to happen. 2) If you're proposing that people don't answer "what's wrong with my code" questions then that opens up a different meta topic about what this forum is exactly about.

Comment: @pnuts... great suggestion. Not enough people discuss their code from the point of view of their data.

Comment: @Andrew http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm The longer you're here, the more you'll see it. Also see the MSE discussion about it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665/216712. Note that such a situation is *very* unattractive to people trying to answer questions, without which this site is useless. Also see the [What have you tried?](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) article.

Comment: @jpmc26... I've been on here for years and have seen such questions. If they're too lame then i don't bother. But those questions also pose value to someone like me who is years later to the SO party. If all users asked perfect, non redundant, questions then someone like me would never have questions to answer that someone hadn't already (ergo no points). I also see it as the responsibility of the mature users of SO to guide new users into the style and etiquete of SO, which is currently abrupt and rude on average. SO isolates new users by behavior of many mature users.

Comment: @Andrew "If all users asked perfect, non redundant, questions then someone like me would never have questions to answer that someone hadn't already (ergo no points)." SO doesn't exist to hand out points. SO doesn't exist to answer every question as though it's a unique snowflake. If after 10 years of SO you find yourself asking a C question, you should *expect* someone else has asked it before unless it's about new standards and features. You should be surprised if you can't find an existing question.

Comment: "I also see it as the responsibility of the mature users of SO to guide new users into the style and etiquete of SO, which is currently abrupt and rude on average. SO isolates new users by behavior of many mature users." And I see it as the responsibility of new users to be respectful of the time and effort of people willing to answer. I was never "isolated" when I first came because I *put in the hard work* to ask decent questions and tried to write good answers. I actually haven't written very many of either, but I didn't have a hard time finding a place to contribute in my own small way.

Comment: @Andrew And you know what? Part of the reason most of my questions and answers were well received is because I  never set out to write a lot of either. I waited until I had a clear point of confusion or a real world problem I needed advice on. I wait until I'm confident that I have an answer that represents a real improvement over what everyone else was saying, and I check through other answers to make sure I'm not saying the same thing differently. I've probably thrown away just as many started questions and answers as I've posted. *That's* the level of quality I expect of myself and others.

Comment: @jpmc26... and that's great that you have that level of professionalism. You know a lot and learned a lot to be as you are. Not everyone has that level at this current moment in time but with the good counsel and coaching of mature and professional users like yourself, then new users have a greater chance of increasing the quality of their use of SO.  Additionally, points are an important aspect of SO but that's obvious. New users have very limited abilities to contribute to SO, so bringt able to gather points is necessary.

Comment: @Andrew Except I don't "know a lot." The reason I am this way is because I was never given a choice. I've never had people that would just hand me answers. I learned to be this way because I was *forced to struggle through my own problems* and acquire knowledge and understanding for myself. And so at this point, it's just become normal. Getting people to stop asking questions is a great way to put them in a position to learn to think that way. Handing them the answers only teaches them that they can't think for themselves.

Comment: @jpmc26. 1) you have over 11K points, so you clearly know more than most SO newbies. 2) I'm not asking you to just give people answers. I'm merely positing that there are occasions and learning styles where that approach is the most effective. Additionally, you have learned a lot about your approach to learning, and that's something you can pass on to the SO newbies in the way you edit questions or give OP feedback about their question. 3) "Handing people the answers..." I disagree that this is the only and absolute outcome. It can lower barrier to entry and encourage people to keep learning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158756/discussion-between-jpmc26-and-andrew).

Comment: In my experience people are already overtaxed with the full scope of themes of apparent equal importance. After the request to "find out more..." the Help > Answers > mcve info is placed as last theme above "view more ...". 'So it isn't perceived as important and  I doubt if it's read in any case. -
As a consequence I'd strongly encourage to add a) a *conspicuous demand* for mcve questions like e.g. "SO participation demands a question that summarizes the specific problem as well as b) a icon link to mcve within the question box (prepopulated text as suggested by @enderland).

Comment: also a brief information on what kind of project they are working can help to understand the context of the problem and suggest better solution if possible then what OP is currently doing

Answer (score 110):

There's a bit of information that the *current* ask-question page strongly implies an asker should have, maybe even assists them in obtaining, asks them to include, but doesn't currently *demand*: **research**.

Let's face it: in the areas where we see the most frustration over low-quality questions, the problem is invariably that *most of them have already been asked* in one form or another. Which leaves two possibilities:

1. The asker didn't understand the answer(s) on the existing questions(s) they found when searching, or...
2. ...the asker didn't search.

Now, #2 is probably quite a bit less likely than we often assume. Something like 95% of all traffic to the site comes from search engines, so folks who don't search are in a tiny minority right from the start...

But even for folks who long ago bookmarked the site and now use it as their first option when a problem arises, we try really hard to prevent #2 from happening: there's an interstitial with a search box on it for new askers, the ask page automatically searches for a title once one is entered, and the *entire sidebar* fills in with related questions once a question is typed.

Which means at some point if you're still typing a question, you probably have a whole pile of links to existing questions that *didn't solve your problem*.

Thing is, the folks reading the question after it's asked can't see the hours put into fruitless searching. They just see a question that looks an awful lot like a bunch of existing questions. If only the asker had summarized their research...

**Let's ask for that research right off the bat.**

```
##I've already read the following related questions but they didn't solve my problem

<!-- enter links to other questions you found while researching your problem
     and explain why they didn't help -->

1. question one link "Didn't help because..."
2. question two link "Didn't help because..."
...
```

Comment: Your suggestion is good because it might make people to actually do some research. You needed to jump through some hoops to shift the blame on the answerers though. 95% seems high at first glance but when you realize that SO has 50 million unique visitors per month the 5% minority suddenly doesn't look so tiny. Your other points like SO search which you base them on are also of questionable quality.

Comment: Not sure what your point is, @oleg. These aren't intended to be shocking revelations. Most people who use SO don't even have an account much less ask questions - that's sorta the whole point. I've posted numbers on the rest before too. Getting folks to share their research has been a constant headache for, oh, about 8 years now, because it makes everything difficult when they don't. I don't see why that should be controversial.

Comment: Your claim that it's not likely that many askers are doing exactly zero research before asking questions is controversial. And my point is that the points you made to support that claim are not very good. It looks like you started with that conclusion and then looked for a way to support it.

Comment: I didn't make such a claim, @oleg. Something like 5% of questions asked are closed as duplicates, so somewhere > than 5% of askers either aren't searching at all or are searching badly. That's a lot of questions on Stack Overflow, and this project isn't likely to help them. Honestly... There are a lot of askers who are probably beyond help. We're not looking for new lost causes here; focus your attention on areas where folks *could* do better if they knew what to do.

Comment: When faced with 'I searched the whole internet and could not find anything to help', I often comment 'Please tell us what search string/s you used so that we might suggest a better one', (knowing that copying the OP's title into Google will surely return millions of matches).  So far, I've had no responses. 100% OP failure.

Comment: That 95% coming into SO from a search engine, how much of that lands on a actual question? How many google (for example) _"stackoverflow"_ or _"Programming questions"_ and end on the frontpage?

Comment: This has made me think back to an old feature request I made: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting

Comment: #2 should be the asker didn't search *enough*. There are plenty of people with a short attention span out there who don't go beyond 1 or 2 search results and even then they can be prone to only skim rather than effectively read. If we're going to bring more attention to research then we had better define very well what is research: it is definitely not spending less than 2 minutes in any search engine.

Comment: @Gimby Re: _"... we had better define very well what is research: it is definitely not spending less than 2 minutes in any search engine."_: Shog kinda did that in his answer here. It's about linking the questions that you looked at which are similar but didn't solve your problem. Note that doing so is not—and should not be—required, but it can be helpful to do so. This is about giving advice to those who would benefit, not standing over them cracking a whip.

Comment: One wrinkle here is that we can't ask users with [less than 10 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) to include more than two hyperlinks. (Unless this restriction excludes links to other questions on the site? Even so, it'll be frustrating if those folks want to link to outside documentation instead.) Maybe search strings as @MartinJames suggested?

Comment: @Cerbrus: I can say with confidence that nobody ends up on the frontpage via [Programming questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=Programming+questions).

Comment: I kinda feel like this is getting into the weeds, @Cerbrus... But, looking at Google Analytics, about 14% of searches lead to the homepage (and about a third of them bounce - no further page-views on the site). Also: based on the internal data I have available, folks ask questions after viewing an existing question about twice as often as they ask questions after viewing the homepage. For new users (no account prior to asking), it's about 3 times as many. Finally, about 6% of askers search from the interstitial page and about 7% click one of the automatic search results on the ask page.

Comment: We don't currently, but we could whitelist question links, @Jon. Or we could ask both: "What did you search for?" and "What did you find?"

Comment: @Shog9: My intention with the question was to determine what part of those searching actually end up asking a question here as a result of said search. From what I can tell from your comment, a pretty significant amount.

Comment: A shockingly tiny amount as a % of the whole, @Cerbrus - under half of 1%. That's still a big absolute number simply because SO gets a lot of traffic, but the vast, vast, vast majority of folks find what they're looking for and go on with their day; asking a question is a failure path.

Comment: Oh, that's a slight misinterpretation on my part then...

Comment: Big numbers are hard. 10,000 questions in a day is a lot of questions, but a drop in the bucket in terms of folks visiting the site. Most people using Stack Overflow do not ask questions; those that do are a rounding error.

Comment: If the links and especially the "didn't help because" go into the question body, I think it would be distracting and a bit against the "knowledge repository" idea. Could this be posted as comments instead? Each link/explanation as one comment for example.

Comment: I donno, @alain - cross-links to related questions can be handy. Probably shouldn't be the first thing in the question body though.

Comment: @JonEricson Maybe it's time to revisit the link restriction. What was it put there for, and what does it do now? If anything, allowing people to put unlimited hyperlinks in their post would make it *easier* for SmokeDetector and others to catch them.

Comment: @alain The question can be cleaned up after it is answered.  We even have a series of badges that aim to encourage answerers to clean up questions on their own, and the answerers are in position to know what research is useful for explaining what the question isn't about versus just being noise.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom For the record, badges have literally zero impact on me. IMO the only metric remotely motivating is rep

Comment: I agree with @alain on this one, the "didn't help because" links are rarely useful to me as a reader; related topics tend to show up anyway in Google and on the right. I disagree with [gnat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/321006) on this one. Also please don't encourage users to put lists saying more or less "Here are a list of things that only sound similar if you don't understand the topic" on otherwise clear cut questions, it's probably a waste of time. IMO a "duplicate until proven new" strategy for closure just encourages OPs to add unrelated junk into their posts.

Comment: What constitutes "research" to one person may not constitute research to another. Much documentation is written for people with a certain level of experience, which the person asking the question may not have. Some documentation requires the user to know where to look, which they might not know. 

And sometimes people have read the documentation and still can't find the answer but get accused of not having done research. (i'm in that boat with a standing question I have about getting ERC work the way I want .. .) 

Demanding "research" actually will discourage people coming here to learn.

Comment: @DavidWagle This might come off wrong, but I do believe there should be a threshold of asker knowledge. It is rather obvious if you take it to the extreme: if someone claims they didn't google something because they literally don't know how, you'd still close that question

Comment: Random idea, use a cookie to remember their searches for the last 5-10 since before starting to enter a question. No searches, strong suggestion that they search. Also note that some bug reporting systems, like for Firefox or WebKit have forms that effectively say "I searched and did not find anything" which is how you actually get to the "enter a bug" page. In fact I think it's firefox that you enter your title, it gives a list of results, only after seeing that list of results are you allowed to pick "My issue is not listed above" and enter a bug. https://imgur.com/a/lIH6R

Comment: @gman Hiding the submit form is actually the road that some online services have taken, especially those servicing the general public. Quite often, it takes a sizable amount of, well, _research_ to finally locate it.

Comment: @gman I don't know how you search... but I use Google rather than the site search - including when I see an embedded search box such as when linking duplicates. Good luck to Stack Overflow to keep track of that.

Comment: Just an update, @JonEricson comments is partly invalid as the restriction was raised to 8.

Comment: @gimby I think the suggestion of tracking is a great one - often even as a fairly experienced user I can't necessarily remember which of the recent questions I looked at was most likely relevant, and end up going to history and browsing through them all again. Putting the questions in my face would make me more likely to actually take the time and link out to them.

Answer (score 105):

Please don't add a template in the text field.

- New users have problems enough formatting their questions *without* there being any markdown in the field, already: We regularly see `enter code here` in questions.
- This will result in users just posting the template, resulting in more maintenance to remove template left-overs.
- There is no format that is a good fit for all questions, meaning you'll be misleading part of your new users.

If you want to (strongly) suggest a specific format, you'd need to split the question into separate fields, much like how Chromium bug reports can be submitted:

**(Obviously the fields would be different)**

> [image]

Comment: What if a user don't have an url to reproduce?

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, the url isn't a required field. Also, note _"much like how..."_. I'm not claiming these are the desired fields, just that I prefer separate fields over a template in the text.

Comment: Now this I like.

Comment: Fully agree that we shouldn’t give a template to fill out. But I also don’t think a fill-out form will work either, for the same reason you already mentioned: *“There is no format that is a good fit for all questions”*. – I would rather see some checklist of stuff to include.

Comment: @poke: That's be nice. Just like the ones you sometimes see for password fields, maybe requiring 90% of the checkmarks to be checked....

Comment: Yes, this. On the Tweakers.net forum they do this when posting a hardware recommendation topic. Plenty of topics are opened with all the placeholders there, not entered but skipped altogether, under which the OP asks _"Is graphics card X a good fit for game Y?"_. Anyway, if we build this wizard, it should be customizable per tag. Regex questions should have entirely different inputs than, say, C# questions.

Comment: Does that bug report page really say, _"Does this feature work correctly other browsers?"_

Comment: I am strongly for at least two input fields -- since we really really want users to show relevant code, why not add a field where you can paste code and have it included with code-formatting automatically.

Comment: @Gus: Often, we need multiple different code snippets in an question / answer. One field isn't really practical.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, this is another path we are looking at. The advantage of question templates is that they are _much easier to implement, test and modify_. Let's not forget the [lessons of Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348030/is-documentation-a-failed-experiment/348143#348143) so quickly.

Comment: @JonEricson: Yea, I realize that. I just wanted a _"I prefer a form"_ represented in a answer here.

Comment: On the topic of "enter code here", there are [1000+ questions and answers with that string right now.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22enter%20code%20here%22)

Comment: This looks very useful for web technologies, but for C/++/#/Java the URL, site and browser related fields are not very relevant.

Comment: I want to upvote your answer for the parts you wrote, but the mere presence of a bug report page screenshot makes me very uncomfortable with upvoting. There's already *so* much emphasis on bug reporting elements here.

Comment: @jpmc26: That screenshot is ___just an example of a form___. It's an example of how you'd split up the fields. Nowhere am I suggesting we use something close to this format.

Comment: @canon: I assume you're referring to the grammatical error, but if not, I guess the Chrome team wants to give the impression that they're interested in interop...

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah, I know. I guess it just bothers me because I know people skim and misunderstand. Not really asking you to change it. Just... expressing my displeasure. xD

Comment: _New users have problems enough formatting their questions [...]_ So it's just another reason to help them learn, how to format text properly. Bad formatting == bad question.

Comment: @Skipper: Even something as basic as `enter code here` isn't properly formatted by some new users. How is adding more template syntax going to help them?

Comment: Chromium's bug tracker system is one of the _least_ accessible to new comers. I'm not sure if we should borrow ideas from it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: The system as a whole, maybe, but I don't think there's anything unclear about a form like that with step-by-step guidance...

Comment: I don't think this would work; any wizard would be too rigid. Questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/5212501) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/5212501) aren't going to fit the same wizard as a "why did my code throw this error" question. Templates give suggestions which an experienced user can ignore. Wizards give rules which nobody can ignore. Admittedly, a bad question asker could ignore a template too, but I'd rather that than see users (experienced or not) try to contort a question into preassigned fields.

Comment: @LordFarquaad: That's kindof my point. There is no template that's a good fit, just as there is no wizard that's a good fit.

Comment: I really like this idea, but if you do implement this for new users, *please make it toggle-able for everyone* (assisted/free-form toggle): I envision a new user asking a good first question and getting enough up-votes to no longer qualify for the template, so then they'll get shoved into the deep end and we'll just get 50-150 rep users asking what 1 rep users used to ask. This also potentially fixes the wizard not being a good fit for all questions: "Your question doesn't fit the form? Switch to free-form" (or would it be form-free in this case?)

Comment: This was buried in the comments on the Q but I think this is along the lines of what you are suggesting... a form to fill in: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253317/2386774... +1 for mock ups, -1 for no hand drawn circles. :(

Comment: this is much more my idea of a useful template......   I think notes in a single question box will be too easily ignored, and even confusing to some people.  Even more powerful, this allows truly required fields to be required......   you can't force someone to put a good code sample, but if they won't even fill in the box, it's a no-go.   And when people put junk in a required & well-defined box, it is really easy for folks to ignore & flag.

Comment: Different kinds of questions need different kinds of forms.  [As discussed on another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions?cb=1#comment524033_357956), a template or form that assumes the user has a debugging question might *discourage* people from asking other kinds of questions, and make people think that SO is intended mostly as a debugging-help site.  Debugging questions are usually the least valuable / interesting.

Comment: The template idea has been tried several times before. Most informatively with requirements. Use Cases got so heavily bogged down in formulaic templating that they fell into disfavor and were re-invented as user stories in order to de-clutter the result. If templates are used at all they need to be minimal. You might be able to create templates that have templates for constructs that need elaboration. However it might be good practice for the answerer to use a template to re-formulate the question. That is more likely to be useful, accurate, and well formed.

Answer (score 94):

How about introducing a **Question Score (Question Strength)**?

When an OP writes the question inside the editor, the score will increase or decrease based on the input. Something similar to this GIF:

[image: GIF]

The question strength can be computed based on the information entered in the template as illustrated in the below image (PS It's just an illustration): (Score from 20)

[image: Score]

---

The **question score** can convey OP about many things regarding the questions viz.:

- Question Quality (If the question score is less, the question potentially is unfit for the site, or might attract downvotes).
- Probable response the question likely to receive (a fair question score indicates that question is fit enough to receive a positive response).
- Possible improvements (Consider the above image. Suppose the OP enters template section 2 only and does not write his problem in template section 1, he will not get 4 points; this will indicate to the OP to fill that particular section in detail, leading to an improved score and overall question improvement)

The Boosters:

- We can further expand this idea by awarding badges, for example, >5 questions with full question score, >100 questions with full question score, etc.
- The question score can be displayed in the review queues (First Posts, Edit Review Queues, etc.) that will help reviewers to take more quicker and clearer decisions.

The Pros:

- Asking question will be little interactive. The static template alone might not do the magic alone.
- Since this will be done while a question is being asked, it is more likely that the efforts spent to cleanup and sort number of questions by reviewers may decrease automatically.

The Cons:

- Determining a threshold and proper score (can be solved by experts who have data).
- In case when template is erased fully, how will a score be determined (can be solved by programmers).

Comment: This is a very good idea!

Comment: Interestingly, we do have a quality score we use to screen out questions before they are posted. We don't go into a lot of detail about what trips the filter because it'd be easier just bypass it. Last week 47% of all attempts to ask were blocked by one of our many quality filters. Showing the score dynamically as you suggest is an interesting idea for the next few steps of this project (the wizard design). It's not something we'll be able to do with the simple template.

Comment: @JonEricson woah 47% is indeed a huge number! Will wait till the tests/suggestions for the wizard design begins on meta then :)

Comment: If you want to make this super effective, allow questions on the front page to be sorted by question score.  Natural selection will prevent bad questions from getting attention.

Comment: We could combine this idea with a wizard (which I really like) and score them on each part. They must achieve a certain score on each panel to proceed. If they don't have research to document (which is represented by a 0 score on this panel of the wizard), then they can't get past this panel and therefore can't finish their submission. This prevents bad questions from being asked but still guides askers as to what they need to do to finish their submission... go do research, provide an MCVE, and so on. The wizard walks them through the process and the ratings score the quality of each part.

Comment: I'm positive that some abstract, god-knows-how defined "score" is a bad idea. It'll only make people bump around aimlessly, trying to satisfy the incomprehensible tin can - or game the system if/when they finally see which changes have an effect. A wizard is even worse, it puts a rigid limitation on workflow that is hard to manage (template's limitations are not rigid, it only makes it harder to ignore it so that only those who want it badly enough will bother to).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I never mentioned that a user won't be able to post a question with low score anywhere in the answer. Score is just an indication to the OP about his question quality,about his question likely to be received by community etc. With less question score, not the OP but the mods, reviewers will have ease in sorting and cleaning up question. And those (new users esp) who would try to increase there question score, will reduce number of low quality and duplicate question automatically. I think same might apply to wizards too, that would help (new users mostly) to frame a good question.

Comment: "Last week 47% of all attempts to ask were blocked by one of our many quality filters" Jesus Hernandez Christ on a bicycle.

Comment: Even if you don't like the score idea itself (but I do!) - the fact that there is a visual feedback that actually catches the eye and tickles the ego is already something to consider. Maybe the labels need to "hurt" a little more though, just seeing that it is weak probably won't make people in a hurry to outsource problems care all that much.

Comment: This is an excellent idea - especially considering that they already have filters in place! This could be implemented with a question template

Comment: wow 47% @JonEricson that's very high -- has this number been going up over time?

Comment: Even if the OP doesn't see the score, the reviewers seeing it could be helpful

Comment: @JeffAtwood Yep, ever since you left... :(

Comment: @JeffAtwood: [Not particularly.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358412/1438) Other than spam season, it's been in the 40-50% range since 2012. (Actually, that's probably not quite right. [Some blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles) were in effect a few months before they were logged in the database.)

Comment: Need this feature, new people like me are frequently banned without any reason. I don,t know why!!! May be this feature will warn us newbies to correct mistakes spot on. Also similar questions based on tag and title so that we know in advance its duplicate.

Comment: @PulkitSharma If you're question banned, edit your questions as it asks you to. If, once you've improved your questions to the best of your ability and waited a day or two, you are still banned, ask _nicely_ in chat or meta, trying to make your question as specific as possible, **after making sure that your meta question is high-quality and not a duplicate**.

Answer (score 61):

The essence of the problem is that the people who post low-quality questions DO NOT come to SO to ask a question. They come to SO to solve a problem.

This is an important distinction. The "good" OP actually wants to know what's going on, so they ask a proper question. The "usual" OP just wants the blooming thing to compile/run/produce results. Stack Overflow is just a magic wand they can wave to make the problem go away.

The question becomes, how do you make the problem solvers to cooperate at producing answerable questions (good questions would be too much to ask for)?

My suggestion is to lure them by explicitly offering to solve their problem.

At least one section of the Wizard should start:

"Help! My program does not work!"

From there you can branch into "Compilation error" (whole screen, with detailed explanation of what compiler is and  may be links to many language-specific pages), "IDE error", "Linker Error", "I don't know what this thing is saying" and so on.

Eventually we'd get to ask for MCVE and maybe even post the question. But the first step has to offer help in solving the problem, or the authors of "Question: how do I do this?" will not even see the rest.

To illustrate the point: here is a typical problem solving question that would benefit from a wizard (at least in the state it is as of this edit):

[C++ Battleship game, variable update doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835918/c-battleship-game-variable-update-doesnt-work)

Comment: That's an interesting point of view. But I would argue that we do not want people not to ask for their problem. However, we want them to ask for it according to the rules, such that the question and any potential answer is useful for everyone, or at least those with a similar problem.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest To be fair, I'd prefer the "problem solvers" to not ask at all. But I realize I am at best a minority and maybe a lonely misanthrope around here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest To address your actual comment: what I propose is not to prevent the "solve my problem" questions from being asked. My goal is same as yours: "we want them to ask for it according to the rules". The point I am making is that the best way to achieve that goal is to recognize the "solve my problem" as a type of question that needs guidance, and provide that guidance in a way that would **appeal** to the problem solvers. Catching flies with honey and all that.

Comment: Ah ok, I may have misinterpreted that. Now my problem with that approach would be that you actually do invite people to come up with their actual problem instead of the filtered, minimal and verifiable version of it. But it's definitely worth thinking about.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest People come to us with problems no matter what. The template (It should rather be a *wizard*) allows us an opportunity to extract relevant information out of them and in some cases solve the problem before they post the question.

Comment: @Arkadiy Questions not backed by actual problems tend to be relatively useless.  You get people asking "how do I frozzbubble", without actually explaining what frozzbubble *is* well enough to work out what they actually need.  Instead they have some nebulous concept in their head and answerers have to read their mind.  Concrete questions about real problems that are well framed both well define the problem *and* permit "actually, your real problem is 1 step removed" answers.  Both groundless questions, and random code spew, aren't good questions.

Comment: Indeed, and that's why I propose a wizard. The wizard may be able to turn "My program does not frozzbubble!" Into "The code below, when compiled with such and such compiler, run with such and such arguments, does bubble then froz. I expect it to do froz then bubble. I expect it to do froz first because the `froz()` function is first in the file. Why is froz not done first?"  This is still a "solve my problem" question, but at least it can be answered.

Comment: I would refer to the question linked at the bottom of your post as a "debugging style question". Many questions present a problem in need of solving, not all problems in need of solving are debugging problems.

Comment: @Yakk Handwaving about imagined questions in an overly general manner is not helpful. If "frozzbubble"  is a well defined task, and implementing and explaning the implementation of said task is not too broad of a topic for Stack Overflow, then it doesn't need a back-story, the last ten code snippets that the user wrote that didn't solve the problem, etc. Such questions are "how-to" style questions, and those questions are inherently on-topic without all of that unhelpful nonsense that people nag about unnecessarily in the comments.

Comment: @TinyGiant It is not entirely obvious what is unhelpful nonsense unless you already know the root of the problem, which is exactly what is being asked in debug questions.

Comment: Agree that the best outcome in many cases would be if the OP does not ask a question. I think the wizard idea may be helpful, but only if enough of its paths end in a message such as "the question you are trying to ask is not on topic for SO" and redirects the user to google to do some research.

Answer (score 55):

### Tailor the template to the type of question being asked

I understand why the focus for the template is on debugging questions. This is one of the bigger problems we face with questions. Debugging questions come in missing one or more of the necessary ingredients like it's going out of style. I think a template in this regard is a very good idea.

*However*... <sup>(and that's a big *however*)</sup> There *are* other types of questions that have different necessary ingredients. I don't know the specific statistics, but I think it's safe to assume that questions which aren't about debugging an error are similarly common to those that are.

There is already so much focus on the problems with debugging questions that other types of questions are regularly closed for the "Debugging / No MCVE" reason even though they aren't debugging questions. Focusing on debugging questions will be confusing for those asking different types of questions.

The natural solution to me would be to prompt the asker for the type of question they are asking before giving them a template, and **tailor the template to the type of question being asked**.

Comment: In the mentoring experiment, we did see that an awful lot of questions from new users were related to code not working. It might be that simple templates will cause more problems then they will solve. That's fine, as long as we learn a thing or two. Whether templates work or not, we'll have a better idea on how to create a guided asking experience that really works. Figuring out what sort of question a user is asking might be the first step there. We'll see.

Comment: @JonEricson, Perhaps what's appropriate, prior to showing a template, is to have the user select from a set of radio buttons as to why they are asking a question. For example: "My code doesn't work the way I want"; "There's a concept I have a question about";[some other options]; "My question is not specifically about programming" (direct them to some other site); and "My question is specifically about programming, but doesn't fit any of the above". Obviously, those are just off the top of my head, but it allows you to tailor the template to the type of question the OP *thinks* they have.

Comment: This is what I'm worried about: Stack Overflow being reduced to "debug-my-code-for-me". [Not the first time I've expressed this concern either.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269887/whats-too-broad-about-all-the-possible-operations-that-could-cause-a-nan/269988#comment85555_269887)

Comment: @BoltClock indeed.  It's all a conspiracy between Hollywood and the profs/TA's to portray software development as 'writing code that works immediately if you are a good programmer', rather than engineering where continual loops round testing/debugging are always required to get software fit for purpose:(   This is blatantly obvious from the many posts: 'I dont' understand - my code compiles with no errors or warnings, but still segfaults'.   Myself, I would start by exterminating the current crop of profs/TA's;)

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, I agree, it's a drag. IMO "debug my code for me" questions are a very weak subset of what SO used to be able to accomplish. There's some useful information in that genre but the more conceptual questions tend to get more done with less; even a straightforward "How do I..." question is probably more useful to readers  than 8 paragraphs of boilerplate "why your code doesn't work". It's also a lot more awkward to write self answered QA if SO only accepts "debug my code" questions.

Comment: Yes, it would be great if the templates would help people to ask actual questions, not submit help tickets. There really aren't that many categories of on-topic questions, but a good template for each category of question would be counterproductive when applied to a question of a different category.

Comment: Also, for those of you that want to only accept questions with an MVCE on SO, is your theory that all of these conceptual sort of SO questions would fit better on Softare Engineering? Are you thinking that we should migrate non-MVCE (e.g., "How Do I" questions, or "help me understand this concept") questions to SE.SE? Would that even work? I'm not really sure it would work, to be honest. Or are you just looking for mass deletion/closure of "How do I" / "I have a question about a concept" questions? I'm just trying to figure out what the future is of those sort of questions.

Comment: Y'know, this doesn't *have* to focus on debugging questions... I kinda suspect MCVE showed up a lot in the mentoring stuff because it's an easy (and often-useful) bit of advice, whereas improving a "HOWTO" question kinda requires a bit more domain knowledge. If you can think of prompts that'd be useful for *not-debugging* questions, propose 'em! I did...

Comment: +1 Tool questions also come to mind.

Comment: @Shog9 My main issue with MCVEs is that they tend to artificially narrow the scope of otherwise widely applicable questions. Yes, so do most askers anyway, but I don't fancy being restricted just because new askers (I specifically use that verbiage because I've seen 20k users who then ask a question for the first time and it's bad) aren't used to how the site works.

Comment: I took the liberty of emphasizing your main point. It was in the last line of your post, and I actually missed it completely while skimming. I was about to post an answer with the exact same suggestion, but decided to do a text search for "type" just to double-check that no one else had posted the same thing already. That's when I found yours. So, anyhow, +1

Comment: @jrh In my experience, there are a lot of conceptual questions would benefit from a MCVE. The reader understands that the example is an _example_ and not the entirety of the question, but having an example illustrates clearer what words alone might not. [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282118/what-is-the-rationale-behind-decltype-behavior)

Comment: @Shog9 I gave it a try but I had a hard time coming up with any guidance for "How do I" questions that didn't seem too restrictive (I couldn't in good faith post a rule that would have prevented a post I honestly found useful). The only clear cut rule I could think of is "Don't post duplicates and be as specific as possible", but that doesn't really prevent most of the common things that should be avoided. So it sort of just came right back to "if you post something too time consuming, you probably won't get an answer.". Unfortunately that's all I've got, sorry.

Comment: What are your standard questions when a co-worker asks you such a question, @jrh?

Comment: @Shog9 I don't ask anything usually, almost all "How Do I" questions I've ran into tended to be answerable as-is. I usually give an answer at the level of abstraction they asked and then wait for further questions to get an idea of what they understand. If it's a coding question I usually make a quick test program or snippet to demonstrate. I could even give an answer to a massive question like "How do I make a Quake clone" by talking in terms of general concepts instead of raw code; they wouldn't have Quake at the end of it, but they'd be a bit better off, hopefully.

Comment: Sounds like prompts that'd help establish a level of detail or skill required would be a valuable addition then, eh @jrh?

Comment: @BoltClock "*My main issue with MCVEs is that they tend to artificially narrow the scope of otherwise widely applicable questions.*" - eh? I'm [on your side](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346347/1709587#comment461742_346347) that a debugging-based question template would be a bad thing, but this particular claim seems confused to me. An MCVE generally *broadens* the audience of a debugging question by changing it from "why does my particular 1000-line application throw a `FrobError`" to *"why does a `FrobError` get thrown in this simple circumstance that applies to many people?"*

Comment: @MarkAmery I believe boltclock was talking about cases of how to questions where people request an MCVE, which then turns the how to question into a debugging style question, hence making the question less widely applicable.

Comment: @TinyGiant ah, right, yeah. That happens, and it's awful. The "what have you tried" crowd and their misguided mission to eliminate all questions other than "debug my wall of code" from Stack Overflow are a disease that the community hasn't yet managed to expunge.

Comment: @MarkAmery I agree

Comment: There could be another separate type of tags, you would get to choose between : `debugging`, `theory learning`, or `code improvement`. And as it would be... forced ? maybe just highly suggested ? then answerers will always know what to expect from OP !

Comment: I honestly think this is the best solution. I hope they adopt this. It should remain the asking template for users with <=20 rep.

Comment: @MarkAmery:  You make a good point.  When you put it that way, I think I have made that "what have you tried" mistake sometimes.  However, when the question is "how do I compare strings in assembly language" or some other trivial task, it's not really a good SO question either.  Like the algorithm is so simple that the surrounding code is going to take up many more lines.  I don't want SO to turn into a code-writing service either.  OTOH I don't mind showing an efficient way when the OP sounds capable of writing something, not just a clueless homework question.

Comment: @PeterCordes *"I don't want SO to turn into a code-writing service either"* - some folks will disagree with me, but *personally*, I'm happy for us to be a code-writing service for any code that satisfies both of two conditions: 1) it's *short* enough to reasonably belong in a Stack Overflow answer rather than a library (though that still might be 100+ lines in *rare* cases), and 2) it's a *generic* yet *well-specified* task that many people will want to achieve and Google for a solution to. The *bad* code-writing questions are the *"please completely implement all of my business logic"* ones.

Comment: @PeterCordes in other words, I consider the categories of "write some code for me" and "debug some code for me" to *both* contain a full range of great to terrible questions. The key factor, to me, is whether the *question-framing effort* has been put in to create a question that is simultaneously narrowly specified and broadly applicable. In the debugging case that generally means showing a common error using an MCVE, but it's equally possible in the "how-to" or "write me some code" case just by thoughtfully narrowing down the task.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Where do homework questions fall into that?  In the assembly-language tag, people frequently post their homework assignments and the task is often simple and common, but I still feel like taking it at face value and answering wouldn't be great.  You're right that the details are in the framing; often there are specific requirements that would make it not a duplicate of a basically similar question.  It also feels wrong to write code for someone that can't write it themselves, rather than answering someone who could write it, but probably not well and would take them some time.

Comment: @PeterCordes With the caveat that I've never written assembly and might be missing assembly-specific nuances, I think I'd break the category of questions you're describing down a little. If the question is well-framed, broadly applicable, and not a duplicate, then I don't think the fact that it's "simple" should count against it -  there's nothing innately wrong with questions being basic. Even if the question is directly answered in the language's docs, answering it is a great opportunity to *introduce beginners to those docs* with a link and a quote. On other other hand... *(TBC)*

Comment: @PeterCordes ... there are some clearly *bad* kinds of homework/beginner-level questions. Outright duplicates are straightforward: close 'em and move on. The category I *hate* are the ones you describe as having *"specific requirements that would make it not a duplicate"*. This often means, in my experience, that the asker is really asking two or three good (but duplicate) questions in one, but lacks the skill to pick them apart, Google each of them, and stitch the answers together. They're bad questions, but can't be closed without being "creative" in interpreting the close reasons.

Comment: @MarkAmery: The main thing that makes asm special is that everything tends to be less generic than in other languages.  The exact details of e.g. problem size might allow different optimizations.  So there's no generic best answer for comparing strings in x86 asm.  And I/O facilities vary by platform (libc or not, Linux system calls, BIOS or DOS calls, etc.), so "print a multi-digit number" questions aren't all duplicates of each other.  Except they really are because the algorithm for repeated division by 10 is the same...  This is one kind of "specific detail" that gets problematic for dups.

Comment: @MarkAmery Just out of curiosity, where did the resistance towards SO becoming a "code writing service" come from to begin with? I like your explanation about when "write some code for me" is okay, and I'm honestly surprised that  it's an unpopular idea. Now that docs failed, does that mean that we're back to old blogs, SO posts from 2009, and old books for example code? Doesn't really sound like that fits with the original goals of the site.

Comment: @jrh Such questions have never been off topic. It is a shame the some users misunderstand the purpose of the system, and in turn they mislead others. Those users doing this actually generally believe that they are being helpful.

Comment: I'd suggest making a meta post on this "code writing service" topic, I don't think I've seen a post that really gets directly to the point and discusses some of the downsides of not allowing those kind of posts (so far I've only seen "zero effort questions are bad"; maybe a bunch of other kinds of questions get lumped in as collateral damage).

Comment: @jrh [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281) is the quickest example I can link (its one of my highest voted answers) but it is all over meta.

Comment: @TinyGiant huh. Well, I can't really ask for much more than that. It's even at +72/-1. Well, thanks for trying.

Answer (score 36):

How about this, cribbing a bit from [Civil Comments](https://meta.discourse.org/t/civil-comments-rate-three-other-comments-before-posting/32401):

> Before you can submit *your* new question, **you must first review three new questions from other users.**

The guidance would give specific steps on how to rate the questions:

- does it show research?
- can you understand it?
- is it clear and complete?

And in a surprise twist...

> Now you need to review your own question by the same criteria

Because we all know everyone else's code is terrible, but ours is awesome, right? What better way to learn what makes a great question than guided review of questions from other new users, then turning that terrible critical eye on ourselves?

This would also solve the problems of new questions being posted without any review, and add a bit higher barrier for new questions to get in the system. As Jon noted 47% (!) of new questions are currently blocked by the quality heuristics, which is great, but if we could involve peer review here *without* blowing up the review queues this could be a real game changer.

Comment: This reminds me a lot of [the idea posted by Tanner](/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly) a while ago.

Comment: I love this idea - any  idea to [demonstrate some awareness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355646/reducing-the-number-of-low-quality-posts-without-excluding-potential-newcomers-t) of the question poster. I've noticed these types of ideas don't catch on, people tend to argue that they inhibit experienced people from posting on the site.  People with programming experience shouldn't be too offended to step over a couple of hurdles to join the site.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would see 99% of users just considering this a pesky, arrogant task, clicking _"Looks OK"_ 3 times and then posting. Kind of like Triage, except way worse. And when you say _`"This would also solve the problems of new questions being posted without any review"`_, you're not actually suggesting to create a new, broader Triage reviewed only by new users?

Comment: @PaulStenne If the buttons are clicked "quickly" _and_ the user hasn't passed the audit, it'll display a message like "looks like you clicked through this" and make the user do it again.

Comment: I like this because, for the users we actually want to keep, it's a gentle on-boarding to the site culture.  I don't think it will make much of a dent on the users we want to shoo away, but that's okay.

Comment: The questions presented to user this way may not be _real_ questions being asked right now. These questions may be specifically designed to show what is allowed and what is not.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I am increasingly convinced that /ask page hurdles (nice, awesomely designed, educational ones) are precisely what is needed, and urgently

Comment: @JeffAtwood I don't know what weight you pull, but pull it stat. 
btw, nice to finally meet you. :)

Answer (score 24):

**Edit:**

A suggestion that takes no effort to implement, with the same effect and fits the question discussed here:

In the question template, there should be a suggestion,

> If your program returns an error message, make it the title of your question.

When followed by the OP, it will trigger the suggested answers mechanism with (hopefully) decent accuracy. And will help Google to find this question when it's the first question regarding such an error.

---

There should be a *dedicated input field* for the error message. That will improve the process dramatically, as it will allow for a system that provides a *correct* list of suggested answers, not to mention other benefits like correct formatting, less discussion in the comments, better answers, etc.

This field obviously should be made non-required, and could be left empty.

Comment: Obviously this is outside the scope of this particular meta question. That said, it would be interesting to have a catalog of all questions related to a particular error string. Well, maybe not ["syntax error"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22syntax%20error%22). (Most of those are just missing semicolons. ;)

Comment: +1 for using the specific error message for suggesting related questions, works well enough for samebug.io (doesn't always get the greatest results, but at least it's more useful than SO search). And @JonEricson if somebody types "syntax error" into this field, you could just block the submission or redirect them to a general "what is a syntax error and how do I solve it" article, as somebody who is not able to solve a missing semicolon by themselves obviously lacks the required minimal understanding to ask questions.

Comment: "I ran my code and there was no error message, it just didn't work!" ... says every other asker...

Comment: @JeffC that's true but irrelevant. This field is for ones who have one.

Answer (score 20):

Display the tag wiki for each tag added by the user.

1. The [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) tag wiki, for instance, contains a wealth of information for diagnosing a problem and a long list of FAQs (which I personally use to close ~10 duplicates a week). I would expect many users to simply click through to get back to writing their question, but it would at least provide a starting place for those more interested in getting an answer than seeing their question posted.
2. This could also encourage people to beef up other tag wikis.
3. It could discourage people from adding irrelevant tags to their questions.

Comment: This is a _really_ interesting idea. Tag wikis have long been underutilized and giving them more visibility at the time questions are being composed seems like a natural. The trick is to avoid dumping yet another wall of text on people. (Though this particular wall of text has a better than average chance to make a difference.)

Comment: Linking to them (say, under the tag entry field as tags are selected) seems like a good idea. They're already linked from the pop-up that appears as you type in tag names, but I'd wager most folks don't see the little (i) icon much less realize it's a link.

Comment: Props to any proposal to reduce mistagging

Answer (score 19):

In principle the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide has all the details in that are needed to ask a question, which can be answered. The first action to take might hence be to remove the "good" from the title and make it the definitive guide to asking a question. (I've seen new users argue that they don't want to ask a particularly *good* question.) Also, it should't say that it is a guide to "improve chances for getting an answer", but simply that every question should stick to this guide.

Any template or clickable guide or so could just stick very closely to what the *How to ask* guide tells us.

One thing this guide isn't very good at is making it clear that *every* question needs a problem description and explaining what a problem description really is. It's all there, but rather implicitely.
I often have the impression that bad questions are being asked simply due to the lack of understanding what a problem description is and why it is needed.
This may be due to a misconception of the term "problem". It is often confused with a "task" (Or a problem is seen as a task that one doesn't know how to solve.)

The understanding that a **problem is not simply a task** is key and I would even dare to say that everyone who has this understanding will be able to ask an answerable question. The fact that one needs to make the problem understandable/reproducible for others is then just a corrolary.

One problem often observed with MCVEs is that people do understand "minimal", but not "complete" or "verifiable". If possible one should make it clear that the emphazis is on all three of them.

If the *How to ask* guide is updated accordingly, I could imagine to add a confirmative and mandatory checkbox for a UI:

```
☑ I have read and understood "How to ask", "Minimal complete verifiable example"
☑ My question includes a clear problem description, not only a task.
```

Also, one might opt for

```
☑ I've included all details (MCVE of code, error traceback, system in use) 
  to let others reproduce the problem. 
☐ I haven't included all details, because:
  Reason: _________
```

This would let people think about the reasons for not sticking to *How to ask*.

Also, if we want users to explain their problem clearly, the restrictions for adding images and links should be abolished. (I often read things like, I would have included the link if I was allowed to). Especially new users will need more than the allowed 2 links to share the research being done.

A final remark: You (the Stackexchange people) can put a lot of effort into designing a question template, or user guide or whatever it is. This will all lead to little improvement as long as there is a clear incentive for people actually answering bad questions. If people can gain reputation from answering bad or duplicate questions, they will. If people see their bad or incomplete questions being answered, or just see that it costs them less effort to ask a 1 sentence question and have it marked as duplicate (effectively linking them to the solution), than to search for a solution, they will ask more bad questions (and other new users will see those questions being answered, so they follow this lead).
If you really want to do something against bad questions, you will need to change the awarding system.

Comment: *"In principle the How to ask a good question guide has all the details in that are needed to ask a question, which can be answered."* - Yes it does and I agree, but my take on this is, that the "front end" doesn't show enough. That yellow box on the right when they click on "ask a question", doesn't have enough (bulleted) points for them to read. It's simply not enough and isn't strict enough. The dev team needs to work on that, and has been neglected (not thought of enough) for too long.

Comment: Yep, that's my first main point here. It is all there, just hidden. But it can be (re)used for any kind of template or UI.

Comment: I've been thinking about this for a long time, being if it's the staff working on the back end doing/writing up the content for the front end. Those two are totally different animals and feel they're not being treated as such :-) They have to remember where "they" came/started from and put themselves in a (new) coder's shoes for a while. Until that happens, it's going to remain the same 'ol, same 'ol. It's been said that Stack was put together by professionals, for professionals, yet the outlying problem is constantly about low quality posts by members who don't know how Stack rolls.

Comment: One thing to note is that new users already go through [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) to get to the form for writing their question. Maybe updating this page would be helpful, but it's not part of the scope of this project. As for the rewards system, I encourage you to try [getting a sock puppet to 1k](http://jericson.github.io/2017/07/26/race_to_1k_1.html). Perhaps the most startling thing for me was to discover how hard it is to get an upvote. Answering questions (good or bad) is not an easy road to reputation riches.

Comment: +Infinity for the last paragraph. On the topic of checkboxes, I think the asker will just tick whatever they need to get their question posted (like we do with agreeing to licenses). What happens if someone just blindly checks all boxes while not adhering to their content?

Comment: @JonEricson In response to your: *"One thing to note is that new users already go through [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) to get to the form for writing their question."* - Is that based on statistics? How is that known for certain? Or am I seeing a different link/view from the "Ask a question" button and seeing [asking help »](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) because of my rep? In either case, I doubt that (too) many don't bother reading what's on or off-topic, they just want "dah codez".

Comment: @Fred-ii-: It's been there for [ages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9710/1438) for users with less than 10 reputation. So you might not have seen it if you got an answer upvote before asking, if you joined very early or if you got the association bonus from reputation on some other site first.

Comment: @JonEricson Oh I see, thanks Jon. I've made a note of it and will be using that link (in the future) for new users and possibly some higher repped who could also (probably) use a refresher ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @JonEricson I guess the same applies to [the page you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice): Remove the "improve your chances" and replace it with something definitive. I hope the main point of this got through though: Make a template according to the existing guide and improve the "problem description" part. (Btw. I do not get what the puppet wants to tell me. You do get reputation by answering bad questions and that is why people answer them, hence new bad questions are being asked. If you don't believe this to be the case, the measurement metrics you use might be off.)

Comment: Echoing @user1803551, there are all too many users that won't go through the tour and whatnot before asking (evident through their lack of badges). These people tend to post questions of the lowest quality

Comment: +1 for the last sentence, -1 for the rest. Here's how the workflow of your typical help vampire would look like with your proposed checkboxes: 1) take screenshot of code, add image to question, click submit -> error! 2) type variations of "halp it not work" enough times so the error complaining about questions having to contain text to go away, click submit -> error! 3) notice red box around some checkboxes and text saying something about "mandatory", check all indicated checkboxes, click submit -> works 4) get upvotes and answers for the submitted trash because people want to "be nice"...

Comment: @l4mpi Maybe you have misunderstood the question, which is how to help users ask questions. I think we do not assume the majority of new users to be help vampires, and I think we can also assume that they would actually notice making a wrong statement by confirming having done something which they obviously haven't. But it should also be clear that if the site mirrors that it is ok to ask bad questions, the fear of doing something bad by making such wrong statement is heavily reduced - this is what the last paragraph is about.

Comment: I understood the question perfectly well. Your checkboxes reiterates things from the introduction page, so the people who actually read stuff have already read it, and the people who do not read stuff will just check it without reading anything to make it go away. "They would notice making a wrong statement", notice maybe, but you must be very naive to think they care. Just look at your average EULA, what you propose is basically the same as an "I have read and understood these terms" checkbox.

Comment: @l4mpi To take the picture from [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions/358065?noredirect=1#comment523534_357956) and below, it seems you are arguing that a "dangerous bend" warning sign will not reduce the number of deadly accidents on a road. I strongly doubt that, since the majority of people have no intention of killing other people - they might just not be aware of the danger ahead. Putting up a warning sign is hence helpful.

Comment: Well, driving lessons teach you to watch out for road signs, but every software or internet service teaches you to ignore mandatory checkboxes. We already have the exact thing you argue for literally everywhere where an EULA is involved and in many other places (e.g. "I have read the community rules thread before posting" in forums). And as is common knowledge, in all of these instances the overwhelming majority of users ignores the text and simply clicks the box to proceed. What makes you think that it would be any different on SO?

Comment: @l4mpi What makes me think that this is useful: All the comments that say "Thank you for the suggested readings, I will go through them." or similar after I have reminded them of looking through *How to ask*  and *MCVE* below their question.

Comment: Notice that this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice does not mention  MCVE,   reiterate the kinds of topics that are or are not appropriate or say to summarize the research that you have done. Instead it states the obvious (search).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest True, but then there are also so many people saying "I just need this to work". To echo l4mpi, I think the message have to be _drove in_, instead of just presented, as your last sentence implied

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: _"I think we do not assume the majority of new users to be help vampires"_ Why not? They are.

Answer (score 16):

Here are some thoughts:

- There are many different kinds of questions, requiring different templates. Maybe you can evaluate the A/B test of the templates in that regard. If the template improved questions, in what tags was the effect most prominent and which tags were not (or even negatively) affected? What words/phrases were used more in the questions with the template, and how do they relate to the improvement?
- Include a button to remove the template text ("this question structure doesn't fit my problem")
- In any case, please don't use headline formatting in the template. Most questions are short enough that they don't need this.
- Don't put questions in the template. They should be reserved for a wizard input. Only the answers to these inquiries should constitute the question post.
  To rip off the example in @enderlands answer, it should instead look like this - just fragments of sentences that can stay in the question text as they are, and should be completed by the asker:

  ```
  I am trying to 

  Here is the code I use for that:

      // …

  I did expect it to

  But instead, it
  ```
- If you really want to put some inquiries or instructions in the template text, hide them through comments:

  ```
  <!-- What are you trying to do? -->
  I am trying to 

  <!-- What is your code that currently tries to do that? Indent by 4 spaces. -->
  Here is my code:



  <!-- What do you expect the result to be? -->
  I did expect 

  <!-- What is the actual result? -->
  But instead
  ```

Comment: *"Don't show the template to more experienced users with a history of good questions."* - You would be surprised as to how many posts I've seen from rather high rep members who failed to "Google it", really. Or a "wishlist" of many bulleted lists for a "this is what I had in mind to..." or a "what do you think of....?".

Comment: All great points. Especially this one: *"Include a button to remove the template text ("this question structure doesn't fit my problem")"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Agreed, there are users with high rep from answers that fail to post appropriate questions. However I would hope that these questions are downvoted if they don't fit SO, so it's not "a history of good questions". In general I would however expect more experienced users to know what kind of information to include, and to know when it's not necessary.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, templates will only be presented to "new" askers. An option to remove the template (or pick from several options) seems reasonable if we make them permanent parts of the system. I'm not sure we'll want to build that out for the pilot tests, however. I really like the way the sentence fragments look; especially with meta comments included. The only downside is that not everyone will understand they are HTML comments. But that's what testing is for!

Comment: @JonEricson Ah, I must have missed that. Removed the point.

Comment: @Bergi I am legitimately confused about that, I'd think having seen horrible questions from the other side, it would be obvious not to post one. But surprise!

Comment: [Looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vyVp.png) this has been deployed (at least in testing)? (Not exactly a success in this case, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 16):

I feel like a template is somewhat missing the point.  Not to say that I don't think that it'll have some modicum of success, but I personally don't believe that templating is the right answer to this.

tl;dr:  **Passive warnings and notifications, which would prevent question submission, should be leveraged instead.  Ignoring said warnings should accelerate the rate at which an asker is question-banned.**

Stack Overflow has a massive amount of data of what questions are and aren't well-received at specific points in time.  That is, there is information around what questions get downvoted at roughly which time.  We can use this information to guide an asker into potentially reforming their question.

For example, if we have someone posting another homework dump, which starts with "Write a ...", and we don't see anything to suggest that they've tried anything off the backside of that, we can raise a warning ensuring that the OP at least sees it, and requires them to click through a dialog that says, "My question isn't just a code dump, I've actually put forth some effort, I promise."

My reason to shy away from templates is that they can largely be filled with garbage to pacify an active checker.  The only way we're going to get  true value out of a system like this is not only if we identify what are known to be poorly-received questions, but also if we add a lot more bite to askers not heeding our advice.

Comment: I bet you're a fan of my question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333906/automatic-downvoting-bad-questions

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre:  Not really, no.  Yours is a system which automatically, through empirical evidence, suggests actions to be taken.  Mine, while enforcing this at the tail end, has warnings for any would-be asker who happens to believe that this site is only here for them to ask low-effort questions based on other historical data.  Pushing them closer to a q-ban is different than downvoting.  Think of it like them deleting a question with an answer on it.

Answer (score 15):

My favorite suggestion for how to ask a question comes from [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app):

> Please note that your issue will be fixed much faster if you spend about half an hour preparing it, including the exact reproduction steps and a demo.

I would modify it for Stack Overflow:

> Please note that most good questions take about half an hour to prepare, including the exact reproduction steps and a demo.

People don't realize this but it's super important.  Asking a question is like writing an email to your boss.  You should proof-read it and make sure that it's coherent and well-written.

My favorite demonstration of what a good question actually looks like comes from [Wikipedia's guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/How_to_ask_a_software_question).  Here's the tl;dr:

**Unclear Question:**

> I am writing a Perl program, but it doesn't work. I am reading in the names but they come out wrong. Is there a solution?

**Explaining the Goal:**

> I am writing a Perl program, but it doesn't work. **The program should read in a list of names, and then print them in alphabetical order.** I am reading in the names but they come out wrong. Is there a solution?

**Describing the Problem:**

> I am writing a Perl program, but it doesn't work. The program should read in a list of names, and then print them in alphabetical order. I am reading in the names but they come out in the wrong order. **In fact, they come out in same order that they started in!** Is there a solution?

**Including an example:**

> I am writing a Perl program, but it doesn't work. The program should read in a list of names, and then print them in alphabetical order. I am reading in the names but they come out in the wrong order. In fact, they come out in same order that they started in! **I have posted my code below.** Is there a solution?
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/perl
>
> # Read the names into the @people array
> while (<>)
> {
>   push @people, $_;
> }
>
> # Now sort the names
> sort @people;
>
> # Now print them out
> foreach $person (@people)
> {
>     print $person;
> }
> ```

Comment: Not all questions are debugging questions

Comment: I like the idea of giving people a timeframe. That's probably even more true if you _aren't_ asking a debugging question, @TinyGiant. Personally, I find myself spending more than that on my questions.

Comment: Spending time is massively important. I take that to an extreme; whenever I would write a question or answer, I don't hit submit but I leave it and come back to it hours later. Mulling it over is a privilege as well as a right. I hate to see people not take that privilege because they're in a hurry to post before others do.

Comment: Let me say, your example of a *"Good"* question is terrible. The terms **does not work**, **comes out wrong**, **Is there a solution>** All that is implied and noise that makes the asker think they are providing what they need to provide and they are **NOT**. I think if those terms/variations of terms should be red flags that a question is **not** a good one.

Comment: _"Asking a question is like writing an email to your boss."_ Maybe we should make it so that the ramifications of doing it wrong are approximately equivalent. Otherwise you will **never** persuade these people to put their own effort into neatness.

Comment: The wording and use of bold in this answer is excellent.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hi, your question has now been downvoted five times and has been closed as "off topic". Your employer has been informed and your position has been terminated. Works for me.

Comment: @JeremyP: Christ, that comment scared me shitless in my notifications :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But what consequences are there, for most people, for writing a stupid/careless/incoherent email to your boss? In most workplaces, probably just said boss quietly being irritated and holding a lower opinion of you before asking for clarification (or passing you off for someone else to deal with); you're unlikely to get fired or yelled at over it. Of course, if you've got a modicum of self-consciousness and conscientiousness, that irritation and contempt are enough motivation. But then, you probably *also* care about the same feelings from your peers on Stack Overflow...

Comment: @MarkAmery: Perhaps.

Answer (score 15):

This isn't a big suggestion, but I haven't seen it mentioned yet:

There should be some mention of how code should be posted in the question. I don't think it's enough to simply say that they should include code, and ideally an MCVE. Too often I see new people posting links to code, or, god forbid, links to images of code. Then it's the same "post code here directly as text" comments every time. It would be really nice if there was even just a hint to askers that code should be posted here directly as text, as well as formatted.

Comment: Also too much code is as much a problem as too little.

Comment: @Elin Yes, an MCVE is necessary. I briefly touched on that. I think I read someone else going into a lot more detail on that, so I didn't elaborate.

Answer (score 13):

## Why, why, why, why, WHY are you doing what you are doing?

> I'm trying to turn off the sun. Please help me.

**WHY** are you trying to turn off the sun?

> Well it is too bright in here. I can't sleep.

So you don't want to turn off the sun. Rather, you want to twist the knob that closes the blinds on your windows. We can help you with that.

---

Encourage people to tell WHY they're doing what they're doing. When faced with a bad question, it's more likely that the person simply has no idea that what they're trying to do won't solve their problem. They don't understand the problem, and as such they can't formulate a question related to that problem. Instead they try to solve it halfway themselves, then ask for help with their solution. Sometimes you might even be so lucky that simply redirecting their attention to the correct problem is enough, there's no real need to answer the question.

Comment: Yes, like a user story. What are you trying to accomplish? And why do you think your attempted solution fulfills that goal?

Comment: Upvoted because I was trying to turn off the sun and found this.

Comment: No please no. We want to answer questions not read a life story. There's nothing wrong with a question that doesnt explain why, and often explaining why will derail the question and leave future readers without a solution for the stated problem.

Comment: This would really help us know when it is an xy problem.

Comment: While not a bad idea in theory, it probably shouldn't be mandatory, and besides, if you list out the requirements of the whole program and every step you took to get there, my guess is, it will either look like homework or "do my design for me". I don't really need to read 15 pages of "we have to support this thing because it needs this legacy thing for windows 7 that needs this legacy thing for XP that needs this legacy thing for DOS that links against a Fortran application that controlled the Apollo missions".

Comment: XY problems are a thing, but that's not always true. Totally agree with @TinyGiant.

Comment: I don't like this, because it's suggesting we ask for irrelevant info. "I am trying to make a site like Facebook" no one cares what you're trying to make; what's the problem you're having? Get to the *point*. etc.

Comment: @TylerH background info is important to find out what the OP is expecting to hear in an answer -- [it can be unclear otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47039867/how-to-find-where-an-object-is-created-in-java). Still, we only need a small amount of it, and it's by far not the most important requirement.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev OP should specify what they are looking for, that doesn't require background information. In the case you linked, the OP was unclear in what they were asking. "We want to find whether an app was created in the heap or the pool" is not 'background info', it's *the entire goal of the question*. Background info would be something like 'we are making this application for a customer because they wanted to track some product'.

Comment: @TylerH It's not possible if [the OP doesn't really know what they're looking for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you insist that SO must still not tell them a solution for their actual problem and instead play a cat-and-mouse game as they try to guess what to ask about to get what they want... [sufficient to say that's not the mainstream opinion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev What? You're making up an entire argument and putting it in my mouth; I'm insisting that users should edit out fluff. I've not said anything about answerers not providing a solution to their problem. The point of the matter here is that questions should provide a clear problem statement without fluff. If they can't do that, we need to work with them and/or close their question until they can.

Comment: @TylerH that's not possible either in the case of XY problems. If an OP asks their real question - "what are the standard ways to solve problem X?" - it'll get closed as "too broad". Asking an XY question, however weird, is a working cheat around this obstruction.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Closing a question is not a permanent state, and users are expected to edit their question when it's placed on hold to bring it back on-topic, if possible. Cheating is not an acceptable behavior to achieve the result you want on Stack Overflow. That will lead you to a question ban faster with discerning users.

Answer (score 13):

Prompt for the title *after* the body has been written.

The process of writing the body can help the user organize their thoughts (the rubber duck effect), especially if other template ideas proposed here help them formulate better body text.  The user will be in a much better position to give an accurate, specific, and concise title at the end of the process.

(I try to write email subject lines and document titles after drafting the body because this trick isn't just for newbies.)

Titles are important.  I once worked on a terrible Q&A site and found that we could identify the best questions by finding the ones whose titles began with a capital letter and ended with a question mark.

Comment: We have a debate on the team about which order is best. The big disadvantage of waiting for the title is that we use it to show potential duplicate questions. I suspect that more people will follow through with asking duplicates if we wait until the end of the process to show similar questions. The sunk-cost fallacy at work.

Comment: That's a fair point.  I wish there were another way to get possible duplicates up early on because I truly believe getting people to write (or at least revisit) the title after writing the body make for better titles.  And quality titles attract more attention, which can mean more comments to educate newbies about how to write better questions.

Comment: You might be pleased with some of the wizard-like mockups we're looking at. ;-)

Comment: This is a big one; like I mentioned in [my meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard), the downside to putting question titles last is that, like Jon said, you can't search for dupes based on question title. **You *can* start searching based on tags and problem descriptions, though. I'd like to see some efforts by SO to do this**. The downside to putting them first though, is that you're always going to get crappy titles. No one picks a title for their book until after it's written for a reason :-) cc @JonEricson

Comment: "we could identify the best questions by finding the ones whose titles began with a capital letter and ended with a question mark." There's actually been a paper that studied SO questions and found the same thing; questions with titles formed as questions using proper grammar (asking something, using a question mark, etc.) were 'higher quality' in that they got more votes, views, and answers, than questions whose titles did not conform to that pattern.

Comment: @TylerH: Maybe you are talking about [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.04692.pdf)?

Comment: @JonEricson That may have been the one; I thought it had a female primary author... either I was wrong or there is another out there that I'm thinking of. Scanning through that one it doesn't seem to touch much upon the quality of titles beyond "not abusing capital letters"

Answer (score 10):

A link to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (minimal, complete, and verifiable example) page (in the question, as a link!) and spelling out the acronym in the first reference to it might be a good addition to this process - it took me a little bit to figure out what the acronym stood for.

Also, in the original question, it is referred to as 'MVCE', which a search for 'MVCE Stack Overflow' brings up a lot of 'MVC model view controller' results.

I realize that most folks here will know what that means already, but we could lose some insight from folks who get frustrated and can't even figure out what this 'MVCE' (*MCVE*) everyone is talking about is, and can't even search for it on this site to get to the definition page (could that be anchored as the top result for 'MCVE'? and maybe MVCE as well since it seems like that's what it's referred to as very often?)

Afterthought - a complete 'SO' (seeking alpha) acronym bank/dictionary (anchored somewhere prominent) would probably help folks read answers to questions that were 'similar' to their question - perhaps questions get asked again simply because they can't follow the conversation in the answers to the OP (original poster)

Answer (score 8):

I guess this isn't a question template but it made me wonder if a template is the wrong approach or is only a partial solution so ...

Just going to throw this out there but, just as Firefox requires for bug reports, how about you can't enter a question unless you've first searched.

Here's Firefox's bug reporter

First you have to enter a title/summary

[image]

Then it searches and you have to click *My Issue is not listed* before you can submit an issue.

[image]

Could SO take any inspiration from that? Heck, if it was up to me I wouldn't mind if it required 3 different searches. Even for myself it would force me to search more than once (which I already do). For that matter, maybe "Ask Question" should not even be on the front page

Comment: We don't require a search to ask a question, but we do _strongly encourage it_ for users with < 10 reputation. Take a look at the [interstitial page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) those users must acknowledge before being able to ask. It's not on the plan at the moment, but I'd like to test variations on that page. My _guess_ is that requiring searches would not filter out too many questions that are going to end up deleted. But it might reduce duplicate questions just a bit.

Comment: @JonEricson Since it's not obvious search results will appear in a little window on the same page, a new asker might be concerned using it would redirect to a new page and take them away from their goal of submitting a question. Not sure what might help with that.

Comment: The user might search, and then without even viewing the search results, he might directly click, _my issue is not listed here_ button

Comment: I think this idea is a good one but the search on SO is... well, it's not good. IMO we'd be better off dropping it and adding in google results. I never search things using SO's search engine. When I did a few times in the past, I never got the results I was looking for... and I was looking for a specific Q and found it easily on google.

Comment: @JeffC: It's pretty hard to beat Google's search. The  [advanced search options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) can help, but often the best way to find something is to [ask your question and look for duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool).

Comment: not all questions are about "can you debug my code" ? some are theorical questions about the size of pointers, what in the C norm guarantees this or that... how to improve performance on this ... hard to put in a bug report form.

Comment: The spiel at the top of this page alludes to a wizard at some later point. There are several meta questions with similar suggestions, some of them quite sophisticated and thought-provoking. So yes, I think this will be coming at some point in some form, but this isn't really an answer to this particular meta "question."

Comment: Every time I see Mozilla's Bugzilla it makes me sad that distribution of the theme for Bugzilla proper is still not ready :(

Answer (score 8):

There are lots of suggestions, but I think a point is missing: the tone of the template.

I'm suggesting to be intimidating in the template, as in put on social pressure for asking something bad. Make it obvious if you ask something not meeting community guidelines, people get pissed at you **fast**, which is indeed what happens.

My theory is there are two types of people that post bad questions, one is unaware of the question being bad, and the other that don't care.

Those that don't care will have to be **made** to care, no amount of guidelines presented in whatever format will get through to them if it isn't important **to them** to abide by it.

To put it another way, if students were to hesitate asking here as much as they would asking their tutors, we wouldn't be getting the hoards of homework dump. People care about not displeasing their tutors, but nothing about a disposable anonymous account.

As an example of what I mean, here's currently what's being put on the question title

> Questions with similar titles have frequently been downvoted and/or closed. Consider using a title that more accurately describes your question.

It seems to me its *shielding* the asker from the social pressure instead of *accentuating* it.

> Questions with similar titles are met with disapproval and will be closed. Describe your question more accurately or visit the help center for more information.

Is much more intimidating, it is assertive and emphasizes the displeasure from people on the opposite side of the screen, instead of just mentioning the post getting bombed. It then suggests a safe option of reading the help center, hopefully dissuading the asker to ask before doing so.

Answer (score 7):

Start with asking for a title and a brief summary, mentioning that a small portion of the brief summary will be displayed along with the question title and that the combination of the two is what will attract users to visit the question. Specify that the title should specify what is being asked, rather than just stating "i has a problem - tag tag tag". That guidance likely should be around the title more so than inside the primary template, and in far fewer words than I've used.

Then ask the for an MCVE, emphasizing the idea of removing anything from the code that isn't relevant to the problem (hopefully invoking the rubber duck effect.)

Follow up with asking for any errors that were produced or any unwanted behavior, including what was expected.

And then finally ask for any attempts that were made at solving the problem, and links to any research materials that were used (for example the tutorial that the user is using/copying from.)

Answer (score 7):

<sup>Copied from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page/326870#326870).</sup>

Sometimes I find myself looking at other users posts before I post my own. It helps me come up with better wording, grammar, style and formation.

The [Tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) shows an example of a well asked question along with its answers, and it highlights what should be asked (and what shouldn't):

[image: What should be asked]

Unfortunately, many users (most?) don't go through this page, and usually skip it or just scroll down to get a badge.

Since we see many low quality questions that are badly formatted, we can tell that many users don't really care about the "How to Ask" and "How to Format" side bars.

I'm thinking that instead of having wall of text of "How to Ask", we can provide a template<sup>*</sup> of a good question that has a two paragraphs of a description (including code formation for code-text) with a code snippet that users can take and change for their purposes.

I know that there are many different templates, and many different ways of asking a good question; some might have code, other might only have a description with possible image, it's not easy to have a *generic* template for a good question - But I'm just dropping the general idea of what I think might help a bit.

Example (of course it should be changed to something more general and make sure everyone understand that it's only a template for demonstration purposes):

[image]

This might help newcomers understand basic formation, while it also shows how a good question is asked.

<sup>* That template can actually be a placeholder that appears for users with < x reputation points</sup>

Comment: I don't think the users who are interested in understanding the basics of formatting are the problem; they probably also do research before asking and are guaranteed to end up with better question content (regardless of minor formatting errors). However, the ones who see nothing wrong with pasting in screenshots of code and/or error messages instead of text, or don't even seem to notice the question preview... well, you say yourself they "don't really _care_" about formatting, topicality et cetera. I doubt they will care more just because you show them an example.

Comment: @l4mpi's right - you can't "fix" these people. The problem is that SO has been made far too accessible for them. The only way to stop the repercussions of that kindness is to stop being so kind. All of the pandering ideas on this page are, sadly, a waste of time (and actually risk doing net _harm_ by getting in the way of the "good" users).

Answer (score 6):

This [has gone live](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360261/1739000).

Unfortunately, it is structured in such a way as to make new users think this site is about giving away free debugging help, which is exactly the opposite of what we wanted.

It is as if you jumped straight to option 1 of [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327082/1739000) without considering that people could have questions that don't benefit from code ([Help says "Not all questions benefit from including code"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) or even [canonical questions on memory efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22146094/1739000), which I consider to be some of the best questions on StackOverflow.

So, you are essentially **sending users down the path of mediocre-at-best questions** and away from some of the best type of questions (canonical ones).

Also, note that users are not directed to stick around to answer clarification questions (not that I've seen anyways, I'm not a new user), or even to proofread their post to make sure it formatted correctly. Both of these are vital.

Comment: One thing to note is that this is not likely to be the final template we test. If we develop a good stable of templates, we might give askers a menu to select from. Another thing to understand is that the goal is mostly to convert some unanswerable questions to answerable. People who are coming to ask truly excellent questions will probably be the sort who will understand that the template is optional. (They also are unlikely to have no prior reputation, but I guess everything is possible.)

Comment: @JonEricson, yeah, everyone has to start the rep game at the beginning :)

Comment: But not everyone needs to start with a question.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of specific formats for separate questions, why not have one general format that directs good questions and funnels worthless information into the background without rigidly requiring information.

I'd suggest some sort of condensed [OPORD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operations_order) format.  This is a standard military format for writing "orders" and are designed to make requests as clear, concise and complete as possible while still being flexible enough for almost any sort of request.  It also forces the "meat" into paragraphs 2-4 without leaving out important stuff like background and data tables.  These things could even be "rolled up" into links, especially after the question is answered and the specific background and test cases are not so important for future readers.

---

1. Situation:

Things in this field are the background of your question.  Who you are, what you're doing and why.  All the stuff that clutters the question body and obscures the problem but is nearly always included.  This info rolls up into a link at the top of the actual question page - answerers can reference it, especially for "why do you need this" questions, but don't have to read it really.

2. Mission:

What do you want to do.  This should really be the title, Inputs, expected outputs, plus any special circumstances.  Tight word/character count in this field.  Pick your tags here as well

3. Execution

What's your intended method.  What have you tried, what have you researched, what do you expect.  This is "the question."  Throws a warning if there's more than a few lines of code here, as most of that should go down in 5.

4. Communication

What's actually happening.  What's the output.  What's your error message. What do the docs say.  What have you found in your research.

5. Supporting data

What's going on around your question.  Put your code dump here. Put your big block of test input data here.  Put the full error trace here if it's pages long. This also rolls up into a link - it can be referenced by answerers, but doesn't clutter the question.

---

You'd probably want to change the terminology to be a little less "military" (situation -> background, mission -> task etc),  but that's the basic idea.

All you'd absolutely need to submit a question is 2.  If you have 5 you'd need 2-3-4 as well.

Under this format it would seem that bad questions would be instantly apparent.  #2 isn't specific enough?  Too broad.  #2 isn't programming related?  Off-Topic.  No #4 on a debugging question?  No #3 on a "how do I" question?  Question buried in #5?  Easy flags/downvotes.

It's also easier on the asker.  Not sure whether that bit of code is relevant?  Drop it in 5.  Not sure what bits of backround are relevant?  Dump it in 1.  Not sure what you need?  Being forced to state it a few words in 2 will help clarify. Input, output, method and gap are built into 2-3-4 without being a formula that might not suit your request.

It might be a bit intimidating for newcomers and tedious for old-timers (maybe relax some rules with higher rep), but it t really does force you to make a good request, and I think it could be easily adapted to asking good questions as well.

Comment: [jkdev's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358273/648265) is basically about the same, but a reference to prior experience here is a humongous plus in comparison.

Answer (score 5):

Put the tags first in the new-question entry form, then the question headline, then the body of the text.

Why might this be helpful? A number of reasons.

1. It asks the naive questioner to think about tags upfront, helping them develop a mental model of their problem that fits the way people will locate their question on SO.
2. It leverages the really nice autocompletion you SO folks already have developed for tags to guide the questioner upfront.
3. Knowing tags when the questioner starts typing the headline may improve the similar-question resultset. Alternatively, the contents of that resultset may (or may not, I know we're working with noobz here) help the questioner refine the choice of tags.
4. It potentially enables the presentation of domain-specific question-writing hints, as well as general hints, maybe in the right column, at the time the question's being written.

This is for the use of noobz who are willing to make an effort. I know some questioners won't have a clue about the tags they need. That's OK, we already have downvoting and close voting to cope with that.

Comment: I like the idea of testing various orders for the text fields, but this is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: I think this might just be another case of the asker not recognizing what the real problem is.

Answer (score 4):

I propose SO improves the suggested questions feature. Here's why.

I know that poorly-worded questions are going to be difficult to help, but I just made a comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840687/form-validation-at-least-one-checkbox-is-required-in-a-group) and when I pasted the exact question title into Google the 2nd result was a SO question from 2011 that had the exact answer that I think the OP wants. However, that question from 2011 did not come up in the list of suggested questions for me when I created a new question just to test this. If it had, and if it had stood out to the OP, I'm fairly certain they would not have wasted their time posting, and anyone else's time reading.

Therefore, I suggest that a good way to reduce the number of unnecessary questions is to improve the suggested questions feature.

Comment: This is _also_ something we are working on as we improve the underlying search infrastructure. I'm not sure what this answer has to do with question templates, however.

Comment: @JonEricson it has nothing to do with templates, I suppose, but in my opinion a template is not going to do nearly as much to help address the issue as improving the suggested questions feature.

Comment: ...so you see Jason, because your answer was not deemed suitable although it might solve the problem at the root of this question, thus rendering the question redundant, you get a down-vote. :(

Comment: @NickM that's fine.

Comment: @NickM: Search failure is definitely [part of the reason we have bad questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358412/1438). It might have helped avoid that particular duplicate. But fixing search requires architectural changes that we are working on the background. So no matter how much we want to fix the problem, we have to wait for the developers working on search. But we _don't_ have to wait for that work to be done to test templates. So that's what we are doing and why we are doing it now.

Comment: About the template. Maybe you can ask the user to fill in tags first then show the form possibly with a template if based on tags you have one deemed appropriate. About search, hare you just using ES or are you also using some ML to evaluate and categorize?

Comment: THIS!  I've started just immediately going to "ask a question" and typing out my thoughts, because the questions it starts to suggest on the side are always significantly better than the ones that come up if I ask the question in my specific wording.

Further, every time I find one this way, I wish I could make it so the question I wanted to ask forwards to it without a ton of work.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [Cerbrus's idea,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358023/3345375) a form with multiple text fields to help in structuring the question.

> 1. Here's what I would like to do: __________
> 2. Here's the problem: __________
> 3. Here's what I have tried so far: __________
> 4. Summary (one sentence): __________

Then auto-create a question that includes section headings:

> **Here's what I would like to do:**
>
> (Response to part 1.)
>
> **Here's the problem:**
>
> (Response to part 2.)
>
> **Here's what I have tried so far:**
>
> (Response to part 3.)

And use the response to part 4 (one-line summary) as the question title.

We could tweak the exact wording, but hopefully this form would be general enough for any type of StackOverflow question.

Comment: I could argue that "Summary" should be first...but, now how does that differ from the Title?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Maybe "4. Summary (one sentence)" should be replaced by "4. Question tittle (one line)" to make it clear. I placed it last because I think people would write more descriptive titles if they would describe the issue in detail first and then write a question title that summarizes the issue.

Comment: Fair enough!  Good stuff!

Comment: Despite all the complaints that "SO questions are too different to fit a single template" ...this one actually applies for virtually everything! +1!

Comment: Looks like there's a misunderstanding what "Summary" is meant to be. It appears to be "the question proper": given the situation, what specific question(s) the OP is expecting an answer to, well, answer.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I professionally interact with someone who has a problem, I usually ask one question: "What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing, or what do you expect it to do that it isn't doing?"

I ask this question so many times at work that I have it hot-keyed.  There are many answers I see here suggesting what I say, but not as many that are wrapped up in as small a sentence as I have prepared here.

Comment: that is actually two questions separated by a `,`. granted they are the same question just worded differently, but still two questions

Comment: 1)The formulation is not enough. It doesn't require to provide enough information for us to be able to answer. 2)Any problem must be reduces to an MCVE ~= a reusable form. The formulation misses this critical fact entirely.

Comment: It was not so long ago I asked my first question here. It was editted few days later by someone i didn't know, later turned out to be some heavy-weight on the forum.  Eversince I'm wrestling code-formatting and quotes when asking/answering. A step-by-step introduction and guidance in this would be very convenient, imo.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should hire Morgan Freeman to read [ask]. People will just sit and listen to his voice and do what is says. [Science says so](http://time.com/4233926/morgan-freeman-voice-waze-science/). People will create accounts just to hear him talk. Do it. Now.

Comment: I'm not sure we have the budget for Morgan Freeman.

Comment: @JonEricson lol... start a gofundme page... watch the money roll in for this. It can't take him that long to read 5 mins worth of text...

Comment: ...then do another with Joe Pesci... Jim Breuer can do a good impression of him. Maybe he'll even throw in a goat boy reading of it.

Comment: Maybe he'll give us a discount, but it looks like he's at [$100,000 - $1,000,000](http://www.celebrityspeakersbureau.com/talent/morgan-freeman/).

Comment: @JonEricson Holy crap... but that's the fee for him to give a speech. He can record this at his home or whatever for cheap. At that point it might be hourly.

Comment: oh my gosh this is gold. See how well it works for GPS?? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xLR5mjkfs4

Answer (score 4):

There are five points I would like to raise for the question of, what to put in a template to ask better questions. The points include the workflows around the templates, and not just the template itself.

***First***, in UX design, you should tell people something three times. The purpose of the site should be a high priority for new users. The templates, the work flows, and the supporting pages should stress Stack Overflow is a site for *Programming and Development* questions. It should span multiple pages and be included in the template.

The Stack Overflow homepage and pages in the workflow must include the purpose of the site. This is an [essential element in UX design](https://www.market8.net/b2b-web-design-and-inbound-marketing-blog/how-to-use-directional-cues-in-your-ux). A number of Meta users [rejected the UX requirement/best practice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358111/608639) in the past.

Once a user becomes experienced enough, perhaps the proactive prompts and additional visual queues can be decreased or eliminated, much like ads are reduced over time as badges accumulate.

***Second***, folks need help when Stack Overflow is a bad fit for their question. In the absence of help finding the right site, some will dump it on Stack Overflow anyways. Perhaps the Data Analysis team can aggregate tags and some keywords from the question, and offer alternatives when it make sense based on the context.

For example, based on analysis, a final prompt like *"Are you sure you want to post this to Stack Overflow? Stack Overflow is a site for Programming and Development questions, and your question might be a better fit on Super User or Unix & Linux Stack Exchange"*

***Third***, please check the HTTP referrer header and use the referrer as a data point. When warranted the site should increase UX awareness and visual queues, like the purpose of the Stack Overflow site and confirmation prompts before posting.

[Google](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/filereport#community) and [Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/forums/) self-help pages send people to the Stack Exchange network for support rather than supporting the products themselves. That explains why we get so many questions like *"how do I SSH into {Google Compute|Amazon|Azure|<favorite storage>}"*. In fact, some users argue Google and Microsoft tell them to ask on Stack Overflow.

In fairness, [Google](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/filereport#community) and [Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/forums/) offer choices in self-help. But Stack Overflow has brand recognition like Apple and Coca-Cola, so folks flock to Stack Overflow.

***Fourth***, maybe there should be an Answer template in addition to question templates. New users post answers to anything they think they can answer, and they don't realize they are [encouraging more off-topic posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448).

Ironically, I also find high reputation users willing to answer off-topic questions, too. I regularly observe users with 40K or 160K answering off-topic questions. It brings about some amusing defenses from high reputation users, like copying/pasting a command in a terminal is programming the terminal. (I've been guilty of this as well).

***Fifth***, some tags seem like they attract more off-topic posts than others. For example, Linux and SSH attract a lot of off-topic questions. The workflows should take tag history as a data point and increase UX awareness and visual queues, like confirmation prompts before posting.

---

I kind of hesitate to point this out because its kind of obvious... The Stack Exchange network has a [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). Instead of relying on votes from non-experts (like computer programmers), maybe it would be a good idea to include the UX experts (the folks on UX.SE) in this process. The UX experts could likely offer insights and suggestions a typical site user lacks.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughts. The answers to this question have definitely convinced me that answer templates are a good idea. ;-) I'm not sure prompting people to ask on another site is a good plan unless we can be nearly certain the suggestion will help.

Comment: Personally, I'm for point *the Second*. I see a lot of questions on SO that are good questions in the wrong place. The Stack Exchange network is big, but most people know about SO, so that's the first place they go.

Answer (score 3):

Each site has a 'tutorial' help screen (the one you get a bronze badge for scrolling to the bottom of). At the moment I can't even find this page.

On this page are two lists. One says 'do ask a, b, c', and the other says 'don't ask x, y, z', with green check marks on the dos and red Xs on the don'ts.

I've always felt that these two lists should be readily available for any site, not just hidden away on that page, and especially should be presented any time you ask a question. Even knowing they exist, it's extremely hard to find them to compare my question against. And the fact that they're different for every site makes it even harder to remember making it even more important to display the question-asking rules for each one.

Comment: I think you are talking about [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). On Stack Overflow, new users are funneled through [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) before they can ask. It doesn't include all the items from the tour, but I think it's aiming for similar guidance. That said, I can see how embedding this sort of advice in a template as an HTML comment might help askers.

Comment: "And the fact that they're different for every site is even worse." This is necessary and a good thing; each site is different and has different scopes and expectations; different ideal question formats. If we had the same restrictions for other sites as we did this one, then there are probably at least half a dozen SE sites in the network where literally 100% of the questions are suddenly close-worthy... not even considering topicality.

Comment: @TylerH I only mean "worse" in that it's harder to remember and even more important to show the dos and don'ts for each particular site, not that all sites should be the same.

Comment: There is way too much information on the tour page. If someone is anxiously trying to find an answer to a problem they are having all the stuff about voting up and down and badges and whatever is really just a distraction. It's their first question.  "Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"  Also a problem.  Show your work does not make sense in the context (which is a list of what not to do).   Lots of that is good information for once you get your first vote or a badge or whatever.

Comment: @Elin I'm specifically referring to the two check lists that are on the tour page, not the whole page.

Comment: @DaveCousineau I am agreeing with you but making an additional more critical comment about the tour page and the content of the check list item that says (show your work) is confusing.  If nothing else it should be (show your work instead) but it makes that one item not parallel in that the others are all more strict "do nots" with no suggestion about how to edit.

Answer (score 3):

First: I think if this is worth doing, it's worth doing it properly. Especially if it's for test purposes. Bad execution could lead to bad results which could lead people to assume that the whole enterprise is a waste of time.

This is why I think that a wizard is far preferable to a template. 9 times out of 10 a "just get out of my face" asker will just delete the template and do what they'd have done anyway.

An intelligent wizard could have branches, as suggested by Arkadiy, but here is my variation on the theme of "gimme the codz":

- Resume your problem in less than 20 words (title)
- What are you trying to do?
- What is going wrong?
- What have you tried so far? (Code, google searches)
- Where do you see yourself five years from now? ;)

I believe the mission statement is (or was) "making the internet a better place". Echoing something someone has already said here, I think we should look into how we could transition to something like "helping developers to improve, the world over". (With that mission statement, maybe Documentation would have had a clearer and more motivating purpose - I'd have called it "The Big Picture").

Comment: As I said in the question, we're looking into doing a wizardy thing regardless of the outcome of this test. The applicable lesson from Docs (as I see it) is to start small, test often and gather feedback along the way. If folks just delete the template, that's useful information. This test is so lightweight we'll have lost almost nothing trying it. If we build out a more complicated branching system without some pre-testing, there's a good chance we'll fail and not really know why.

Comment: @JonEricson, I think the applicable lesson from Docs is to have a clear idea of what we're  trying to do, and a way of deciding whether a) we're not achieving what we wanted to or b) we had the wrong idea in the first place :)

Answer (score 3):

### Preface

Stackoverflow should not be so concerned about fewer new questions being asked because 99.999999% of all the general problems already have duplicates.

> Ad revenue is not made by lots of people asking new low quality
> questions, it is made by people finding answers to old common
> questions that have been answered, most of the time for years.

Accepting all the *sewage* as someone else calls it, is actually drowning out the answers to these highly common questions.

So punitive measures to people selfishly ignoring the site guidelines and just posting *read me the docs*, *send me teh codez*, and *explain this code line by line* questions can never be too severe.

Right now, these people easily claim ignorance, many times when they have a long history of asking the same types of questions selfishly that is easy to see.

All that said, I still think [this is a better idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252769/probationary-period-for-questions-to-be-answered-to-encourage-better-questions-w) to help force the education of new users and remediate the flood of low quality questions from brand new users that selfishly want an answer to their highly localized, most likely off-topic and assuredly low quality question immediately and do not care about anything else.

The idea of a *one size fits all template* is a terrible one.

The idea of a few templates for a few special question types is a terrible one.

Any kind of template system will fail, no matter the number of templates, because if the template is just pre-defined headings they will either be ignored or just deleted by the problem users. If it is a *form* with individual fields, the the current *Title* field kind of proves that approach as useless as well, no reason to expect better form field data than the current title data.

---

### Want a different outcome, you have to force a completely different behavior!

> The idea of offering users a "type/classification of question"
> drop down before they ask a question that includes all the *off-topic*
> classes as well as a few common general type of on-topic questions and
> a *Other* is the most effective direction to take.

### Some Example Categories ( not complete )

#### On Topic:

- I am getting an error message and I do not know what it means.
- I have some code that compiles and runs but give the wrong results.
- I have some code that does not compile and I do not understand the compiler error.

#### Maybe On-Topic/Maybe Not:

- I have a question about how to do something the best way.
- I have a question about which design pattern to use.
- I have a question about some code and how it works/why it was written that way/etc.

#### Off-Topic:

- Why did the team X team do Y?
- Which framework should I use to do X?
- Framework X vs Y vs Z?
- Explain "some basic CS concept/theory" in detail.
- Where can I find examples of X?
- Lots more all listed in *"What not to ask?"*

#### Other:

- My question does not fit in any of those categories?

*Other* should go into some kind of queue like reviews to get people to vote on what category it fits it. If say three more people pick *Other* then it is *Other*, if it is something Off-Topic then it should be a strike against them and after some point of them just picking *Other* over and over, they should not be allowed to pick *Other* anymore.

> When those `Off-Topic` types are picked, the user is educated why they should not
> ask that type of question, and this should be tracked, especially when they then pick *Other*. If they go ahead and ask a question and it is closed for that specific off-topic reason(s) they have picked then it should weight
> like 10X against the question ban.

There are a few basic machine learning and expert system techniques that could improve the remediation of low quality questions easily. And fewer low quality questions means probably an order of magnitude fewer low quality answers.

This requires a completely different behavior and would more likely result in different outcomes.

Templates is just more stuff to ignore; which is actually no different behavior than now.

Comment: Fortunately, we are just doing a pilot test of one-size-fits-some templates. If the results are encouraging we're planning to build out something similar to what you suggest. I think it would be terribly shortsighted of us to _ignore_ the volume of bad questions and so we are not. This very meta question is part of a defense-in-depth strategy we've pursued for years. (Please see: [my answer to "Why are there so many bad question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358412/1438))

Comment: @JonEricson - *"baby steps"* in the wrong direction ( template ) is not going to provide any validation to a completely different solution. That is like saying you are going to learn how to ride a bicycle with training wheels and if successful you are going to race F1 cars. Actually *"baby steps"* always lead to failure, it is a process designed to prove failure not success. It is a process of *"doing enough to fail and no more"*, in the 30 years I have been doing software development.

Comment: I think a better analogy is testing a scale model of a race car before building the actual car. I'm willing to [be persuaded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/1438) that a single template test is not representative of the self-categorization system you are suggesting. But it's not helping to jump to absurd arguments.

Comment: scale model to full size are not any less absurd for more valid experiments either because of many reasons, the most important one is material physics. A single template test is nothing more than a single template test, it does not even begin to represent what a multiple template system would result in or how it would perform. Even more so, it does not even validate anything other than that single template that was picked performs. Maybe a different template would perform better or worse. That is why A/B/C testing exists. Single template == *baby steps* mentality and an invalid outcome.

Comment: Correct. This is why we are collecting ideas for several different templates to A/B test. We're looking at just testing one template to start in order to verify the initial work. If that test is encouraging, we'll probably jump more quickly to a template selector. If it's not encouraging, we'll test a larger variety of templates (probably in parallel to save time).  If templates don't work at all, testing will help us know _why they don't work_. We've long passed the point where intuition is a helpful guide to approaching this problem.

Comment: I can tell you the only reason you need to know why the template(s) no matter how many will be a waste of time. Human nature, which is P.C. for selfishness; dictates that the target audience will just delete the template text and do what they do now. Or if they are forced to enter in stuff into template fields will enter nonsense into any mandatory fields, kind of like the *Titles* are today, mostly garbage. Templates will not change **behavior**. You have to change the **behavior** to change the **outcome**. Forcing them to do something different forces a different behavior and thus outcome

Comment: **The most selfish thing an asker can do is ask a question that will actually get a useful answer.** Of course many people will just ignore the template. (I expect many won't even bother to delete it.) But the thesis of this test is that a template might help a tiny portion of askers create good questions rather than bad ones. We've tried the silver bullet approach with [little effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358412/1438). Forcing users to do something different often results in users finding more innovative ways to cheat.

Comment: I was also skeptic about the idea of a template that is both generic and useful enough... [until I actually saw one in another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358273/648265).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev - put gibberish in all the fields and then delete the entire block of text is what will happen by the target audience this is trying to address. It is just a trivial speed bump for the least amount of effort help vampires.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Not 100% of them. If even 20% will, that will already be a huge win. Currently, I see that many (most) newbies -- not help vampires, even those showing genuine effort -- honestly don't know what information to include for us to be able to answer.

Comment: @JonEricson "The most selfish thing an asker can do is ask a question that will actually get a useful answer." I reject this premise. The most selfish thing a user can do is ask a low effort, crap question that a bunch of answerers have to guess about the details and they choose the one that happens to guess right about the final output. It is *vastly* less selfish to create a *useful* question that gives a good presentation of what their current understanding is and what they find confusing about it. Such a question also generates very useful answers.

Comment: @jpmc26: So the [data suggests](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/761142#graph) downvoted questions are unlikely to get even one answer, much less several. If you want multiple answers, your best bet is to ask a question that gets upvoted. Of course, new users are not likely to understand this and some users aren't going to ask good questions no matter what. My point is there is untapped potential among users who would like to get answers, but just don't know how to ask.

Comment: @JonEricson These questions are frequently upvoted or receive answers before I see them to downvote. Even I fall into the trap of trying to answer questions that have failed to clarify their needs occasionally. What's worse is that they virtually *never* go back and clarify once they start receiving answers, even when explicitly asked. I don't know how'd you'd even quantify that, but it's clear that voting, especially *early* voting, does not reflect quality *that* well.

Comment: @JonEricson Also, have a [more readable query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/761183#graph). I took the liberty of looking at some [additional calculations](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/761212). Negative scoring question have an *over 30%* chance of getting answered; nonpositive scoring questions have an almost *50%* chance. Nonpositive scoring questions comprise 60% of all answered questions and **70% of all questions**. This shows that askers consider the odds for no effort questions to be *very* worth posting them.

Comment: @JonEricson Of course, I'm ignoring the fact that some good quality questions are never upvoted and some (possibly many) poor quality questions receive a positive score. I don't know how much this evens out, and I don't know of a way to measure it. But the data certainly suggests that the odds of getting an answer even on a bad question aren't *that* bad. The cost of asking a bad question is also very low, so in a cost/benefit analysis, asking a bad question might even have a bigger probability of payoff for the effort involved.

Comment: @jpmc26: I did, in fact, ask [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359713/take-the-knife-edge-question-challenge) because of our conversation. But the general idea has been bubbling up in my mind for a few weeks (or maybe longer). I think there's a disconnect between the criteria most voters use on questions and the signal active users expect to get from score. These conversations are helping me understand that disconnect a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

please mention somewhere in the question panel that you can ask a question only every 90 minutes. so this makes them think and present the question in a more simplified and direct manner.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that is missing from almost every question I see is a complete lack of attempting to think through their issue and understand what information they need. Essentially, the vast majority of questions are missing an attempt to answer the question themselves. The result is that the asker often doesn't have a good grasp of the task they're trying to perform. This results in missing but necessary details (Unlcear) and low quality questions that are trivially solved by combining a couple or a few other simple operations (Gimme teh codez, closable as Too Broad for asking to do multiple tasks).

Note that this is not optional in crafting a good question. You *must* go through these steps to be able to to articulate the nature of your problem. You *must* go through these steps to identify individual pieces of your complete task, rather than just asking others to do you work for you. You *must* go through this to be able to clarify what information you are looking for.

Here are two ideas to start working with.

#### Explain what you *do* understand about your problem

The user needs to articulate their current understanding of the situation. Without this information, we cannot judge where their understanding currently lies and what is wrong with it and what is right about it.

This will include information like

- What the user tried (and why they tried it)
- Information the user discovered during research

#### Explain what you *don't* understand

This helps the user nail down exactly what it is they're actually looking for. It helps them identify for themselves where their understanding is going wrong.

This includes things like

- Specific behaviors or details that the user finds confusing.
- Guesses about cause (the location, the direct reason without knowing how to fix it)
- Specific requests for information

Going through this process will prevent the asking of many questions, as users will often find they untangle the issue themselves.

Comment: "You must go through these steps to avoid dumping a question that is solved by a trivial combination of other simple tasks." A question that is solved by a trivial combination of simple tasks is not off-topic at SO by that metric alone.

Comment: @TylerH No one said it is. That does not prevent them from being of extraordinarily low quality. Such questions categorically deserve downvoting. The goal is to drive users toward high quality questions and discourage the asking of low quality ones.

Comment: If something seems off or poorly phrased about this post, please let me know. Perhaps the wording can be refined. But if users are fundamentally opposed to the idea that askers need to actually think through their questions before asking, then this entire template and any other effort to improve question quality is a complete waste of time.

Comment: Let's apply this logic to [one of my recent questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42635091/1079354)  "What do I think the answer should be?"  I *literally* have no idea.  "What confuses you?"  "Quite frankly, everything about this situation."  I'm really not sure how that'd help me when asking a question...?

Comment: @Makoto You thought the answer to your problem is something to do with the hooks directory missing. You were confused about why one wasn't created, especially given that one is created on your local machine. This is information you spent a great deal of effort hunting down and trying to answer your own question. (+1 for a good question, btw.) Any ideas on how the wording here could be improved to make that clearer to you?

Comment: I think users are fundamentally opposed to the restrictions you personally feel should be applied. Simple questions are OK as long as they are specific, on-topic, and objective (and not a duplicate). Just because you don't personally like them doesn't make them low quality.

Comment: @TylerH Then why is "lacks research effort" a downvote reason? A question like I describe *fundamentally* fits into this category. These questions also very typically have edge cases that the asker never addresses, even upon specific requests for clarification, leaving answerers guessing about what the actual requirements are. Yet such questions frequently receive positive scores; we *really* need something to discourage them.

Comment: Hmm.  I suppose I can agree with the "user needs to articulate their understanding" bit.  However, that's an *incredibly* tough thing to master since it's so horribly nuanced, and subjective to, well, how others view the question.  As a template, it's tough to say that this would be serviceable since there's nothing realistically stopping a bad asker from stating what I did.  The difference in those two situations is actually looking into the question and determining what's going on as opposed to a static check which could be cheated.  I agree with the spirit, but I don't see it working out.

Comment: @Makoto Honestly, if a template can't get users to articulate their understanding, then the whole thing is a waste of time. Yes, it's a hard skill to master, but the fact that asking a good question is a difficult skill doesn't mean we should tolerate low quality questions. Perhaps if something in the vein of what I'm suggesting is included, it would at least act as a good heuristic for low quality questions when a user fails to answer, and maybe more users would readily downvote them.

Comment: @jpmc26 Because a question has a simple answer, or a problem a simple solution, doesn't mean that the user didn't research it. I have seen many questions across this site & when googling for answers to my own questions over the years where the solution is not documented anywhere official, and is buried in some obscure site 14 pages down in the google results, with the solution being some simple one-liner. That's simple; trivial. It's also *not* easy to search for. Quit applying your bias to a category that doesn't deserve it. Downvote questions where research would yield an answer, instead.

Comment: @TylerH I didn't say simple questions are necessarily bad, particularly when some documentation fails to communicate the solution well. I said that questions that are *trivial combinations* of other simple tasks are bad questions. Consider for example, "How do I print out the contents of a file to the console?" This is not a good question. It's a trivial combination of "open the file" and "print the lines" and would have been solved with a trivial amount of research. But even a simple question benefits from the user explaining where their gap in knowledge lies.

Comment: [I think you may have hit the nail on the head about this whole "template" thing, @jpmc26.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358265/1079354)

Comment: @Makoto lol. Actually, now that I think about it, maybe the template is more beneficial for *answerers*. Filling in a template with garbage makes it much easier to recognize the lack of effort.

Comment: @TylerH I've made a major revision to my answer. See if this makes more sense to you.

Comment: I'm frankly horrified that three people thought "make askers think about their questions" should be downvoted.

Comment: @JoshCaswell To be fair, the original suggested wording in here probably wasn't that good. "What do you think the answer is?" could probably be pretty easily misread as condescending. Hence why I revised heavily. But thank you for the encouragement.

Comment: I suppose it is a bit clearer now. And it reminds me of [jmac's puzzle analogy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason/215220#215220).

Comment: @jpmc26 The issue I have with the answer is still present. Simple questions are not inherently off-topic or low quality.

Comment: @TylerH Questions that lack research or any attempt to understand the nature of the problem *are* categorically low quality, though, and such questions by definition lack these. I really feel like you're not even trying to understand the point I'm making; you're too focused on overgeneralizing the word "simple." None of askers, answerers, or readers are better served by being unable to piece together two lines of code on their own. If that is really not a dominant opinion, then any effort to improve the quality of questions is doomed to fail and we should all just give up.

Comment: @JoshCaswell:  It *really* was the wording that initially led me to doubt its viability.  I still doubt it, but not as severely.

Comment: @jpmc26 Questions can be simple and not lack research/attempts to understand. It sounds like *you* are overgeneralizing the word simple to mean additional things.

Comment: @TylerH No, I'm being specific about what kind of question I'm talking about. I've clarified in comments several times and even edited the answer to try to be more clear. Yes, some simple questions are good questions. However, the majority of seemingly "simple" questions I see are either, "Write my code for me because I can't be bothered to read two other questions and figure out how to put them together," or actually have a ton of edge cases the OP didn't bother to even consider or clarify their needs for. These are *not* good questions that offer any lasting value to anyone, even the asker.

Answer (score -2):

How about when a user first creates a question we dim the website and show him a guided tour? Something like how it's done in Android:

[image]

We could add "copy your code and click to format it, never link to a screenshot" as a step. And as a first one I'd add something like this:

> **Is your question about programming?**
>
> Stack Overflow is a site about developing computer software. If the problem you're facing is not about creating your own program or tools related to coding, you should probably ask elsewhere. If you have a problem with installing/configuring third-party software, ask in [Super User](http://superuser.com) instead

A short, 4-5 step tour like this could help, especially if we make it full-screen and obtrusive enough (not a small box to the right of the editor). Granted, some people will spam the next button, but at least people who genuinely didn't know how Stack Overflow works, now do. Of course, this would appear only for the first question asked.

Comment: +1. That proposition reminds me of mine, back in June 2009 (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/521/6309)

Comment: Oh god no. I hate it when apps do this, not to mention websites. I usually click through these _"holding hands"_ tours without actually paying attention, just to get it over with.

Answer (score -3):

One thing I would like to see added, which may apply more to some of the other sites, than to SO specifically, is to keep the post limited to one question, or at least one narrow topic. I've seen this several times across the various SE sites. User posts a question, and at the end of the post, adds a tangential question, that would be better served in a separate post.

Comment: What do you think should be in the post template to prevent users from posting multiple questions at once?

Answer (score -3):

How about suggesting the user how a good question looks like, just like

**Questions that may already have your answer** kind of illustration.[image]

We may name it as **Best questions look like** and list the best questions so that a user can have a glance at them.

Answer (score -3):

All good answers.  I would also suggest a decay period of time or reputation after which the template won't appear.  Unless a question is closed. In which case the users gets the template again.

Comment: We'll need to see if the feature even works before trying to refine it. ;-)

Answer (score -3):

How about encouraging people to include the version numbers for the library/libraries their question relates to?  I'm talking about things like React versions, NPM/NuGet package versions and the like .

At the moment if you look at an answer, use the code and it doesn't work you then have to try and work out if the code actually relates to the version of the library you are using as well as just working out if you are using the code incorrectly.  That seems like a real time waster, especially when you are learning a new library and have a lot of questions and little experience.

(I do appreciate that tags handle that in some cases)

Comment: I agree this is something I'd like to prompt for. Might not be helpful for _every_ question, but is vital for some questions. The difficulty (for the asker and the system) is identifying which question is which.

Answer (score -4):

Nothing.

Seriously, nothing.

The vast majority of people who post garbage questions are the same help vampires that haven't bothered to actually read through the tour, or How to Ask, or search to see if their question is already answered. To be blunt, they don't give two s**ts about asking better questions, they don't intend to contribute to the community in any way shape or form - they only care about getting an answer to the problem that they are having right now.

Attempting to encourage this type of person to post better questions is a waste of everybody's time. Whether you go with a template, or a wizard, or even someone physically sitting next to them and holding their hand, it's not going to prevent them from posting their terrible incoherent word salads. The only benefit that a template/wizard would have is to add more hoops for them to jump through, which would presumably be enough discouragement to thin their numbers somewhat.

Until Stack Overflow accepts that bad questions are a result of bad users, and does something to address the latter problem, the former problem is going to persist.

Comment: You may wish to reconsider your phrasing, given [the fate of an earlier answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358161/) with a similar view. Don't let the substance of your point be lost because of the form.

Comment: "The only benefit that a template/wizard would have is to add more hoops for them to jump through, which would presumably be enough discouragement to thin their numbers somewhat."  Sounds like progress to me.

Comment: I encourage you to read [my answer to "Why are there so many bad questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358412/1438) In any case, there's very little harm to trying something new while we wait for the technology to [deliver a jolt of electricity](https://threepanel.com/t/cube-drone/18/20) to people who ask bad questions.

Comment: @JoshCaswell "Be Nice" is BS because it assumes that everyone is trying to be nice, which is very obviously not the case with help vampires. "Be Nice" is what's killing Stack Overflow and until and unless the powers that be accept this, we are going to continue to be inundated by tides of crap. Considering Spolsky's only aim nowadays seems to be monetising the s**t out of SO, maybe that was always the end game.

Comment: I'm [largely](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348030/is-documentation-a-failed-experiment#comment526687_348030) in [agreement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351792/) with your answer; that's why I was worried about it.

Comment: I don't think most people know they are help vampires, they just haven't been "shown the light" so to speak. If we implement some kind of wizard that walks them through the right way to ask a question and provides not only guardrails but walls that prevent them from proceeding before providing the necessary info to craft a quality (or at least not worthless) question, that's progress, no? Doing nothing accomplishes nothing... you don't really want that.

Comment: there are no *bad users* if all the users generate income. by definition these *bad users* are the *best users* for generating income given their numbers and proclivity for coming here for every problem no matter how small or trivial for a copy/paste answer.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson when SO started it didn't need these _bad users_ to generate income because it was getting income from web search visitors finding answers in _good_ questions. Such a pity that attracting income this way seems to be becoming a forgotten art. As evidenced by recently introduced [spammy banner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357858/839601) that will likely repel / distract such visitors

Comment: @gnat - when it started, `rep` actually had some value because it actually quantified something because it represented something valuable, now it does not really represent anything other than *I do lots of the things the system rewards me for, most of which are meaningless because anyone can do them*

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Are you confusing reputation with badges? The system does not confer reputation (except a one-time association bonus of 100 rep); users do that manually.

Comment: @TylerH - no I am very aware what rep is now and was before the last 4 years.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Okay, well then you're mistaken; the system doesn't reward rep to users.

Comment: @TylerH - then what does? The gamification is part of "the system" if not *the system* in its entirety!; it rewards great questions and answers the same as it does crap questions and answers. It encourages help vampires to put as little effort as possible into questions and provides them with the entitlement attitude to the immediate gratification they desire and get. "the system" rewards all the crap users even more than the non-crap users. So you can say what you want "the system" rewards rep as the incentive to not care about the system as a whole, like cancer that kills the host over time.

Comment: @TylerH - the system rewards you for asking questions, not good questions. It rewards you for posting answers, not good answers, it rewards you for being "fastest gun in the west" without any consideration to correctness/quality, it rewards you for not caring about the system in the whole, it punishes you for caring and honestly rating crap as crap, it rewards those that bitch and moan about downvotes with an outsize outpouring of "counter" upvotes. The system is the gamification rules and they have been screwed for at least 6 years and other than making question downvotes free, no change.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson "then what does" Like I said, users. There are problems with rep and with the system and with the company's priorities, but let's not conflate direct deterministic outcomes with systemic issues.

Answer (score -4):

It would be extremely useful if the user was strongly prompted to provide a JSFiddle or something similar. Just pasting vague code can make things very difficult. I've noticed a lot of people end up commenting immediately asking for a JSFiddle. That seems like a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score -5):

> If the problem was an error or exception, what is the specific error message, and (if applicable) the stack trace?

Can't have vague "I got an error" questions.

Comment: @KevinB the other fields in the template

Comment: @KevinB is correct; we're starting with a very lightweight system of prefilled text. But this answer might still be useful if we move to a more complicated system that guides the asker through the process of posing their question.

Comment: @JonEricson I can still edit for what it could be here.

Comment: I hate long stack traces, almost as much as I hate 100 line `package.json` dumps, and they are rarely necessary.

Answer (score -5):

The best way to improve question quality is to reduce the number of questions that are asked at all. The template should suggest that the poster first search, debug, rubber-duck, and avail themselves of all other avenues for solving their problem before considering posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The cynicism is strong with this one... :)

Comment: The best recommendation so far... unfortunately looks like the goal to have more "why my String.Replace does not change string" duplicates just better formatted...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: We have several other ideas for helping people find duplicates before they ask. If we are specifically looking to reduce duplicate questions, we'll make that the primary metric we look at. For this particular test, that's not the goal.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for clarifying. I understand the scope of your initiative now. But in more general terms, it's more than just duplicates. It's questions from people who sometimes don't even know what language or framework they are using, or ask questions which are so rudimentary they literally have never been asked before, or make debugging requests that they could figure out themselves in five minutes if they knew the most basic debugging techniques.

Comment: The problem is that SO is famous! Instructors are pointing brand new coding students to SO as a way to get their questions answered. However, these new coders have no clue what they're doing, and not enough knowledge to even realize they're asking a question badly. They even think that asking their question on SO **IS** doing their research.They also tend to vote each other's bad questions and answers up, thinking they're helping a friend out. I can't think of any template that's going to help those users understand what and how to ask.

Comment: @enderland It isn't just cynicism. It's true. Asking a question really should [feel like a strange thing to do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1394393). We live in an age where most documentation is readily and freely available and searchable and most of the simple questions have already been asked on a searchable, well organized Q&A site. If you find yourself posting a lot of questions on SO about mature technology, it's a good indication you're not doing enough research or breaking your problems down into smaller tasks.

Answer (score -5):

This is a suggestion for a specific kind of question that requires HTML, CSS, JavaScript constructs. I have observed that many users present their code by using the code sample instead of a code snippet. For instance, users will post something like:

HTML

```
<div>My HTML code</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
   ...some CSS...
}
```

JavaScript

```
var myJs;
```

This is a clear situation where the code snippet is better suited since it will produce a running example that can be visualized inside the thread.

If possible to catch this case, the user could be presented a callout indicating that her code could be structured inside a snippet to create a running example.

Comment: I usually see the opposite problem, people posting Java code, configuration files, or even log messages as code snippets. I blame the naming and it probably can be at least improved if not solved, not sure if it's related to a template though.

Comment: All the more reason to clarify the purpose of the code snippet. As we see it is being both misused and underused, depending on the nature of the question. This is not related to a template but it is related to generally improving the quality of questions.

Comment: Stack Snippets are not even well-suited for the majority of web programming questions. Rarely do people post complete code that runs as a snippet, and it is hardly ever necessary that they do so. Experts can solve JavaScript errors without seeing a complete web site. I don't think more encouragement to use Stack Snippets is necessary. As Oleg says, most of the time I see them, they are misused.

Comment: Speaking from experience in PHP, this encourages code barfing. People will use this to post reams of code that aren't relevant to the question. CSS and JS don't cause PHP parse errors...

Answer (score -6):

You're overdoing it... All you need is *one* field for the question *in detail*.

Asked questions have a title. Then follows the actual question - the content. The question often contains details that you cannot (and should not) include in the title. A well-formed question should include a more detailed question *referring* to the *content*. I propose that any asked question should have a refined question at the end. For the same reasons that you have a [summary](https://writingcenter.fas.harvard.edu/pages/summary) when you write an essay.

**Detailed Question:**
Considering the structure of well-written essays, doesn't it make sense to use the same concept for StackOverflow questions?

Comment: No, questions are not essays. I want clear and concise questions, not a life story. If a question is long enough to benefit from a summary, it is probably too long.

Comment: Summary might be the wrong term. Still, I have gotten many appreciative comments on questions where I have adopted this pattern. What I'm suggesting is just a way of enforcing good pedagogy. If you have a question followed by lots of blah blah blah it makes perfect sense to repeat the question.

Comment: Or you just remove the blah blah blah, so you don't have to repeat the question. If a question has too much blah blah blah, no one will read it. Reducing the noise while increasing the signal increases both the question quality and chance of getting the attention of experts in the field.

Answer (score -7):

Not a template suggestion, but a related suggestion to improve the quality.

How about after pressing 'send' on a question without any code included, the user is prompted with an alert with a message along the lines of the following?

> Please include at least a few lines of relevant code in your question. Questions with code added have *x%* more chance of being answered in the next *y* hours.
>   Of all questions without a code sample, z% has not received an answer after *{* days.

The statistics are likely available.

Comment: Only debugging questions require code. For most every other type of question code is usually unnecessary and noise.

Answer (score -7):

The problem with a comprehensive template to cover all possible transgressions is that it will be tl;dr and we'll be back to telling OPs to RTFM.

I would suggest using a deep learning approach to the problem. Train on a subset of all the OPs that have been closed together with the reasons for the close.  When an OP is identified as confidently close-able, display context-specific help based on the predicted reasons for the predicted close.  Neural networks can make predictions very quickly so the user can have a wait time of less than a second.

The user has to at least close the warnings dialog to post.  Then it's a teachable moment.  Discover and Explain is the way to go IMHO.

Answer (score -7):

I know the StackOverflow folks already use Microsoft technologies (I saw evidence of this at this year's Microsoft Build conference!) so this is not far-fetched: how about you employ the [Language Understanding Intelligent Service (LUIS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/home)? You could possibly integrate it with a chatbot, to interactively assist the user as s/he phrases his/her question and provide live feedback not just as to the completeness of the Question form, but also as to whether it successfully illustrates a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, and whether it's already been asked (displaying a list of similar questions as StackOverflow already does). I think it's time StackOverflow (SO) takes its user interface to the next level and capitalize on the numerous Artificial Intelligence (AI) advancements already available and make it clear to visitors that it is running on interactive AI--which it already is, just it's not a very attractive, engrossing, effective, and self-correcting interface... otherwise we wouldn't be having this discussion! A chatbot or virtual assistant of this sort could greatly enhance SO's image and give it a personality, thereby (through its new, more active and involved chatbot/guide/assistant) achieving the goal of helping people ask better questions via the ultimate user-friendly conversational template! It will do all the hand-holding that is presently absent and disallow bad/incomplete questions to get through. It's just got to be executed right so it doesn't become a stumbling block for users or get in the way of what StackOverflow already does sooo well--and that's the tricky part!

Comment: This might be the endgame, but we are starting off much slower to verify we are on the right track. We've [not had great luck](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349410/tearing-down-the-structure-of-documentation) building complex things lately.

Comment: Wow, this is the first I hear about the StackOverflow Documentation site. As much as I've used the Internet for answers to my technical questions over the years, I'm surprised I never ran into it. I do see my idea as a very grand scheme with a similar potential for failure I guess, but hey--we're brainstorming here, right? ;)

Comment: ... `/complex/overly complex/` things lately.

Comment: Thinking that an advanced technology would solve all your problems for you -- especially those you can't even formulate -- is a frequent and grave mistake. Doubly so for M$ technologies. Beyond the glossy look and rich promises typically is a minefield of labyrinthine design, bugs and arbitrary limitations at every step. Which you can do nothing about 'cuz it's closed source. They usually create more problems than they solve.

Answer (score -11):

The irony is that this is a wrongheaded question.

When you're thinking about shaping users as a primary goal (which is much of what SO does) then the problem is the system, not the users.

**How about asking a different question:**

*Given SO's significance as a platform, how can it be shaped to accept and encourage more diverse uses, types of users and ways of considering the practices, paradigms and processes of programming?*

Comment: Why should the system be changed? What kind of questions would you want to allow?

Comment: Because it's digital fascism. All coding questions.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of questions ___aren't___ allowed now, but would you want to be allowed?

Comment: Far and away the biggest problem I see with questions right now is [too many](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318174/why-are-there-so-many-bad-questions/358412#358412) don't have enough information for other people to answer them. Almost as bad, sometimes the information is there, but buried by irrelevancies. It doesn't matter who is asking a question if it is unclear or unanswerable. Unfortunately, people tend to use shortcuts to evaluate the merit of a question and those shortcuts tend to favor questions like the ones that already exist. So better questions could help diversity.

Comment: @Cerbrus I really do mean it: ALL coding questions. Shape the system to deal with this diversity rather than trying to shape users to the system. It's 2017, nearly 2018. I think it's high time the world's largest collection of programmers figured out how to use some of its technologies, toys and talents to benefit the entire spectrum of itself. And all those newly coming to coding and programming.

Comment: @JonEricson you make allowances for the answerers more than you do the questioners. And then defend this by attempting to suggest it doesn't matter who is asking the question. It always matters who is doing something. Someone famous asking a question badly will be treated differently from some unknown with exactly the same wording. Someone good looking will be treated differently, too. You can't avoid these aspects of crowds in a network anymore than you can enforce morals.

Comment: And you use this "better questions" subjectivity that's pertinent only to the experienced in this same sense of subjectivity. It's a subjectivity suited to those bound up in entitlement and power issues, and this is and are also parts of any entrenched system's attainment of power and its sustainment. So there's yet another reason to consider changing the system. This is one of the reasons behaviour around here is akin to a type of fascism that I call "digital fascism".

Comment: _"Someone famous asking a question badly will be treated differently from some unknown with exactly the same wording. Someone good looking will be treated differently, too."_ That is simply not true. That's not how SO works. (Burden of proof is on you here)

Comment: @Cerbrus Sure... and no SO users are subject to the winds of change. Nor do they succumb to the temptations of trends. Take a wild guess: am I being literal or figurative?

Comment: Neither. You're being sarcastic, @Confused. None of your comments, nor the answer have given us a reason to take this rant seriously, so I shall refrain from doing so.

Comment: There it is: "us". Achievement unlocked.

Comment: That "Achievement unlocked" above, that's sarcasm. The rest is not. Including the part where I point out that your use of "us" is the proof positive of your belief in what you perceive to be an ideal SO brand of digital fascism. Which I'm trying to point out is a subjective reality that's limiting yourself (and others) needlessly. Look at the question I'm suggesting be asked in my answer, please. Read it carefully. It was written with some degree of care. When you asked me to be more specific it was clear you probably haven't even read, and certainly didn't bother understanding, that question.

Comment: So I don't think you are wrong, @Confused. But I think the solution to creating a more diverse and equitable Q&A site must begin with helping ordinary people ask answerable questions. We see that many people attempt to ask questions without formatting their code correctly. Some people get more editing help after they ask. But if we can somehow help everyone use code formatting, that would level the playing field just a tiny bit. At the end of the day, I think Stack Overflow helps lots of folks might otherwise be shut out just by making answers available via search.

Comment: @JonEricson I think the question you and the site are trying to ask, but are afraid to voice with any real honestly, is this: we want to continue to grow the site and its traffic, we have an empowered, entitled and enormous answerer base. Can we get a sizeable growth, whilst doing the least amount possible, by preparing new users so they're willing to tolerate the aggressive and fascistic nature of our prolific answerers? This question probably stems from stats showing new users leave often, early, and don't much return. But I'm reading between the lines a bit on many things I've seen/noticed.

Comment: @JonEricson I don't much understand this comment: "I think Stack Overflow helps lots of folks might otherwise be shut out just by making answers available via search." Largely because SO is a monopoly on what it does, this seems like a flag being waved in the air at non users. Are you somehow suggesting you've considered being a club and removing public search for non-members and removing yourself from google results? I don't see how anyone can "otherwise be shut out" from what already exists.

Comment: @Confused: I'm saying that before Stack Overflow, it was hard to find answers to long-tail programming questions. So people needed to ask themselves. With answers available via Google, there's no barrier to entry except internet access. But we've travelled a long way from my question. (I also do not appreciate or accept the adjective "fascistic" when it comes to people who answer questions. Most just wish questions had the enough information.)

Comment: @JonEricson I think it's wise to consider pre and post SO. And the nature of programming at all different levels, in all the spectrum of possible computing endeavours. On distance from your question, you and I differ. I think we're getting closer to a question worth considering when we think holistically about programming and THEN consider SO's capacity and capricious current users. Simply oiling the chains of SO commerce and finding more gears to grinds, when it's already a monopoly, seems like a waste of an enormous opportunity, to me.

Comment: @Confused you're obviously confused. The problem with the site is not a lack of questions, nor even a lack of open questions. The problem is that alarge portion of the 8000+ questions we receive every day are either unanswerable garbage, or will never be useful to anyone other than the OP. Both of those things drive answerers away from the site, prevent good questions from being answered, and detract from the overall quality of the content here. That's ultimately what we're talking about here improving question quality.

Comment: I f you want to go off on a tangent about how horrible SO is because your question got closed, the comments section under any one of the blog posts expressing the same sentiment would be a good place.

Comment: @TinyGiant If you want to go off on a tangent about how horrible it is that someone questioned the sanctity of SO answerers, this is as good a place as any.

Answer (score -12):

I am surprised that so far nobody has mentioned spell checking.

Just run a spell check on the post, and if the number of spelling errors is too high, ask them to proof-read it.

(And if after proof reading the number of spelling errors is still too high, then [***shadow ban***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stealth_banning) the poster.)

Comment: I assume they expect the template to be static, aka not require much client or server side code to run. But I agree that making posters aware to use a spellchecker (most browsers offer this as an built-in option) is a good idea.

Comment: Shadow banning is despicable, it is the worst thing you can do to anybody online, please don't even joke about it.

Comment: Great idea! But please teach the spell checker all of my library names, variable names, tool names, organizations, standards, technical terms of any profession that might require a computer program, abbreviations, brand names, placeholders such as foo/bar, tech slang, and any other unusual words that might be perfectly valid in the context of a question - wouldn't want any false positives, right? By the way, I just used a spell checker on your post and it found an error - apparently your last name should be spelled "Nikes" instead...

Comment: @Oleg no, we need more of it. C-:=

Comment: @l4mpi all that is easy with analysis on existing SO content.

Comment: We don't have a spell check test exactly, but we do have a [quality filter algorithm](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/) that takes a bunch of related indicators into consideration. But in any case, this is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @Oleg: Related: *[Is there going to be a process around hellbanning?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/93806/is-there-going-to-be-a-process-around-hellbanning)*

Comment: @MikeNakis : No, we do not need more lying.  Having a server deceive you by thinking that it is displaying information (to other people), when it is not, is not a good thing.  More deception is not the approach that this world needs to be seeing more of.

Comment: Downvoted because you're suggesting shadowbanning. That is some seriously despicable behavior you're advocating.

Answer (score -13):

**"What can we put in the question template"** - whatever you put there will be perceived as a way to force people to adhere to a certain type of question. Eg, ask for code / output / expected output will disqualify from SO/SE a lot of questions that are not necessarily related to some piece of misbehaving code. => less content => less traffic => another useless site.

**"...to make people..."** - in a democratic ecosystem (excuse my English, perhaps I should say: on a website where participation is optional) you can't make people do things, or do things in a certain way, and most specially not in whatever way some generic software deems appropriate. You can try but eventually you'll decide it would have been a lot easier to design the software to adjust to people. After all that's the whole point of technology.

**"...better questions"** - this is relative to a lot of things. Years ago I was a noob, when I was on a deadline and some stupid function was returning nil or my database crashed in the middle of the night I couldn't possibly care less about posting according to some template, all I needed was a helping hand. Same for some code that didn't do what I expected (regardless if I RTFM or not...) and for whatever other reason. I do realize SO/SE is not an emergency room, but at the same time it's not supposed to be a casual chatting website either. Real people come here with real problems which do have a degree of importance which is perceived differently by the OP and moderators and whoever else. Flagging some question as "too broad" or "not good enough" doesn't help. Besides you are not flagging the content itself but the way said content is categorized, which makes a huge difference. It's like the famous judging of a fish by its ability to climb a tree. Plus, you cannot make an objective decision to qualify a question as "not good". Instead, I would suggest investing more resources into properly tagging and categorizing content so that relevant questions are promoted to relevant users as well as offering a more substantial incentive for such users to actually invest time into researching and posting for clarifications and/or answers.

Right now I am kind of debating with myself whether I should post this and get lots of down-votes because my answer is not good enough, or call it a day and spare readers of my irrelevant "not good enough" contribution. I will post it anyway because my rep here is not essential to my existence as individual, however the fact that I am having this inner debate clearly translates to "something is wrong". Who are we to judge whether a piece of information (a question, an answer, a comment) generated by someone else is "good enough" or "not good enough" for an unknown 3rd party...

Comment: The point of the template is to *improve* the site's value by giving would-be askers a better experience.  We get a very negative rep for being "too strict" with newcomers, and all we're asking those newcomers to do is to play ball with us.  You're right; we can't make people do things.  But if we don't get the kinds of questions which are on-topic or answerable, we continue the negative cycle.

Comment: _"in a democratic ecosystem"_ SO isn't really a "democracy". For the rest, this answer reads like a bit of a rant. What does it add that hasn't been said in another answer already?

Comment: If you get a question that's not "on-topic" (again, this too is relative to perception) or "not answerable" then perhaps an automated system can push that down the queue so you don't really "get" it anymore. Unless you choose to dig through the bin. There won't be a need to create custom question templates per each type of question/category/whatnot.

@Cerbrus: you're right, I said it wrong.

I wish I just posted the shorter version of my answer: "Nothing".

Comment: But off-topic questions are off-topic. Questions that are lacking information that is required to answer will not be helped with what you describe. This answer shows a clear lack of understanding of the system, the problem,  the proposed solution, and the question asked here.

Comment: Tiny Giant, you are probably right. Sorry for posting that garbage, lesson learned. Going to play with my dog now.

Comment: @NickM your voices of reason don't belong here. Move along. You're being sensible, considerate of users and mindful of technology's possibilities, potential and promise. Such thoughts require empathy and a desire for meaningful connectivity with people not self-selecting for opportunities absence of beneficial, civil and humane responsibility towards the other members of their society. Your dog is lucky to have you.

Comment: @NickM It's funny because I have been debating whether to post an answer about how people have to learn how to ask questions just like they learn anything else. There are effective ways to get that to happen and ineffective ones.   It seems to me that as the discussion goes on and on the responses become more and more like spaghetti code, like if we just add one more goto it will all be okay.