# "How to Ask" is confusing on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, meta

When you're writing the title of a question on Stack Overflow Meta, you get

> **How to Ask**
>
> **Is your question about Stack Overflow?**
>
> We prefer questions that can be *answered*, not just discussed.
>
> Provide details. Share your research.

Requiring that questions be answered rather than discussed is suitable for the main site, but given that lots of questions on meta are a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), it doesn't seem appropriate here.

Comment: No discussion allowed. Nope. None.

Comment: Wait you actually read that text? I thought it was a convoluted haiku.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier That's not a haiku.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 It is in the original language.

Comment: @MrLister the original Klingon, Esperanto, or Mongolian?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Polyglot.

Comment: This is too meta.

Comment: @heez comments about the meta site should be posted on the meta meta.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's a really great rhetorical technique called [parataxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parataxis) that involves placing two ideas near each other and not explaining what, if any, connection the author has in mind. It can create meaning not found explicitly in either idea individually. For instance:

> [Nero fiddled while Rome burned.](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Journals/CJ/42/4/Nero_Fiddled*.html)

Neither phrase means what the sentence means as a whole: Nero didn't care about the plight of ordinary Romans. The human brain draws the right conclusion almost without noticing there's no logical connection.

I think the same effect occurs here on meta when it comes to discussion. Obviously, we *do* encourage discussion since one of the required tags is [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). But we don't want people to ask any sort of discussion question they feel like. This isn't a place for small talk. We want discussion questions *that can be answered*. That is to say, discussions ought to have some sort of purpose beyond the entertainment that comes from discussing things.

In practice, [discussion questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tend to be announcements or specific questions about site policy. Announcement questions are often answered (once you get past the "this should be on the blog" comments) with thoughtful and considered statements of concern, agreement, disagreement and analysis. This is good because these are in fact the sorts of responses we hope to get (and would be harder to produce in blog comments). Policy questions benefit from some of the same sorts of answers.

In addition, we expect discussion answers to [be persuasive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/1438). There's not much benefit in answering questions on meta with unsupported opinion and voting often reflects that reality. As a result, good meta questions ought to set up answers that make arguments based on data, experience and reason. So I do think the sidebar advice works, even if it doesn't perfectly spell out the situation.

It should also be noted the advice quoted in the question includes two important qualifiers:

> We **prefer** questions that can be answered, **not just** discussed.

So there is some wiggle room if you want to be a stickler for the rules.

Comment: So what's the answer?  You'll change it or it stays as is?  Because this isn't really an answer.

Comment: I think it's fine @JonH. It explains a context then acknowledges the situation not being perfect but still being adequate, which is a fine answer to a somewhat vague question ("it doesn't seem appropriate").

Comment: Rather than all this talk a simple yes or no and a small reason. This was a story.

Comment: @JonH: I don't know. This seems, um, kinda low on the list of problems we're facing at the moment. Might be easier to say yes if someone were to write better copy. (Though it is a little awkward that this only matters on meta. That's sorta a pain.) I'm sorry you didn't enjoy the story however.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it indicates that it's "Status-by-design", rather than accidental copypasta.

Comment: How's [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358481) for "better copy"? Probably still needs plenty of tweaking, but if there's anything in there you feel might be useful, feel free to use it. :)

Answer (score 5):

IMO, the *real* issue with this notice (and with many other parts of the meta interface) is that it's talking about "asking a question", even though a significant fraction of the "questions" on meta are really bug reports, feature requests, proposals for a new policy or action, etc. — lots of things that are not, and aren't meant to be, questions.

([A quick SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/746894/count-combinations-of-mandatory-tags-on-meta) indicates that bug reports and feature requests alone make up about 1/3 of the "question" volume here on Meta.SO over this year.  Of course, that figure doesn't include things like tag renaming or burnination requests that aren't really questions, either.)

If the SE meta site interface *really* reflected the way these sites are actually (meant to be) used, the "Ask Question" button would be relabeled e.g. as "New Topic" or something else similarly vague and forum-ish (since there really isn't enough room for that button to read "Ask Question or Start Discussion or Make Proposal or Report Bug or Request Feature or Whatever").  And every other part of the interface that referred to "questions" and "answers" would be similarly rewritten to refer to, say "topics" and "responses".

I'm not holding my breath for that to happen, though.  For the time being, we'll just have to live with the fact that [meta is different](/help/whats-meta) and looks and behaves like a Q&A site, even though it's really not.

In the mean time, here's my modest proposal for rewriting that entire notice you quoted:

> #### How to use Meta
>
> **Are you here to talk about the Stack Overflow website?**
>
> Meta Stack Overflow is a place for discussion about the Stack Overflow website itself.  Here you can discuss policies and community decisions, report bugs, suggest new features, ask about how Stack Overflow works, etc.
>
> If you have a question about programming, [**ask it on Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead.
>
> For more information, see [What is "meta"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

This should hopefully even transfer reasonably well to other per-site metas, with appropriate substitutions for the site name and topic.

Comment: We are working on the ask page (starting with [templates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions)) with the idea that it'll be flexible and customizable for all sites, including metas. One idea (that's been suggested by . . . lots of folks) is an option to select from a list of question types. So there's _some_ chance we'll be able to do something like the first idea. I'm not sure that the proposed copy isn't swinging the pendulum in the opposite direction; it seems to encourage more idle talk as I read it.