# Could tools be helpful to simplify Stack Overflow question asking?

Tags: discussion

I am a new enthusiastic user of Stack Overflow.
During these months, thanks also the suggestions of other users, I have learned how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

It usually takes a few minutes in order to be able to extract the MCVE from the code I am working on, and often quite some time needs to be spent on creating artificial data etc.

My question is whether automated tools exist for this purpose, or whether users on this network would find such tools useful.

e.g.

- Select a code snippet, right click on it,
  activate some shell extension-like that allows to paste the code with variables renamed/obfuscated
- A tool to generate a script which generates a work-space equal to the one of the code one is working on, or a sub-sample of

Comment: Obfuscated variable names would be terrible as it severely decreases readability. If you're looking for heavily downvoted questions, creating hard to read generated MCVE's is exactly the way to go about it.

Comment: Considering the amount of languages one can ask questions about on SO (_all of them_), a tool like this would be a beast to build, let alone maintain...

Comment: Imo, A mcve is a debugging step. Not somethjing that exist only to be post on SO. Yes it can take times. And time should not be a issue, as you are trying to isolate the problem and trying to understand and solve it at the same time.

Comment: We need a feature request: "SO Vpn so Answerer can directly edit my code and check if it compile?"

Comment: @DragandDrop I agree, a MCVE is a debugging step that needs to be done anyway. My question could be rephrased as: are there tool to extract a MCVE from an existing piece of software?

Comment: to be honest I do no see why this question should get so downvoted...I had no expectation to get a ''SO Vpn'' but rather see how the healthy workflows that I learned from SO could be automated....I think it could be useful for any person writing code, but this is an opinion

Comment: @Liborio, Downvote on meta are not the same. they are answering the question: "Do you want/need a tool to extract MCVE?" On meta Downvote do not judge the quality of the post.

Comment: Ok. I would say after this discussion I agree with you, it should not be a tool from SO

Comment: @Liborio, I talked about Vpn cause if someone do not wan't to post a mcve or fail to deliver one. Most of the time they will fail to implement the solution and start commenting answers about how to copy past answer in their code.

Comment: 'I think it could be useful for any person writing code' - it might, a bit.  Unfortunately, it's extremely un-useful for any SO contributor who might want to help.  It's a suggestion to move all the effort and responsibiity for testing/debugging from OP's to the skilled and expereinced developers who answer questions.  OP's will just use such a tool to justify dumping untested code.   NO!  OP has to extract the MCVE, test it and provide inputs/outputs/error messages etc. to how how it fails.  SO should not become a free test and debug house.  NO!

Comment: 1/. Trust a tool for a MCVE 2/. Get your valid and well written question close for typo. Creating a mcve is not copy past and rename! It's build for Scratch and compile.

Comment: If computers could produce *good* MCVE's for a problem, they could probably just write the software for us.

Comment: @meagar I quite doubt that...but it looks like you are one of the users that would find that valuable (as I was originally asking in the question). I also think such a tool would take us closer to singularity

Comment: @ErroriSalvo I wouldn't find the tools you're proposing valuable, no. I ask very few questions, and for the questions I do ask I would never want a tool to automatically generate code for me.

Comment: automatically generate code  is still different from automating repetitive tasks in my view

Comment: The "repetitive task" in question is generating code, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: well not quite. identifying which variables are used in a snippet, and what are their current values, thinking about dummy values, reformatting to fit in quesiton box is not generating code, it is just tedious  copy pasting IMHO

Comment: @ErroriSalvo well, I would call that part of testing/debugging. There is no effective alternative to the OP cutting down the code, with or without the aid of any tools/scripts/whatever, generating an MCVE and then, at least minimally testing and debugging it to make sure it builds and still demonstrates the original problem, before getting SO involved at all.  I certainly would not wish to get involved in specifying/designing any 'MCVE generator' tool, never mind try to build/test/debug one.  Such an effort would just get me blamed for everything, so no chance.

Answer (score 24):

No.

You create a MCVE in your IDE or favorite text editor. You click on <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>New Project...</kbd> and start recreating the minimal code that reproduces the issue.

This is *not* something you do in your browser. Before even thinking about asking a question, you should have your MCVE ready, runnable and reproducing the issue you're facing.

Way too often people use the process you describe. They copy-paste some snippets from their project which they think reproduces the issue, while in fact it doesn't, because the poster omitted crucial code that actually caused the problem to begin with.

Comment: What I meant was not about a browser extensions exclusively

Comment: And I would see that a tool for collaborating between developers, also outside SO, a MWE extractor.

Comment: You can create a blank MCVE outside your project, not containing any sensitive info, and push it to GitHub. That's not Stack Overflow's job to implement.

Comment: where was it stated it was stack overflow job

Comment: I was under the impression that you expected Stack Overflow to include such tools in the Ask a Question window. Nevertheless this isn't something that tools can do for you, yet. You definitely don't want to obfuscate code you copy-paste out of a project, if you think you need that then you definitely need to create a new project.

Comment: Yes, I realize that my question was really not correctly asked. No expectations from SO

Comment: @Liborio If you have no expectations from SO, why are you asking on SO.meta?

Comment: why are you asking on SO.meta? I felt I could be interesting while not being a stricly a question by itself. now I know better the scope of SO.meta, will be more careful in phrasing

Answer (score 5):

I think asking an awesome question requires more than a tool.

But, for years we believed that a pristine white textbox was all that was needed to write the perfect question. Oh sure, there were links to help pages and [external blogs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for guidance but that was about it.
With the upcoming [redesign](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page) of the [ask question page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions) we might steer towards *tool assisted question asking*.

That doesn't mean I think I would appreciate anything that went from an IDE directly into a question. However, there have been a few attempts to create [plugins](https://stackapps.com/search?q=plugin) to support asking a question, or, even more importantly, searching for answers. By all means, try to use the tools that assist you in asking great questions but don't let those tools lure you into becoming lazy and neglecting all the careful crafted advice to curate our quality content.

If such tools doesn't exist yet, and none of the existing attempts serve your goal, by all means start a journey to create such tool and if you book results with them, we would love to hear about it.

Comment: lol, I'm guessing that a great many OP's would like some automated tool to generate their MCVE's, but the number willing to specify, design, code, test, debug and verify such a tool is approximately zero.  To me, this is an old story - 'there is a perceived need for something to help OP's, this would be something, someone else provide the something'.