# Take the knife-edge question challenge

Tags: discussion, question-quality

When talking about question evaluation, it sometimes comes up that voters and answerers are not really to be relied upon to make the determination between good and bad. I'm never sure how to go about defending these objective yet second-order metrics. As humans, we bring all sorts of biases and subjectivity into our evaluations. In particular, we tend to remember bad questions that got upvoted or answered and forget bad questions that are downvoted, closed or deleted. Further, we tend to recall extreme outliers such as the guy who got over 30k of reputation from asking about [the difference between the stack and the heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap).

I don't think there's a foolproof way to rank questions and `Score = up - down` has [fundamental problems](https://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html). However, it's reasonable to assume that for large sample sizes voting reliably separates answerable questions from truly bad questions. To verify that assumption, it's informative to look at a sampling of questions that are right near the dividing line between [good and bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests). These are questions that:

1. are not closed or deleted and
2. have a score of exactly 1 (good) or -1 (bad) or
3. have a score of 0 and at least one answer (good).

I call this the knife edge between good and bad because a single user has made the determination. (Well, this isn't *quite* true, since a +2/-1 question is scored as 1.) You won't see a lot of terrible questions (these tend to be downvoted more, if not closed and deleted). Nor will you see particularly interesting questions. If you eliminate extreme scores, you also eliminate most outliers.

My hypothesis is that -1 questions will tend to look like +1 questions, but lack information needed to answer them. And, of course, questions with 0 score that have answers will have provided enough information for someone to attempt an answer. In other words, we aren't talking a high bar of goodness, but rather **the fundamental quality of a question**. My hypothesis might be wrong, so I'm going to try looking at [a random sample of 10 knife-edge questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/761444/knife-edge-question-evaluation-challenge).

If you'd like to follow along, grab a sample using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/761444/knife-edge-question-evaluation-challenge) and go through each one looking for:

- Comments suggesting the asker provide more information.
- Edits in which the asker provided such information.
- Answers that seem to get at the askers problem.
- Votes on answers (especially when the OP accepted one).
- Comments on answers that indicate the question was successfully answered.

Feel free to report your findings in answer.

Comment: Am I supposed to vote on a good/bad question that comes up during the challenge? Or should I avoid polluting the sample? Also, are the readers encouraged/discouraged to vote on the questions linked in answers? And, do we plan to do *something* with the findings reported?

Comment: The query was a bit confusing since apparently we have to change `dummy` to break the cache. Also, I think mentioning the `dummy` value in the answer also helps others to avoid accidental duplicate set of questions. Otherwise, please input own user ID as the dummy to prevent duplicate value :)

Comment: Your sampling will have a significant bias due to [Roomba](/help/roomba) deleting a whole category of questions which would have fit your criteria. If the question has a score of -1, is > 30 days old and has no answers, then it's deleted. Thus, all your -1 questions are either < 30 days old, or answered. This skews your sampling towards -1 questions which are answered, as [unanswered -1 score questions](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-1..-1+closed%3Ano+answers%3A0) make up  only 2.3% of [all -1 score (!closed, !deleted) questions](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-1..-1+closed%3Ano).

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, what is the objective of this little experiment? Are you going to try and infer patterns based on this little crowdsourced experiment? You could consider automating this with a little applied ML...

Comment: Based on questions < 30 days old, the [unanswered -1 score Qs](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-1..-1+closed%3Ano+answers%3A0+created%3A2017-10-22..) should be about 49.3% of [all -1 score Qs](//stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-1..-1+closed%3Ano+created%3A2017-10-22..). Thus, there are ~450k Qs at -1 score w/o answers which have been deleted. This is particularly relevant because you are specifically hypothesizing about -1 score questions "lack information needed to answer them". Such questions are predominantly the category excluded from selection due to being deleted by Roomba.

Comment: @Makyen: Oh. Yeah, that is a problem. I updated the query to look back a week from 3 days ago. That's kinda annoying. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I mostly did the work to test my instincts/hypothesis. I suspect people (including myself) are biased by extreme examples and don't take the time to verify their assumptions by analysing more typical questions.

Comment: @CodeCaster: It's definitely preferable for the asker to edit the question before posting. And it's one of the goals of the [coming template experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions). On downvoted questions, I'm actually suggesting that voting is just as reliable in either direction. I don't think we ought to change the Roomba logic since a single downvote combined with no answers very likely represents a question that can't be answered without more help from the OP.

Comment: I'm still not getting the point. Is the whole community now running an effort to review random questions because @JonEricson cannot trust his instincts? Is this to find a statistically sharper knife at the end?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Only the portion of the community who reads this question, thinks it's an interesting exercise and has some time to spare on it. It's a bit like those [self-evaluations we stopped doing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261601/shutting-down-recurring-community-self-evaluations). Maybe you might be interested in reading about our [upcoming A/B testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests) that will have some serious statistical muscle behind it.

Answer (score 10):

My ten questions:

> [How to set initial values of MDL slider programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201117/how-to-set-initial-values-of-mdl-slider-programmatically)
>
> Score +0/-0 (0), 1 accepted self-answer (0), 0 comments, 27 views

Way too specific. The question could have asked how to interact with Material Design element through JavaScript, but instead asks about setting a minimum and maximum value for a slider, while there are many more elements with many more properties in that library.

Not a bad question, but only useful and findable for very few people.

> [Is it slow to use the PHP date() func to compare with SQL datetime fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079109/is-it-slow-to-use-the-php-date-func-to-compare-with-sql-datetime-fields)
>
> Score +0/-0 (0), 2 answers (+1, 0), 54 views

They're executing an SQL query (inherently slow) and are asking whether a single `date()` call (and including the resulting string in their query) would noticeably slow down their code. Opinion-based ([race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)), duplicate ([Faster to use MySQL's CURDATE() or PHP's date()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113920/faster-to-use-mysqls-curdate-or-phps-date)), no research shown. Comments indicate the same sentiment. I would downvote.

> [Arrays first index displaying wrong element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883316/arrays-first-index-displaying-wrong-element)
>
> Score +0/+0 (0), 2 answers (+2, 0), 3 comments, 115 views

Asker needs a book, not an answer. Question does not properly explain what the code they wrote should do. Anyone with a bit of experience could see that, and offer a solution. Commenters agree with that.

This question is not useful for anyone else. Asker commented on the +2 answer, didn't accept, hasn't ever voted on any post.

> [How to sort sql query result pivotally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034461/how-to-sort-sql-query-result-pivotally)
>
> Score +1/-0 (1), 1 accepted answer (1), 0 comments, 32 views

*"This is my data, this is my desired output. Gimme the codez."* An 18K rep user happily obliged.

Should not have been upvoted, zero effort shown, plenty of duplicates exist.

> [Keeping strok tokens after the initialization function ends in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945624/keeping-strok-tokens-after-the-initialization-function-ends-in-c)
>
> Score +1/-1 (0), 1 accepted answer (0), 2 comments, 33 views

Something about accessing local variables in other methods and "corrupted  pointers", initially without code. The comments address this, after which the OP added code, which according to a new comment doesn't compile. Can't verify.

The principle itself has been discussed in plenty of other duplicates.

> [Angular 2 performance issue when displaying a list of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303625/angular-2-performance-issue-when-displaying-a-list-of-items)
>
> Score +1/-0 (1), no answers, 1 comment, 31 views.

*"Why does this [screenshot of code] spend the numbers of milliseconds shown in the screenshot?"*. Why was this upvoted? Where is the MCVE? But that's a trend in the Angular2 tag anyway, it looks like a cesspool of help vampires and enablers.

> [Domain Hijacking / Unrestricted EPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46873764/domain-hijacking-unrestricted-epp)
>
> Score +0/-1 (-1), 1 unaccepted self-answer, 1 comment, 11 views

OP has done a vulnerability scan on their site using a not specified tool and pasted one of the findings (of which the description is tool-specific) in the Stack Overflow Ask-a-Question box. This happens quite often for various of such tools.

A question like this could be useful when they at least mention what tool they used and what their research for the mentioned finding turned up, but neither are present. The comment mentions this, no action by the OP was taken to clarify. They self-answered with something along the lines of *"You can configure this with your domain host"*, without explaining how (host-specific of course).

> [Laravel total of products from Pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46926036/laravel-total-of-products-from-pivot-table)
>
> Score +1/0, 2 answers, 1 accepted (+2, +1), 4 comments, 50 views

*"How to sum a column of rows I render in a table"*. I can't imagine this question not to have been asked before, so should've been closed as duplicate instead of answered. It also shows no research effort.

The comments don't mention any of this.

> [How do I not display "0" when printing my array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201872/how-do-i-not-display-0-when-printing-my-array)
>
> Score +2/-2 (0), 5 answers, 1 accepted (+2, +1, 0, 0, 0), 4 comments, 76 views

The question *"How can I let a user enter any amount of numbers and [do something] with the numbers they entered"* comes by at least once per day, and every time they *have* to use an array (not a List, because hey, we're using C# to teach programming, we're not teaching idiomatic C#), and if the user enters fewer than the preallocated numbers, the rest of the array contains 0's and the calculation or printing they do with the array isn't correct.

I don't know why two people upvoted (one apologist in comments explained the OP is here to learn, so that might be it). One commenter complains this reeks of homework (it does), and the question has been answered by users with a reputation ranging from 1K to 21K, while this question shows zero research effort and must have at least a hundred potential duplicates.

---

So, what do we see in questions with this score? We see exactly what we see when browsing the frontpage of Stack Overflow: a load of zero-effort, poorly worded, hardly salvageable questions that get answered by people who care more about their reputation than about deduplication and quality on the site. Nothing surprising to me.

When I disagreed with any of the scores above, it was because the question was scored too high. Would I have encountered any of them organically, I would've downvoted all except the first.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because you did a pretty thorough analysis of the questions, which I appreciate. It seems to me that where we differ on these questions is that I'm evaluating whether they _could_ be answered and you are evaluating on whether they _should_ be answered (or even asked).

Comment: @Jon ah, that's an important disctinction. I might try and revisit this answer  later to see whether those questions _could_ be answered, but can't promise anything at the moment.

Comment: No hurry. It's great that you did it that way since it helped me clarify in my mind how different people think about the site. (Maybe you might be interested in [this essay I wrote](http://jericson.github.io/2016/07/13/QA_economics.html).)

Answer (score 8):

1. [Working groovy script is not working in jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051007/working-groovy-script-is-not-working-in-jenkins-pipeline)

   The comments indicate missing information. -1 score seems right.
2. [Can't stop AVFoundation song](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47171284/cant-stop-avfoundation-song)

   Asker reported working around the problem in the comments, but didn't answer or edit the question. I agree with the -1.
3. [Blurred values gets display when i selected the grid values from grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848352/blurred-values-gets-display-when-i-selected-the-grid-values-from-grid)

   I agree with the comment that this isn't a good idea client-side. But there is obviously enough information to get an answer. The 0 score makes sense.
4. [Google Services Conflict Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195780/google-services-conflict-error)

   A comment asked for the error log, the OP edited it in and got an answer. Later the OP self-answered. Good enough, but nobody voted.
5. [Json.Net deserialize JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47289887/json-net-deserialize-json-objects)

   The question was missing a description of the error, but it did get an answer the OP accepted. No particular reason to upvote the question, but it is good enough to get an answer.
6. [merging tweets by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242319/merging-tweets-by-date)

   A commenter asked for example data, the asker added that and got three answers. Maybe not an amazing question, but I wouldn't argue with the +1.
7. [Formatting is sporadic in Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231283/formatting-is-sporadic-in-spreadsheetwriteexcel)

   As a fan of Perl, I was happy to see this question turn up. The asker's code is not really up to my standards, but the question was good enough to get two answers. One didn't seem to help, but the OP was satisfied with the other one. I kinda doubt this will help many other users, so I'm not too upset the question got no votes.
8. [Hiding the ellipse button in command bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47009157/hiding-the-ellipse-button-in-command-bar)

   Got an answer that seems to have helped the asker, so the question is answerable. I know folks might complain that the asker didn't provide code. (It is provided in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007282/minimise-a-commandbar-in-uwp-with-on-click-event), however.) Still, I think this could be helpful for others with the same problem.
9. [Listen to the input in a while, and start a thread concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368089/listen-to-the-input-in-a-while-and-start-a-thread-concurrently)

   Straightforward question, clearly asked and promptly answered. Definitely reasonable to upvote.
10. [How to access the ID of a collapseTool in a grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115108/how-to-access-the-id-of-a-collapsetool-in-a-grid)

    If you are going to use images of text, this is a pretty good way to go about it. Definitely enough information to answer and there's even an alternate solution suggested in the answer comments.

---

Surprisingly, I didn't find any questions where I really disagreed with the voters' assessment. ('Though confirmation bias suggests I should be surprised to disagree.) When browsing the site or looking for questions to answer, I tend to see questions that aren't just unanswerable, but almost unintelligible. This sample didn't turn up any questions with broken formatting or massive code dumps or evidence the asker had never actually programmed before. I wondered if I was just lucky, but taking a few more samples of 10 questions shows the same sort of result. (I won't bother to write up an analysis of those samples, however.)

I was *not* surprised that so many questions get no votes even though they are answered. I wish more people upvoted questions that have good answers, but I can see not wanting to encourage questions for one reason or another.

Downvotes do seem to be explained in the comments. We often hear they aren't, but that seems to be the exception rather than the rule. (Interestingly, there's a [local minimum average number of comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/762000/average-number-of-comments-per-question-by-score#graph) at -1. I don't know how to explain it, but it's a lovely graph.) From my observation, if you get a downvote, it's likely to get an explanitory comment too. And if you read the comment, it's likely you'll be able to add a bit of needed information to get an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I agree with the -1*"? That you would downvote as well or that the question is at the score you think it should be? We're supposed to vote regardless of the current score (though I bet many people do). The vote should reflect our ternary judgment on the question and not attempt to have it reach a certain score. If the "*agree with the -1*" question had -3 would you want to upvote it because you think it should be -1?

Answer (score 6):

Okay, buckle yourself in, because this is going to be a rough ride. 10 questions each with 5 bullet points as well as an overall review? Remember, you asked for this.

Here is the query result

[image: my query result]

1. [Stop SQL query based on count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46879005) { Score: 0, answers: 1} 
   This question addresses a fundamental misunderstanding common in beginner SQL database developers. It was at +0, I don't find it interesting and it does not help me in the least, and I would not recommend it to others, that said, I find it to be on topic and well posed. I would also give it +0.  
   There were two comments by potential answerers asking for clarity, and two comment responses by the OP, however there were no significant edits to the question by the OP.  
   There was an answer which was an attempt at helping to solve the Y of this XY problem, but to be honest, the level of refactoring involved here in order to accomplish the requested action would have been immense, perhaps over the head of the OP, and certainly far too large of an answer to give (if not also an off topic answer as it does not "technically" answer the question).  
   The answer had no vote. It was a decent answer, to be honest given the narrow context it was probably close to the best approach to use, and the OP did comment on it that they were going to "try the suggestion". There was no activity following that comment on the post.
2. [Launcher Activity Not Starting it's Crash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47133434) { Score: 1, answers: 1} 
   Much better outcome than the first! I would probably upvote these if I had found them and I was working on the OP's issue. There was a comment from a user requesting more information, the OP then edits in the information requested, and then another user comes in and posts an answer to the question which the OP then accepts and leaves a comment indicating that the solution solved their problem.
3. [Cancel partially an observable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47164662) { Score: 0, answers: 2} 
   This question involves dealing with asynchronous behavior in a JavaScript library rxjs. It was basically a "here is my attempt, how can I make it work" question. There was a comment asking for a small clarity, but no resulting edits were made to the post. An answer was posted by the person who asked for some clarification, and oddly enough the OP then decided to post their own answer as a riff on the posted answer. There was no action on the post after that. I am not sure if this will ever be of value to any future readers.
4. [DocuSign REST API: Adding a Carbon Copy Recipient With Document Visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47112958) { Score: 0, answers: 1} 
   This question was in reference to using a DocuSign API. The question was well posed, contained 0 comments, and the resulting answer came really close to solving the problem. In comments on the answer the solution was found (but not edited in). The answer sits at +0 with no accept mark even though the OP stated it solved their problem.
5. [Combine two images obtained from PDF in a single image with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47221593) { Score: 1, answers: 0} 
    
   This question was just bad. I am not sure if I should action it or not since I was hoping to avoid the meta effect. It is unclear, provides no insight into what type of approach they were using, and only includes links to some images (supposedly, didn't click) that need to be combined with code. The only comments were with regards to  the links being broken, there were no edits to the post. There were no answers either. Overall, in my opinion this question is not up to Stack Overflow standards.
6. [C++ When I take in and print a string a user inputs, it only prints the first word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47242305) { Score: -1, answers: 0} 
    
   This question was a commonly asked question about getting user input in C++ from the console. It was a duplicate, and there was no changing that from the moment it was posted. A few users answered the question as one liners in comments, one user posted an answer to the question but was downvoted and then it was deleted. Overall, this post serves no purpose, has 2 close votes, sits at -1, and I highly doubt it will be of value to future visitors.
7. [pandas groupby sum area plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47142864) { Score: 0, answers: 1} 
    
   This question was well posed, a user was trying to compose data for graphing, but got stuck and wasn't sure why. A typical Stack Overflow mind reader came along and showed the missing piece. There were no comments, but the answer was accepted. Both the question and answer stand at +0, but it looks like it could help future readers to me.
8. [RecyclerView scroll to drag and dissmiss](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47355286) { Score: 0, answers: 1} 
   This question was not composed as well as it could have been, but overall it still seems okay. No comments on the post itself. It was asking about android scrolling. An answer with code was posted which seemed to be a stepping stone. The OP then posted a self-answer and accepted their own answer referencing insight from the other answer. The self-answer contained a significant amount of code and overall as a result the post seems like it would be of value to future readers, however it may be unlikely anyone ever finds it due to the question's composure.
9. [How to enumerate sibling nodes in SyntaxTree using SyntaxWalker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47308437) { Score: -1, answers: 1} 
   This was a rather complex question about vb.net compilation. It doesn't really include much information, and has code in an image but overall seems like it produced a decent answer. There were no comments anywhere, and while the answer sits at +1, it was not accepted by the OP. I am unsure if this is useful or not.
10. [Catch panning event in Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47182434) { Score: 1, answers: 1} 
    This is about catching an event in a JavaScript library for charting. I am rather familiar with this library. The documentation is really good, but sometimes it can be hard to pinpoint solutions. While the question has a minimal set of code, it is enough to kind of grasp what was going on. No one asks for clarification on the post, but there are a few suggestions in comments. A user also posts, in my opinion, a rather spectacular answer given the context of the post, with a working example. It sits with no comments at +2 and is accepted. I would assume that this post would be useful to future visitors.

---

So, there you have it. I will leave the overall analysis up to you, as far as what you may glean from this. From my observation one post should be deleted, two others should probably be closed, and the rest should stay.

In only one question did I observe an edit which improved the overall situation or allowed another user to answer.

Answer (score 4):

(`dummy` value set to 0)

---

1. [Stop SQL query based on count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879005/stop-sql-query-based-on-count)

   The comments indicate the original question was unclear. The asker edited it to make it a bit more clear, but there’s still some ambiguity about what the asker is really looking for. After that edit, an answer was posted that’s a reasonable attempt to get at the asker’s problem, and the asker commented on that to say they would try it — but never commented again after that. The gist is that it’s not a terrible question, but also not clearly a very good question. The 0 score makes sense.
2. [Launcher Activity Not Starting it's Crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47133434/launcher-activity-not-starting-its-crash)

   There’s an accepted answer that’s essentially just quoting a part of a stack trace pasted into the question — which indicates that the asker maybe didn’t take time to look carefully at the stack trace (or didn’t know how) before posting the question. There’s a comment for the question asking for additional info, but the asker never responded to it. The code snippet in the question with the stack trace is poorly formatted, and the question is poorly worded. There doesn’t seem to be any good reason for anyone to have upvoted the question.

   **So for this question the +1 score seems excessive.**
3. [Cancel partially an observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164662/cancel-partially-an-observable)

   The comments have a clarifying question, which the asker responded to. There’s a good answer that gets at asker’s question but which is upvoted but which the asker did not accept. (The asker instead posted their own answer just based on information the provided in the other answer.) The upvoted original answer is decent but the question isn’t really exceptional. The 0 score makes sense.
4. [DocuSign REST API: Adding a Carbon Copy Recipient With Document Visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112958/docusign-rest-api-adding-a-carbon-copy-recipient-with-document-visibility)

   The question is decent and has no glaring poor-formatting problems or poor-formatting problems. There are no comments. It has a solid answer, with a comment from the asker that seems to indicate it successfully answered the question. The answer is not upvoted nor accepted — but the asker has only 1 rep, so they’re not able to upvote and maybe don’t yet understand how to accept. The asker’s problem isn’t a very general one — it’s arguably just a mistake/oversight on their part. So the 0 score makes sense.
5. [Combine two images obtained from PDF in a single image with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221593/combine-two-images-obtained-from-pdf-in-a-single-image-with-java)

   The question has no glaring formatting/wording errors and describes a reasonable problem. However, in the question the asker says *“I tried to use different methods”* but doesn’t show code for what they’ve tried — nor even actually describe at all in any way what they’ve tried. There’s a good comment which the asker responds to with info that sorta just seems to further confuse things. I’d expect a 0 at best for this question, if not multiple downvotes (but it’s only been viewed 29 times).

   **So for this question, the +1 seems excessive.**
6. [C++ When I take in and print a string a user inputs, it only prints the first word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47242305/c-when-i-take-in-and-print-a-string-a-user-inputs-it-only-prints-the-first-wo)

   There’s a comment with a one line of code that solves the problem in the question. The question seems to show some basic unfamiliarity with the language. The -1 makes sense.
7. [pandas groupby sum area plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142864/pandas-groupby-sum-area-plot)

   The question is decent, and is about a fairly simple problem, with no clarification needed and no comments asking for any. There’s a simple, good, accepted answer that exactly gets at the asker’s problem. The 0 score makes sense.
8. [RecyclerView scroll to drag and dissmiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355286/recyclerview-scroll-to-drag-and-dissmiss)

   The question is OK, with no comments asking for clarification. There’s a good upvoted answer that addresses the asker’s problem but it has a comment from the asker explaining why it’s not applicable due to some additional info that the asker didn’t actually put into the question. There’s another accepted answer from the asker that apparently solves the problem in the way they were aiming for. But it’s not clear the problem is a general one that anybody else is likely to run into. The 0 score makes sense.
9. [How to enumerate sibling nodes in SyntaxTree using SyntaxWalker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308437/how-to-enumerate-sibling-nodes-in-syntaxtree-using-syntaxwalker)

   There are no comments. There is one answer, upvoted, from the asker.  The question is simple and not obviously bad, but in place of an actual code snippet, it has an image of a code snippet. The -1 score makes sense.
10. [Catch panning event in Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182434/catch-panning-event-in-highcharts)

    There’s one +2 accepted answer. The question itself is decent and it’s imaginable that it’s a general problem that other people might ask about. The +1 score makes sense.