# Have we started trying question templates?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, question-quality, a-b-testing

I just came across these HTML comments when I went to edit a question:

```
<!-- What are you trying to accomplish? (Please include sample data.) -->
<!-- Paste the part of the code that shows the problem. (Please indent 4 spaces.) -->   
<!-- What do you expect the result to be? -->
<!-- What is the actual result you get? (Please include any errors.) -->
```

I haven't seen these before, and I was wondering if they were related to ["What can we put in a question template to help people ask better questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions)

If not, what are those about? I'm pretty sure the OP didn't put them in.

If so, I'm sorry for spoiling the official announcement.

Comment: _"I'm pretty sure the OP didn't put them in."_ Anyone else from the questions edit history?

Comment: Good question. But there are no edits so far. I assumed they didn't put them in because they don't match the rest of the writing style at all, and it seemed strange for someone to ask themselves questions in their question.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Honestly I'm surprised it took this long for someone to comment!

Comment: @JoeFriend maybe it's so successful that it's producing nothing but questions that don't need editing? ;)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Wow, you just made me smile. Okay, so that probably isn't it, but it made me smile anyway. Maybe the whole of meta has been too busy Christmas (or Hanukkah or Kwanza or whatever) shopping to notice?

Comment: In case it's not obvious, feel free to delete or leave these comments as you see fit. I decided to make the template 100% HTML comments so that the OP can see them while editing, but they won't show up in the rendered post. That way it doesn't matter so much if the asker ignores the template.

Comment: @JonEricson [:(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624643/about-jboss-p2p-and-bridge)

Comment: Although, I assume googling "What are you trying to accomplish? (Please include sample data.)" isn't the best way to find examples of successful template users.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: Ugh. That clearly goes in the "template failure" category. Thanks for cleaning it up with an edit. If we see a lot of cases where people screw with the template without deleting it, I might need to adjust the copy.

Comment: I [was wondering about this the other day, too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions/358056#comment536880_358056).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes. We started an experiment on Friday (see screenshot of editor with template below). So far 15,000 people have seen the template and over 9,000 of them have gone on to ask a question. Anyone with less than 111 rep is eligible for the experiment (no guarantees on whether you see it or not). The outcome of this experiment is evaluated using our [new question grading system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests). We are also running a survey for those who experience the template. We will be back in a week or two with details on how well it works.

**Editor with template**
[image]

It is important to remember that this is the first of many experiments we will run around the question quality theme. Given that we haven't executed an experiment around question quality before, we intentionally kept things simple so that we could focus on the mechanics of running this new type of experiment.

Comment: Would it be worth adding something like "please remove all these comments before posting"?

Comment: @Shepmaster I don’t think so — HTML comments don’t show up in posts.
 <!-- (but they do show up in comments) -->

Comment: @JF lol, but Still No, they have to replace comments (one by one) by their actual writing or code, that's the point... isn't it ?

Comment: I'm curious to see how many people simply select-all -> delete. Then proceed to copy-paste dump their homework or a screenshot of it with the title: "**HALP URGANT!!! PLZ!**"

Comment: _"Anyone with less than 111 rep is eligible..."_ Oddly specific number. What's the logic behind it?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier: The point is to get people to think through their questions a bit better. If people want to replace the comments in order, I think that's ideal. But if people prefer to add their content between the comments, that's fine too. I'm even ok with people reading the template, asking a better question as a result and forgetting to remove the template. In any case, the A/B test ought to show us if there's a measurable improvement in question grade as a result of the template.

Comment: I don't know, @Shepmaster, in the question I originally saw that prompted me to ask this question, I thought it was interesting to see what the person thought belonged under each of those comments.

Comment: @Don'tPanic what would you think if the comments were promoted into markdown headers (in some cases, at least)? If they contribute to the understanding of the question, it seems they should be visible to everyone. If they don't contribute to the understanding, why leave them at all?

Comment: @j08691: at a guess, the logic is that a complete beginner on this site can have 1 point by default + 100 for transferring their account from another SE site, so they can have 101 without having used this site before. 10 more means they've either done a few edits that were accepted, or else received at least one upvote on an answer or two on previous questions, so they've shown at least *some* familiarity with the site.

Comment: @Shepmaster that's a good point. I guess I'd say it gave me more understanding of the question asker than it did of the question itself.

Comment: "(Please indent 4 spaces.)" could be improved by informing the user that the `{}` in the edit bar will perform this indentation. Perhaps: "(Please indent 4 spaces; e.g. select your code and click the {} in the edit bar above)".

Comment: Also, shouldn't we be asking for an MCVE instead of "part of the code"?

Comment: @j08691 When we ran the mentorship experiment we used more complicated criteria. I suggested simplifying the criteria AND increasing the rep level to broaden the pool of participants. Having a bigger pool helps reach a statistically significant result sooner. So, 111 is 11 rep (earned on SO) + 100 association bonus that you get by having decent rep on some other network site. This is an imperfect attempt to fully include most very, low rep question askers. It seems to be working well at this point.

Comment: @KevinWorkman: I have a template variation that specifically prompts for an MCVE. For this test, we wanted something simple that didn't require people to go to another page to figure out what the template is getting at.

Comment: @JonEricson Cool, thanks for the reply. Maybe a slight rewording could be "Paste an example program that shows the problem." or something?

Comment: @JonEricson It seems that even some [truly terrible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663863/i-want-to-make-an-email-server) questions are at least trying to fill in the template, so... good news?

Comment: @mbrig: Huh. Well. . .  maybe more entertaining than if there _weren't_ a template?

Comment: @JonEricson I think it bodes well that there was an attempt, instead of it just being deleted. The question is off-topic, but I can imagine that if it wasn't, they might have been able to fill things in a bit better...

Comment: Some people are [responding to the template's prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47683027/1) without realizing that no one else sees them.

Comment: Any reason why there's a rep limit at all? Is it harmful to have this on for everyone? Or is it just for experimentation right now?

Comment: @DavidG I can see long term users being annoyed and asking for an off button. 111 is a good starting point, but I guess there might be other factor later down the line e.g. 200 rep OR a question with +3 upvotes and no downvotes

Comment: @SGR I see long-term users posting terrible questions too, there's no harm in reminding them...

Comment: I know I'm a stuck record, but this is a horrible template. It's waaay too restrictive in what it allows users to post (and one of the metrics you should be somehow trying to look at is how many *good* questions we lost because askers were deterred when we showed them a template they couldn't reasonably contort their question into, or who made their questions worse trying to massage them into the template.

Comment: Also, this seems like a recipe for unhelpfully broad questions. You're demanding users provide a problem spec with sample data *and* some buggy code. Questions that contain both these things are frequently bad because they're two questions in one - they're in effect asking both "how can I achieve this task?" and "plz debug my code", which are usually unrelated problems. I always complained about the "what have you tried?" crowd demanding that all questions be made into two-questions-in-one in this way; I'm sad that the site itself now wants to do the same thing.

Comment: @JoeFriend Are you also [testing an answer template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47698808/2370483)? Or did the user do that on their own?

Comment: @Machavity: We aren't testing answer templates.

Comment: @MarkAmery: We are looking at now many people are deterred from asking by comparing the rate people actually ask something after hitting the ask page. Some dropoff is expected and probably fine. It'll be a little harder to tell if we are losing specific classes of questions however. Depending on the results, we're looking to test other templates. In the future, we might offer a menu of templates. This test is focused more on verifying the test structure than validating this specific template. More to come.

Comment: This is a massive detriment to the site. We can now expect even less interesting questions, and even more mindless debugging nonsense questions that have been asked and answered in one way or another hundreds of times already and will never help anyone other than the OP ever. Y'all just keep coming up with ways to discourage experts from participating, and encourage those who ultimately add no value to the site to participate. Just making the great wall of crap that much bigger.

Comment: @JoeFriend "We will be back in a week or two"... where do I sign up to receive a notification? It seems the info on this is scattered between several meta posts.

Comment: @TinyGiant The plan isn't too only have a template for debugging. That is just the template we are testing currently. We have other options that we're considering.

Comment: @NH We will feature the post with the results so hopefully you won't miss it.

Comment: @JoeFriend, thanks!  I do have [a few gripes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360371/1739000) about the exact way the feature was implemented, though. Not to be mean, just want this to be as helpful as possible.

Comment: "It's OK, we're just shooting ourselves in the foot _right now_. Once we're done shooting ourselves in the foot, we'll still be able to walk... right?"

Comment: Are you sure that everyone reading that template knows what indent means? I didn't, until 3 years ago. As Makyen mentions, something like `Select a block of code, and use {} button to indent it.` might actually encourage them to try to do something about it.

Comment: @NisargShah *Help! I pressed the { and } buttons on my keyboard, but it just overwrote all my code with the letters {}!* Probably best to advise them to press `CTRL-K`; I think it's the editor's most idiot-proof indentation method.