# 'Ask a question' wizard and non-code-related questions about software tools

Tags: support, ask-question-wizard-2018

I'm wondering if questions that relate to software development tools but that don't involve code are allowed on Stack Overflow. The example I have in mind is non-code-related questions about Xcode's Interface Builder.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), it says that questions related to 'software tools commonly used by programmers' are allowed. However, the 'ask a question' wizard doesn't necessarily seem to allow for such questions.

The first page of the wizard currently offers these options:

- I have a question about some code
- I need help with a homework problem
- I need a hardware recommendation
- I need a software recommendation
- I need to troubleshoot some software or hardware
- Other

The only specific option that seems like it could apply to a tool like Interface Builder would be the troubleshooting one, but not all questions about tools are about troubleshooting.

If you choose 'Other', the next screen offers the following criteria for questions:

- Includes a bit of source code
- Concerns a specific coding issue, algorithm, or language
- Isn't opinion-based

A question about Interface Builder could include no source code and not directly relate to a specific algorithm or programming language. As such, it seems such questions would be disallowed on Stack Overflow.

Although I could be wrong, I doubt Stack Overflow actually intends to disallow non-code-related questions about tools like Interface Builder. Among other things, there are many such questions on Stack Overflow already (although I understand the policies may have changed since those questions were posted).

I searched this forum for threads on the wizard, and found some discussion about whether the wizard inadvertently disallows valid questions. I didn't find any clear answers though, and the aspects of the wizard in question haven't changed, so it's not clear to me what is and isn't allowed at this point.

Are questions about development tools such as Interface Builder allowed on Stack Overflow, even if they don't involve code, provided they otherwise meet Stack Overflow's requirements?

Comment: Just curious, doesn't "Other/not Opinion-based" fit your proposed question?

Comment: Yes, these concerns have been posted in this answer to [The Ask Question Wizard Is Now In Testing!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378221/4642212).

Comment: [I raised this point on the announcement when the feature went live](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live/381673#381673).

Comment: @Paulie_D I think 'not Opinion-based' is just another criterion, not a separate category. That is, it's just saying questions in general should not be opinion-based. That said, several people upvoted your comment, so maybe I'm wrong. Maybe someone can offer clarification on that.

Comment: I am pretty sure your interpretation is right and @Paulie_D's is wrong. Although there's no 'and' or 'or' between them, it doesn't make much sense to read those bullet points as having 'or's between them; as far as I can see the intended meaning is that a question must meet *all* the criteria to be askable. The alternative interpretation, as you point out, would mean that the wizard says *any* non-opinion-based question is okay, with no other criteria, not even that the question is programming-related. I may disagree with the 'and' interpretation, but the 'or' interpretation is clearly absurd.

Comment: [They did it specifically to make it appear as though how-to questions are off-topic, and said so.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378075/4639281)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're allowed. Please entirely disregard the suggestion that a question must "include a bit of source code" to be allowed; it's not true and never has been. Many questions are improved by the inclusion of code, but equally many are *not*, and any suggestion that the inclusion of code is universally mandatory, across all possible types of question, is just plain wrong.

I've been crusading against this messaging for a while:

- In [Please don't force new users into a debugging-specific form on the /ask page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366936/1709587), I pleaded with the staff not to deploy a question template that implied that only code debugging questions were welcome here, and was told (wrongly, it turns out) that they wouldn't do so.
- In https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378221/1709587, I pointed out that our highest-voted questions disproportionately do *not* "include a bit of source code".
- In https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381813/1709587, I argued that this wording would drive away conscientious contributors who are planning on asking perfectly on-topic questions but read the wizard's wording and are led to believe that they're against the rules.

They're absolutely not against the rules. There is, to quote a [recent post of Cody Gray's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382518/1709587), *"a persistent undercurrent of thought that attempts to transform Stack Overflow into a debugging service"*, and the worst thing about the new Ask Question wizard is that it buys into that idea; it's impossible to ask anything other than *"Here's my code, here's what I want it to do, here's what goes wrong, please fix it for me"* via the wizard, and the instructions suggest that other sorts of question are forbidden. I agree with you that the question you want to ask unambiguously disobeys the instructions in the wizard, but that's because the wizard's instructions are a terrible misrepresentation of the established norms of the site. Please, please, ignore and disobey those instructions.

The saddest thing about this, to my mind, is that you are - judging from this Meta question and your previous two questions on the main site - clearly an articulate writer capable of asking a clear and useful question. You're *exactly* the sort of asker we should *want* on the site. But it's people like you who are disproportionately likely to be conscientious rule-followers who walk away when the wizard suggests your question isn't allowed. To hell with that. The wizard does not accurately represent the community's values, and we want people like you here. Don't let it drive you away.