# Should definition questions be allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I had asked a question to define some jargon commonly used in coding, but it was closed as off-topic. I understand where this is coming from and agree with it to some extent, but I'm not sure I completely agree. It raises a more general question.

If someone asks to define a term germane to programming, should it be on Stack Overflow? It seems to me that there is some gray area, and there is a chance that folks could be discouraged from asking questions that are sometimes viewed pretty often. Alternatively, perhaps the decision is if the definition pertains to a particular language or application. Then, more general questions are better for another Stack Exchange site? Which one could that be?

Examples

- [What does "nit" mean in hacker-speak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810522/what-does-nit-mean-in-hacker-speak)
- [What does SGBD mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980813/what-does-sgbd-mean?rq=1)
- [What does SCM stand for in meaning of trac, redmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090643/what-does-scm-stand-for-in-meaning-of-trac-redmine?rq=1)
- [What does "ctx" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120808/what-does-ctx-mean?rq=1)
- [What does MUT mean in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583491/what-does-mut-mean-in-android?rq=1)
- [What does `hl` stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271747/what-does-hl-stand-for?rq=1)
- [What does "pl" or "p" mean in a version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491729/what-does-pl-or-p-mean-in-a-version-number?rq=1)
- [What does rc mean in angular versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087743/what-does-rc-mean-in-angular-versions?rq=1)

Comment: I'd like to add, please spell out acronyms at least one per answer if used a lot. There have been times I have been totally lost because both OP and Answer use long acronyms and they are hard to google.

Comment: Definition questions very frequently show a lack of research. Instead of asking about being stuck in understanding some easily accessible definition or tutorial, people want yet another one. Beginner questions about basic applications of a term also very frequently show a lack of research, because they make no effort to apply or understand a definition.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I am perfectly okay with questions like these. They are on-topic as long as they are *obviously* programming-related. In other words, they need to be asking about terms used in source code, language definitions/specifications, and/or development environments. Like many of the examples in your question, or [this one about Win32 resource scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816635/what-does-the-acronym-idc-mean).

Just because it's [incidentally found in a commit message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810522/what-does-nit-mean-in-hacker-speak) or part of general "hacker speak" doesn't make it programming-related, though. This unfortunately has to be decided on a case-by-case basis.

There is a persistent undercurrent of thought that attempts to transform Stack Overflow into a debugging service, where the only on-topic question would present source code and ask for someone to debug that code. Resist this urge. While such questions are *also* on-topic (as long as they contain [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), they're also the least interesting and least generally-useful questions that can possibly be imagined, so we certainly don't want to restrict the site's scope to *only* handling these questions.

Our charter is to build a library of high-quality answers to [the long tail of programming-related questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/). We naturally have to exclude questions that are unanswerable in our format, even if they are about programming, such as polls or primarily opinion-based questions that don't have a verifiable answer. For practical reasons, we have also learned that "recommendation" questions should be discouraged, because they tend to lead to spam and low-quality answers. Definition questions, however, do not fall into either of these categories. They are narrowly focused and have verifiable answers.

Note that *naming* questions—what should I call my function that does *x*?—are off-topic because they are primarily opinion-based and there is no objective answer.

Comment: This answer has aged badly and has become incorrect. I would advice to edit the answer to mirror the current status quo, otherwise, this is a statement of opinion and should be removed. I do not have the ability to do either, so I urge you to act.