# How "mandatory" can we make the help wizard?

Tags: discussion, ask-question-wizard-2018

I was reading the featured post of the Question Wizard, which is great that it's finally out and has recorded positive metrics!

However, I am still a bit unclear on the actual "must use" nature of the wizard. I think it's great that it's required to answer a few questions first, but how will this effect (for lack of better words) "established help vamps"? We all know these accounts, tons of rep and badges for a couple questions ask years ago, and then a slew of poorly received questions.

Could posting several poorly received questions in a row "reset" the Question Wizard back to guided mode until the user has fulfilled the requirements to return to traditional mode, regardless of rep and or account age? I still see plenty of thousand thousand rep users posting the same quality questions as a 1 rep hasn't read the FAQs user.

Comment: Metrics? What metrics?

Comment: Well ideally those users would just get question banned, instead of being given the wizard.  If prompts like that would have helped them ask good questions, they'd have done it before getting to the point you're describing (because they'll already have seen so many people asking them those questions in comments).

Comment: @Makoto I want to say it was in a blog post, let me try and find it (the pre-release test metrics)

Comment: @Servy question bans are virtually impossible to achieve when you have thousands of rep

Comment: I've likely seen the same blog post but my question remains:  [what metrics?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381794/1079354)

Comment: You can be q-banned and have thousands of reputation.  Being question banned isn't the same as being answer-banned.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Yes, I know.  That's what needs to change.  Not the wizard.  The question ban need to be altered such that users that have 200 bad questions and 5 good questions can't ask questions, unlike the current algorithm.

Comment: @Makoto Technically, yes, in a practical sense, not really.  Positive feedback is worth so much more than negative feedback that a small number of questions going viral will allow for an unreasonably large amount of bad questions.

Comment: @Servy both could be nice too -- but obviously, the development effort is stretched and life isn't ideal for engineers :P But I definitely agree that a Q ban algorithm needs updating. That being said, the Guided wizard is nice, and it's never a bad time to have a refresher :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it as of now. The only problem is the bar (111) is too low.

Comment: Yeah, 111 is pretty low (I can't remember if that takes into account the +100 multi-account rep?), but they did say it's easily adjusted if needed

Comment: It would really suck if they did make it mandatory, because the wizard makes it extremely difficult to ask how-to questions in favour of useless debugging questions. It would be much better if they just benched the project until they figured out how to properly advise users asking how-to questions without making it seem like they are off-topic or require code.

Comment: @SterlingArcher They provided metrics in the blog post; Makoto is talking about not being able to query exact data using SEDE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The wizard isn't going to solve a problem like this, mostly because [it lacks bite](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358265/1079354).

That is to say, people *can* and *will* put in whatever they wish to pacify the wizard to get their question posted.  In the grand scheme of things, this makes sense; a person doesn't exactly *care* what measure of quality their question is, so long as they get it answered.  And if we *reward* poor questions with answers, then the wizard has not measurably* made an improvement.

However, ***this isn't the job of the wizard at all***.  It's the job of the quality check scripts which come in **after the fact**.  Users who ask poor questions through the wizard aren't immune to the quality check; the hope with the wizard is that questions which are asked through it are less likely to fall afoul of the quality check, and thus, would imply that they are more palatable/more answer/better questions.

Making the wizard more mandatory (for a given definition of "more" or "mandatory") doesn't fix the issue of people asking bad questions like a rate limit or question ban would.

But hey - when we do get some numbers to support the assertion that quality is on the rise, we'll be able to know more and guess less about how effective a mandatory wizard actually would be.

Comment: Looking for your * but can't find it!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  It's a tongue-in-cheek reference to my statement on the launch of the wizard.  I can't empirically say if it has or hasn't measurably made an improvement because we lack numbers, kind of like you lacked (briefly) a reference to the asterisk.  It's also in the comment chain on the question itself. ;)