# Force a bad question asker back to the wizard

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, ask-question-wizard-2018

Is there a way to force/suggest a bad question "asker/OP" to use the new wizard [The Ask Question Wizard is Live!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381671/125981)

I am one more likely to ask someone to improve a question or even edit it myself then "suggest" more improvements rather than a simple close vote, then if they do not later vote to close it.  People are here to get an answer but sometimes what the question is exactly is obscured by the person asking it (OK we all know this).  I often post a link to the "how to ask", MVE etc.

So, is there a way to "force/strongly suggest" that instead of "closed as unclear what you are asking" they work through the wizard - or even put it IN that close reasons or some such? (OK done with my rambling now)

Comment: We should perhaps wait and see whether the wizard really improves the quality of questions before doing this. Have you noticed a difference in the tags you follow?

Comment: During the wizard test, we saw users putting the [bare minimum of work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378753/1197934) into a question.  Even if we force them into the wizard, would it really deter those who are determined to ask a question, regardless of the roadblocks?

Comment: Strongly related:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382615/1079354

Comment: If anything, the questions over the past couple days have gone down in quality...

Comment: @fbueckert - perhaps I misunderstand the purpose of the wizard as some form of "Get better questions" since you indicate it did/does not help from the test phase.(at least in part perhaps?)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss _"If anything, the questions over the past couple days have gone down in quality."_ There maybe many reasons for this, like e.g. seasonal university schedules, cosmic rays, sunspot activity, or whatever.

Comment: The purpose is definitely to get better questions.  But there's always a class of users who refuse any sort of guidance, and there won't be any way to help them improve.  The ones failing after asking a question or two are likely in that category, as they've likely been through the process already.

Comment: You're assuming that the question hasn't already been through the wizard process. As I understand it, the wizard doesn't *enforce* quality, it *suggests* it. I suspect that a new user could answer "blah" to every prompt and the question would be posted. Summarily closed, of course, but posted nonetheless.

Comment: The purpose of closing a question is to prevent low quality answers from being posted until a question can be improved.  When you see unanswerable questions you should be voting to close *immediately*, not waiting a while to close the question.  If the question is fixed and becomes a good question, it can be reopened.

Comment: Closing this as the corporate body here seems to NOT care about driving users away by closing questions especially on new and less frequent visitors based on the only answer AND the comments. Will accept this once the time period has lapsed

Comment: Conflating curation with being welcoming is not going to get a very good reception; one is about keeping quality high, while the other is just not being a jerk to others.  Closure and downvotes are curation.

Comment: I agree the comments are not very welcoming on this question at least from my perspective which to me is a shame.

Comment: How are the comments not welcoming?  They're certainly against your proposal, but are we not supposed to express disagreement now?  How can dissent be expressed if it's automatically classified as unwelcoming?

Answer (score 11):

...to what end, though?

If a user decides to ask a bad question, they're going to ask a bad question irrespective of what guard rails and guidance we put in front of them.   Phrased another way: if the wizard has fulfilled its role, then the questions which are of quality **do not require closure or downvotes**.

By the time a user has asked a question on the site, they have *lost* the guard rails of the wizard and are now subject to the same rules of quality as every other question asker.  Asking a question through the wizard doesn't make an OP magically immune to this rate limiting, nor *should* it for the circumstance you're outlining here.