# 'Ask a new question' Title example/placeholder

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

When I go to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) I get the following generic title suggestion:

[image]

> e.g. Is there an R function for finding the index of an element in a vector?

I have several related questions and comments related to this suggestion (please let me know if these should be broken up into a series of separate questions.)

- Where is this title suggestion stored? Can it be queried/edited by sufficiently high-rep users? (If so, how?)
- I seem to get this question no matter what tags I have selected when I ask the question. Is it user-specific? (i.e. is it giving an R-related example because that is overwhelmingly my most-engaged-with tag?)
- I think this is a poor exemplar for the title of an R question. It reinforces a mentality (common among R users, many of whom are closer to end-users rather than programmers) of "how do I find an existing tool that does X?" rather than "how do I solve the following problem?" (whether the *answer* is "use built-in function Y" or "use package Y or "write code like this ...") This is not a *bad* question — there are legitimate reasons to ask if there is a built-in function ... I just think this example primes askers in the wrong way. IMO we should encourage askers to focus on solving problems rather than finding/choosing among pre-existing solutions.
- Is this the appropriate venue for discussing this topic? (If not, where?)

This seems related to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357951/what-can-we-put-in-a-question-template-to-help-people-ask-better-questions) but AFAICT only loosely ...

---

Various commenters have pointed out that this example title text is **not** user-specific on Stack Overflow (i.e., it's a coincidence that I, an R-oriented user, am getting an R-oriented title suggestion); however, it's not the network-wide default. A haphazard sample of other SE sites suggests that non-SO sites use "What's your [site topic] question? Be specific."

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this particular example comes up for everyone. There's probably a field somewhere for each Stack Exchange site for the title placeholder. Changing it probably requires a CM or a dev.

Comment: That is static boilerplate. We all see that example. No logic is intended.

Comment: 1. You're right. It's a really bad example of a title. but 2. I get the exact same one and I've never asked nor answered an `R` post.

Comment: You might want to consider asking this on MSE as this example is shown network wide. On the other hand, that's a bad title that will get closed immediately (though if asked rightly it shouldn't be closed).

Comment: @BenBolker no I am referring to the R example. This questions title is fine.

Comment: @10Rep, I don't think this is network-wide? Will edit in a second ...

Comment: The [ask] site has a great section on what's a good title and what's not.  Is there any way we could provide a link to that near the title bar?  Or, since the average user has proven to be incapable of reading a short help page, could we put the first bullet point from the help page into the title bar suggestion?  It reads: "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one [full] sentence" (the addition of "full" is my addition)

Comment: Apparently, the title is referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577727/is-there-an-r-function-for-finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector) which was posted in 2011 and garnered 300+ upvotes.

Comment: "Can it be queried/edited by sufficiently high-rep users?" - I believe moderators can edit some things, but other than that it's only staff who can edit things in the help center and any of the other text on the site outside of posts, comments, user info and tag info.

Comment: Since this is based on a real question with many upvotes, it would be cool if the system would pick randomly from the top questions, and ideally narrow that down to the questions in a tag once the tags have been selected.

Comment: @poke that sounds nice in theory but that only needs one weird title to survive voting to cause lots of chaos. If anything, the boilerplate being  "tweaked" to the asker is nice but foremost is needs to be helpful and accurate. I think that is better achieved with closely controlled text then stuff that gets randomly read from a db.

Comment: @rene, I would say that the current title suggestion supports your theory. Taken as a whole that question is actually good (as well as highly upvoted), but it turns out **not** to be a good title to suggest to new askers.

Comment: This is almost surely unique based on the ask question 'wizard' and the additional work they are still doing/planning on that front. I'm not sure how you square "this isn't a good example of an R question" with "this is not a *bad* question--there can be a perfectly legitimate reason to [...]". Either it's a good title for *that question* or it's not. I don't think you need to worry that users asking questions in [tag:r] will be misguided by such an example that they almost certainly don't actually read before typing in their own question title.

Comment: (1) the question overall is good, and the title fits that question. For the reasons I explained in my question, I don't think the title encourages good practice in new askers. (2) The reason I brought this up in the first place is a conversation I had with a user who said (when I questioned their title/approach) "but this is just like the example that StackOverflow showed me".

Comment: This has attracted a reasonable amount of attention from commenters, but I don't see any moderators or admins (i.e. people who could actually do something about this) weighing in.  Is there something I can or should do to bring this to someone's attention?

Comment: I asked this question more than a year ago, but the suggestion is still there. Given that all the discussion here seems to be in consensus that the suggestion could be improved, what are suggestions for how I would bring this to the attention of someone who can do something about it?

Comment: Now 2+ years later, wondering if this is ever going to be changed. What is the polite way to try to bump this to someone's attention for action?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is Stack Overflow-specific. On other sites, the text looks like this:

> What's your [site name] or your [site name]-related question? Be specific.

I think on Stack Overflow it should be something like this:

> What's your programming <strike>or programming-related</strike> question? Be specific.

Another problem with the current text is that it's asking, "Is there an R function do to [something]?". Such a question, in all probability will get closed with "Needs More Focus".

If not my suggestion, please change it to a good title that's descriptive and not closable.

Comment: Could just be "programming question" (no need for the "or programming-related" IMO, that's just another temptation for askers to go in tangential directions; the "or" clauses in the examples I have seen occur where the site covers multiple topics ("science fiction or fantasy", "computer software or computer hardware" ...)  on the other hand, I don't think the current suggestion is unfocused (just bad for reasons I explained in my question)